# O que é JSON? Para que serve e como funciona?

Tags: json, terminologia

Costumo me deparar com esse JSON, mas não sei pra que serve e como ele funciona.

Comment: [JSON](http://www.json.org/) é uma `notação` (uma forma de se escrever) objetos em Javascript. Pode ser visto como um formato "universal" que é muito conveniente para troca de informações entre aplicações através de diversos protocolos. *"Join"* é um verbo em inglês que tem vários significados, relacionados a junção, junta, acumulação etc. O significado específico depende do contexto. Sem um contexto objetivo, a pergunta fica ampla demais.

Comment: @JeffersonAlison dê uma olhada __[aqui acerca de JSON](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)__. Sobre `join`, que é um método para juntar elementos de uma array/pilha, têm de ser mais específico sobre em que linguagem você procura. Javascript/PHP/etc

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Conceito:**

JSON, em seu significado teórico é "Javascript Object Notation", do qual nada mais é que o formato mais leve conhecido por mim de transferência/intercâmbio de dados, ele é similar ao `XML`, e tem a mesma utilidade, mesmo intuito, porém é mais leve, o detalhe é que não necessariamente, apesar do nome, você tem que usa-lo com Javascript. Muitas linguagens hoje em dia dão suporte ao JSON, é meio que um novo método, substituto do antigo e conhecido `XML`. Ele é muito usado para retornar dados vindos de um servidor utilizando requisições `AJAX` para atualizar dados em tempo real.

**Informações e Exemplos:**

Muitas empresas e sistemas conceituados hoje em dia utilizam JSON, como a Google e o Yahoo. Com ele podemos armazenar dados de uma maneira que funciona da seguinte forma:

Temos um objeto JSON simples, ele deve conter uma denotação(que é extremamente recomendado) ou não, como por exemplo:

```json
{"ObjetoPai":"valor"}
```

Agora vou mostrar um objeto JSON mais complexo com Objetos pai e objeto filho.

```json
{
"ObjetoPai":{
    "ObjetoFilho":"valor"
  }
}
```

Podemos ter um Array de objetos filhos, também:

```json
{

    "ObjetoPai":[
        {
            "ObjetoFilho":"valor"
        },
        {
            "ObjetoFilho":"valor"
        }
    ]

}
```

O JSON pode ser complexo, você pode ter mais de um objeto pai com filhos também, e referente a tipos ele aceita valores inteiros, booleanos, e também strings, como você pode ver:

```json
{

    "ObjetoPaiGeral":[
        {
            "ObjetoSubPai":{
                "ObjetoFilho":1
            }
        },
        {
            "ObjetoSubPai":{
                "ObjetoFilho":true
            }
        },
        {
            "ObjetoSubPai":{
                "ObjetoFilho":"string"
            }
        }
    ]

}
```

Ele pode ser facilmente armazenado dentro de uma variável como um Objeto, assim tornando fácil a usabilidade do mesmo, podendo acessar valores de forma programática, como por exemplo em Javascript declarando e acessando o ultimo exemplo acima:

```js
var JSONObject = {

        "ObjetoPaiGeral":[
            {
                "ObjetoSubPai":{
                    "ObjetoFilho":1
                }
            },
            {
                "ObjetoSubPai":{
                    "ObjetoFilho":true
                }
            },
            {
                "ObjetoSubPai":{
                    "ObjetoFilho":"string"
                }
            }
        ]

    };
```

**Acessando valores:**

```js
JSONObject;                                            //objeto geral em si
JSONObject.ObjetoPaiGeral;                             //array dos sub pais
JSONObject.ObjetoPaiGeral[0];                          //acessando o primeiro filho do pai geral
JSONObject.ObjetoPaiGeral[0].ObjetoSubPai;             //acessando o objetosubpai do primeiro filho do pai geral
JSONObject.ObjetoPaiGeral[0].ObjetoSubPai.ObjetoFilho; //aqui você tem um valor, que é o valor do objeto filho do sub pai que é filho do pai geral.
//Você pode utilizar o tamanho do Array para fazer um laço de repetição se quiser:
JSONObject.ObjetoPaiGeral.length; //retornará 3.
```

Atualmente é um dos melhores métodos para resgatar informações do servidor, principalmente em uma aplicação que exige atualização de dados em tempo real.

Você pode aprender mais sobre ele aqui no [Site Oficial do JSON](http://json.org/json-pt.html).

Answer (score 22):

[JSON](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json) é um acrônimo para "JavaScript Object Notation", é um formato leve para intercâmbio de dados computacionais. JSON é um subconjunto da notação de objeto de JavaScript, mas seu uso não requer JavaScript exclusivamente.

É uma notação de javascript, que pode ser escrito em um arquivo texto, como por exemplo um arquivo [XML](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML). Pode ser usado para a troca de informações através de webservices. Por ser mais leve que o XML, é cada vez mais utilizado.

Join significa junção. Pode ser para [unir duas tabelas de um banco de dados](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/join.html), unir textos e etc. É um termo bastante genérico que pode ter significado diferente em cada tecnologia.

http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json

Answer (score 9):

Um ponto importante que não foi abordado nas outras respostas: um JSON válido **não** precisa ser obrigatoriamente um conjunto de pares chave/valor. Tudo bem que é o formato mais comumente utilizado, mas não quer dizer que é o único possível. Mas vamos por partes...

---

## Especificação do formato

JSON, como as outras respostas já disseram, é apenas um formato de dados, cuja sintaxe é inspirada no JavaScript - seria apenas um "subconjunto", pois no JavaScript a sintaxe é mais flexível e com mais possibilidades (como já apontado em [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/517720/112052) - e no final também há mais alguns exemplos).

Apesar de JSON ser acrônimo de "*JavaScript Object Notation*", não quer dizer que só pode ser usado com JavaScript (muitas linguagens possuem suporte ao formato, seja nativo ou através de bibliotecas).

Há alguns documentos "oficiais" que descrevem o formato:

- [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627), de Julho de 2006, atualmente **obsoleta**, pois fui substituída pela RFC 7159
- [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159), de Março de 2014, também obsoleta, pois foi substituída pela RFC 8259
- [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259), de Dezembro de 2017, atualmente é "o que vale", e está marcada inclusive como *Internet Standard*
- [ECMA 404](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-404_2nd_edition_december_2017.pdf), de Dezembro de 2017, é usado - entre outros - pelo JavaScript ([trecho da especificação da linguagem que faz referência direta ao ECMA 404](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-normative-references))

Um ponto em comum é que todos descrevem o JSON como sendo um texto em um formato específico. As RFC's descrevem assim:

> *JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) is a lightweight, text-based, language-independent data interchange format. It was derived from the ECMAScript Programming Language Standard. JSON defines a small set of formatting rules for the portable representation of structured data.*

E o ECMA 404 descreve assim:

> *JSON is a lightweight, text-based, language-independent syntax for defining data interchange formats. It was derived from the ECMAScript programming language, but is programming language independent.*

As definições dizem, portanto, que é um formato de texto **independente de linguagem**, que foi **derivado** da linguagem *ECMAScript* ([que no fundo é o JavaScript que conhecemos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/16015/112052)). Ou seja, a sintaxe é inspirada/baseada no JavaScript (porém não é 100% idêntica, pois o JavaScript permite variações que não são JSON's válidos), mas o formato pode ser - e hoje em dia é - usado em outras linguagens.

Outro ponto importante é que todos definem que JSON é um *data interchange format* (formato para intercâmbio/troca de dados). Ou seja, apesar de ser muito usado na Web, não é o seu único propósito. Qualquer aplicação que precise trocar dados com outra pode usá-lo. Neste aspecto, não é muito diferente de outros formatos, como XML, CSV, [YAML](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80881/112052), etc.

E um outro detalhe é que as especificações referem-se aos dados usando o termo "*JSON Text*", já que é um formato baseado em texto (*text-based*). Informalmente vejo as pessoas se referirem a ele apenas como "JSON" (como em "*Esta API retorna um JSON*", que tecnicamente quer dizer que ela retorna um *JSON Text*). Ou seja, no fundo, um JSON é uma "string" (uma sequência de caracteres), que representa os dados em um formato específico. Esta é uma distinção importante: **um JSON não é um objeto JavaScript** (ele pode ser convertido de/para, mas não é).

Além dos documentos já citados, existe também o [site oficial](https://www.json.org/), que usa a definição do ECMA 404.

---

## Valores (*JSON Values*)

Outro ponto em comum é a definição de valores válidos, que são chamados genericamente de *JSON values*. Todos os documentos acima definem que um *JSON value* pode ser um objeto, array, string, número, ou um desses 3 literais: `true`, `false` e `null`.

**Atenção:** Vale lembrar que aqui o termo "objeto" não deve ser confundido com o [objeto das linguagens de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/112052). Até porque [em JavaScript, um array também é um objeto](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array-objects), mas a definição do formato JSON trata esses termos como coisas diferentes. Portanto, no trecho abaixo, quando eu me referir a "objeto" e "array", estou falando das definições das RFC's e do ECMA 404 (ou seja, esqueça o JavaScript - e qualquer outra linguagem - pelos próximos parágrafos).

---

Os tipos mais, digamos, básicos de *JSON values* são os números e strings. A definição completa pode ser consultada nos links já citados, mas basicamente um número pode ser representado por literais como `42`, `-10.56`, `6.02e24` (notação cienfítica), entre outros. E uma string é uma sequência de caracteres entre aspas duplas (além de permitir os escapes como `\n`, `\t`, e `\uXXXX` para representar [code points](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394834/112052) em hexadecimal).

---

Um objeto é um conjunto de pares chave/valor, delimitado por chaves (`{ }`). Cada par possui uma chave e seu respectivo valor, separados por dois-pontos (`:`), e os pares são separados por vírgula. Esse é o "JSON mais comum" que é usado (e que muitos acham que é o único jeito possível). As chaves só podem ser strings (uma sequência de caracteres entre aspas duplas), e os valores podem ser qualquer *JSON value*.

Exemplo:

```js
{
    "nome": "Fulano",
    "idade": 42,
    "aprovado": false,
    "filiação": {
        "pai": "Ciclano",
        "mãe": "Beltrana"
    }
}
```

No caso, o objeto acima tem 4 chaves: "nome", cujo valor é a string `"Fulano"`, "idade", cujo valor é o número `42`, "aprovado", cujo valor é o literal `false`, e "filiação", cujo valor é outro objeto (que por sua vez tem 2 chaves: "pai" e "mãe", cujos valores são respectivamente as strings `"Ciclano"` e `"Beltrana"`).

---

Já um array é uma sequência de *JSON values* separados por vírgula e delimitado por colchetes (`[ ]`). Ex:

```js
[ "Fulano", 42, false, { "pai": "Ciclano", "mãe": "Beltrana" } ]
```

No caso, o array acima possui 4 elementos: a string `"Fulano"`, o número `42`, o literal `false` e um objeto (que por sua vez possui as chaves "pai" e "mãe" e seus respectivos valores `"Ciclano"` e `"Beltrana"`). Não há nada na especificação do formato que impeça que os valores sejam assim, de "tipos" diferentes (implementações podem tratar isso da forma que bem entenderem).

Vale lembrar também que, como objetos e arrays podem ter quaisquer *JSON values*, então eles podem estar aninhados uns aos outros: podemos ter arrays contendo objetos, cujos valores podem ser outros objetos ou arrays, etc. Não há um limite teórico para aninhamento de estruturas, mas as implementações podem definir um. Segundo a RFC 8259: "*An implementation may set limits on the maximum depth of nesting*".

---

## O que é um JSON válido?

A RFC 4627 (a mais antiga e atualmente obsoleta) define que um JSON válido só pode ser um objeto ou array (lembrando que ainda estou me referindo ao "objeto" e "array" explicados acima, e não à definição de uma linguagem específica). Ou seja, o formato mais comum (o objeto, o conjunto de pares chave/valor) não é a única possibilidade. Portanto, um array como `[1, 2, 3]` é um JSON perfeitamente válido.

Já as RFC's 7159 e 8259, e o ECMA 404 vão além, e definem que qualquer *JSON value* é um JSON válido. Ou seja, tanto `42` quanto `"Ok"` ou `true`, qualquer um desses valores é considerado um JSON válido.

Mas é claro que, para funcionar corretamente, você precisa saber detalhes de implementação da linguagem que está usando, para ter certeza que eles conseguem lidar com quaisquer *JSON values* (algumas implementações mais antigas seguiam a RFC 4627, por exemplo, enquanto outras podem incluir "extensões" e aceitar formatos não definidos pela RFC). Mas até onde sei, atualmente a maioria das linguagens *mainstream* suportam a especificação mais recente e aceitam qualquer *JSON value* sem problemas. Por exemplo, em [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) esses *JSON values* já [são mapeados para os tipos específicos da linguagem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json-to-py-table):

```py
import json

x = json.loads('42')
print(x, type(x)) # 42 <class 'int'>

x = json.loads('"abc"')
print(x, type(x)) # abc <class 'str'>

x = json.loads('false')
print(x, type(x)) # False <class 'bool'>

x = json.loads('null')
print(x, type(x)) # None <class 'NoneType'>
```

Também testei em JavaScript, PHP e Java (usando a biblioteca [Gson](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Primitives-Examples)), e todos aceitam os *JSON values* acima. Inclusive, as documentações de alguns citam a [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159), e portanto consideram que qualquer *JSON value* é um JSON válido.

Enfim, embora o objeto (conjunto de pares chave/valor) seja a escolha mais comum - principalmente hoje em dia, a esmagadora maioria das API's que vejo por aí optam por ele - não é a única opção. Eu reconheço que em muitos casos este *pode* ser o formato mais útil, por fornecer um descritivo das informações (`{"nome": "Fulano", "idade": 42}` me parece mais claro do que somente `["Fulano", 42]`), mas vejo que muitas vezes isso é abusado. Um exemplo clássico, temos uma API cuja URL é `/users` e retorna o seguinte:

```js
{
    "usuário 0": { "nome": "Fulano", "idade": 42 },
    "usuário 1": { "nome": "Ciclano", "idade": 20 },
    "usuário 2": { "nome": "Beltrano", "idade": 30 }
}
```

As chaves "usuário X" não acrescentam nenhuma informação relevante - se a URL é `/users`, eu já sei que ela retorna dados de usuários, então o retorno poderia ser um array:

```js
[
    { "nome": "Fulano", "idade": 42 },
    { "nome": "Ciclano", "idade": 20 },
    { "nome": "Beltrano", "idade": 30 }
]
```

Claro que é só um exemplo ilustrativo e a análise deve ser feita caso a caso, depende dos requisitos, etc. Mas é só para mostrar que nem sempre um único objeto (um grande conjunto de pares chave/valor) é o mais adequado ([outro exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/360771/112052)).

---

#### Diferenças entre JSON e JavaScript

Só para terminar, mais algumas diferenças (além das já citadas em outras respostas) entre o formato JSON e a sintaxe do JavaScript.

Em JavaScript podemos ter muito mais variações que um JSON não permite:

```js
function nomeChave() {
    return 'bla';
}
var chave = 'idade';

// Este é um objeto JavaScript válido, mas um objeto JSON inválido
var obj = { // JavaScript aceita comentários, JSON não :-)
     // não precisa de aspas na chave, e string pode usar aspas simples
    nome: 'Fulano',
    // nome da chave pode estar em uma variável, e o valor literal pode ser "undefined"
    [chave]: undefined,
    // chave é uma expressão que resulta em uma string, e o valor é o resultado de uma expressão
    [nomeChave() + 'xyz']: new Date(123459 * 2300),
    // o número é convertido em string, e o valor é uma regex
    2 : /[a-z]+/,
    // o valor é uma função
    func: function() { console.log('oi'); }
};

console.log(obj); // { "2": /[a-z]+/, "nome": "Fulano", "idade": undefined, "blaxyz": "1970-01-04T06:52:35.700Z", "func": function() { console.log('oi'); } }
```

Agora, se eu fizesse um JSON assim, ele seria inválido:

```
{
    nome: 'Fulano',
    [chave]: undefined,
    [nomeChave() + 'xyz']: new Date(123459 * 2300),
    2 : /[a-z]+/,
    func: function() { console.log('oi'); }
}
```

Claro que você pode usar `JSON.stringify` para converter `obj` para um JSON válido, mas o resultado estará de acordo com o formato especificado pelo ECMA 404 (muitos valores serão convertidos para string ou algum outro tipo válido, por exemplo, embora a função seja ignorada por *default* - mas [é possível customizar esse comportamento](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18089155)).

Enfim, saiba [separar o formato (que no fundo é só uma especificação) das suas implementações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/112052), especialmente do JavaScript. Cada linguagem vai ter detalhes de implementação que podem ou não ser iguais a outras.

Por exemplo, a especificação não diz nada sobre unicidade ou ordem das chaves, fica a cargo de cada linguagem/biblioteca tratar isso da forma que achar melhor. Um número como `13245678913246789`, como ele vai ser interpretado? Algumas linguagens possem tipos específicos de acordo com o tamanho do número, outras possuem apenas um único tipo numérico, enquanto que outras podem simplesmente não aceitar valores acima de certo limite, ou [exigir alguma adaptação específica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/525381/112052). A especificação deixa tudo isso em aberto, e cada linguagem trata da forma que achar melhor (no fundo, é uma preocupação que você sempre terá ao enviar dados entre aplicações, independente do formato escolhido).

Answer (score 8):

JSON é o acrônimo de JavaScript Object Notation.

Isso significa que usa-se uma formatação de texto que é semelhante à sintaxe de declaração de um objeto na linguagem JavaScript.

Esse texto pode ser usado de várias formas para estruturar um objeto qualquer em diversas situações. Em geral ele é armazenado em algum lugar (pode ser um arquivo simples, banco de dados ou outra forma) ou transmitido de uma aplicação para outra local ou remotamente.

Ao contrário da crença popular, e de ser o uso mais comum, ele não é usado apenas para transmitir dados via web.

Apesar de ter se baseado na sintaxe do JS não quer dizer que precisa dela para usar, apenas a sintaxe é bem parecida, e esse dado, porque isso é um dado (ou uma lista deles porque é possível ter até mesmo um array dentro do formato), pode ser processado por qualquer linguagem usando uma biblioteca padrão que entenda o formato ou mesmo manualmente se o programador o desejar (dá muito trabalho e corre-se risco na maioria das situações).

É verdade que ele foi criado originalmente para trabalhar com JS, mas ele foi universalmente adotado.

Existem concorrentes deste formato, cada um com vantagens e desvantagens, alguns mais poderosos, ou mais flexíveis, mas simples de usar, mais robusto ou com outras características que pode interessar ao usuário dele (o programador). YAML, BSON, XML e CSV são só alguns dos mais conhecidos.

Mas é importante reforçar que ele é só um formato de dados. Ele não pode ser confundido com o o objeto criado em JS. Ambos são declarados com a "mesma" sintaxe, só isso. E claro, se a sintaxe é parecida a semântica também é, mas ela é mais limitada.

Assim como o objeto do JS ele define toda a estrutura de do dado, através de pares de chave e valor (é possível que a chave seja implícita agindo como se fosse um *array*), sendo que o valor pode assumir várias formas usando a tipagem básica adotada pelo JS, e claro a sintaxe para definir um valor em cada tipo. Por isso JS tem total compatibilidade. Outras linguagens podem ter alguma impedância e precisar de alguma adaptação de algum tipo, embora por serem tipos básicos isso não deve ser frequente, nem um problema difícil de resolver.

Por ser um texto é de fácil leitura por humanos e fácil de processar, ainda que não seja eficiente nem em tamanho, nem para processar. Em geral um processo de [serialização](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) ou desserialização é realizado para converter esse formato em um objeto da aplicação.

Há um [site oficial](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) que demonstra a exata sintaxe adotada. E como pode-se ver existe uma [especificação oficial](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-404/). Lá também tem uma lista (provavelmente não muito atualizada) com implementações em diversas linguagens para manipular esse formato.

## Diferenças para um objeto JavaScript

Uma das diferenças mais importantes para o objeto JS é que JSON só aceita chaves do tipo `string`. E sintaxe oficial exige o uso de aspas duplas para delimitar uma *string*.

JSON aceita chaves duplicatas, até por ser só um formato, não tem como proibir isso ativamente, e cada implementação terá que lidar com isso da forma que achar melhor quando for criar um objeto na aplicação quando este não aceitar chave duplicada.

Obviamente que o formato só aceita valores literais, não pode criar expressões para serem executadas, inclusive não pode usar funções, pelo menos em JSON oficial.

Portanto todo JSON gere um objeto JS compatível, mas nem todo objeto JS pode gerar um JSON padrão.

Não existe o termo JSON Object. Desconheço uma linguagem que tenha um tipo chamado JSON, mas pode existir, provavelmente ele seria usado para facilitar a conversão para outro objeto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Objetos JS também só aceitam chaves do tipo string (embora as aspas sejam opcionais se a chave for simples/não possuir certos caracteres).

Answer (score 6):

JSON é um método de codificação hierárquica de dados, como XML, embora mais simples.

JSON nasceu dentro do contexto de Javascript -- e sendo Javascript válido pode ser diretamente interpretado com eval(), embora isto seja perigoso por questões de segurança. Também é interpretável diretamente em Python. mas hoje é considerado um método genérico e suportado por toda linguagem de programação.

Answer (score 4):

Json e Join são coisas completamente diferentes.

[Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) é utilizado em banco de dados quando se deseja retornar dados de múltiplas tabelas que possuem relação entre elas. Deve-se utilizar quando se deseja obter dados que não estejam em um tabela somente.

Já o [Json](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) "usa a sintaxe JavaScript para descrever objetos de dados, mas ainda é independente de plataforma." Neste caso, é utilizado quando se quer fazer trocar de dados entre aplicações. O formato Json é muito utilizado no ambiente Front-end para a troca de informações com o Back-end

Comment: Ficou confuso ver "join" nas versões mais recentes da pergunta. Só consegui entender o porquê da sua resposta verificando o histórico da pergunta