# O que é serialização? Quando usar? Como implementar no C#?

Tags: c#, json, .net, terminologia, serialização

```
[Serializable]
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Cpf { get; set; }
}
```

- Existe apenas um tipo de **serialização**?
- Quais as alternativas para não precisar **serializar** um objeto?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Serialização: O que é?

> Em ciência da computação, no contexto de armazenamento e transmissão de dados, a serialização é o processo de salvar ou transliterar um objeto em outro em um meio de armazenamento (como um arquivo de computador ou um buffer de memória) ou transmiti-lo por uma conexão de rede, seja em forma binária ou em formato de texto como o XML ou JSON. Esta série de bytes pode ser usada para recriar um objeto com o mesmo estado interno que o original.

Fonte: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serializa%C3%A7%C3%A3o (adaptado)

## Existe apenas um tipo de serialização?

Não. Existem vários tipos de serialização, sendo a diferença o formato final de representação dos dados. Por exemplo, utilizando o método `Json`, da biblioteca `Newtonsoft.Json`, você terá uma serialização JSON. Usando o objeto `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`, você poderá converter (ou serializar) um objeto no formato XML.

### Em JSON

```
var objeto = new { nome = "Nome", valor = "Valor" };
return Json(objeto, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

#### Resultado

```
{ 'nome': 'Nome', 'valor': 'Valor' }
```

### Em XML

Vou usar sua classe:

```
[Serializable]
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Cpf { get; set; }
}
```

Uso:

```
var pessoa = new Pessoa { Nome = "Nome", Cpf = "123.456.789-01" };
XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(pessoa.GetType());
x.Serialize(Console.Out, pessoa);
```

#### Resultado

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM437"?>
 <pessoa xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3
 .org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Nome>Nome</Nome>
    <Cpf>123.456.789-01</Cpf>
</pessoa>
```

## Como implementar no C#?

A serialização já é implementada no C# para diferentes formatos. A serialização deve ser vista primeiro como um conceito, e depois como um recurso de linguagem.

Você pode, inclusive, implementar sua serialização para o formato que desejar, mas o ideal é usar componentes prontos para evitar trabalhos extras.

Comment: Cigano, se possível você poderia criar uma pequeno exemplo de Serialização/deserialização? Tanto pra eu entender melhor o conceito como também a forma de implementar num projeto.

Comment: Ok, vou colocar pra você.

Comment: Muito bom @Cigano, o único problema é que fui testar o exemplo me retornou esse erro: Apenas tipos públicos podem ser processados.

Comment: @NULL Faltou um `public` em algum lugar do seu código.

Answer (score 15):

Só complementando a resposta já dada pelo @CiganoMorrisonMendez.

Algumas vezes simplesmente não é possível evitar a serialização:

- transmitir um objeto pela rede
- transmitir um objeto entre AppDomains
- se você quiser salvar um objeto em disco

Em todos esses casos, uma referência ao objeto vivo, simplesmente não faz sentido.

Comment: Ela nem deveria ser "evitável". O conceito é super importante para trocas de dados entre módulos e aplicações.

Answer (score 3):

Vou fazer algumas ressalvas, observações e vou responder o que não foi respondido.

## Serialização: O que é?

Usando a [Wikipedia em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) acho que a definição fica um pouco melhor.

> Na computação, serialização (ou serialização) é o processo de traduzir
> uma estrutura de dados ou estado de objeto em um formato que pode ser
> armazenado (por exemplo, arquivos em dispositivos de armazenamento
> secundário, buffers de dados em dispositivos de armazenamento
> primário) ou transmitido (por exemplo, fluxos de dados em redes de
> computadores) e reconstruída posteriormente (possivelmente em um
> ambiente de computador diferente). Quando a série de bits
> resultante é relida de acordo com o formato de serialização, ela pode
> ser usada para criar um clone semanticamente idêntico do objeto
> original. Para muitos objetos complexos, como aqueles que fazem uso
> extensivo de referências, esse processo não é direto. A serialização
> de objetos orientados a objetos não inclui nenhum de seus métodos
> associados aos quais eles foram vinculados anteriormente.

Um dos usos mais comuns é para transferência de dados entre processos, na mesma máquina ou em rede local ou remota (internet por exemplo). Então serializar é mais um mecanismo de comunicação entre processos de uma forma ou de outra, não importa a distância que eles estão ou depois de quanto tempo o objeto será reaproveitado.

## Existe apenas um tipo de serialização?

Não, existem várias formas de serializar, sendo o mais comum hoje em dia o uso de textos. No passado se usou mais formatos binários, mas foi percebedo-se problemas nisso. Na verdade, algumas pessoas usam hoje um formato um pouco mais híbrido, porque são textos, mas não muito legíveis, assim fica mais eficiente. Mas o texto puro ainda é o mais usado, não necessariamente o melhor, ainda que faça pouca diferença para a maioria dos usos. O formato JSON é o mais usado em transmissão, especialmente em ambiente web.

De fato, ela é usada em banco de dados, mas de forma bastante rara, pelo menos no modelo relacional. Em outros modelos como o de documento também pode-se questionar, porque sua aplicação não tem que serializar nada, ma o DB NoSQL costuma gerar um JSON ou BSON ou JSONB ou algo assim, o que parece serialização, mas é o formato dele não é usado o mesmo processo da aplicação. Pra mim a serialização ocorre quando há conhecimento dos objetos na memória (de certa forma existe isso em alguns DBs, mas só para a aplicação deles e não para a sua).

Note que existem casos de serialização que em vez de transmitir é armazenado, mas a forma como a maioria faz não é uma serialização. A não ser que você considere que qualquer forma que transmita ou armazena dados dos objetos seja serialização. Eu considero que é necessário ser um processo completo e linear de transformar de objetos em formato específico de uma aplicação e tecnologias (linguagens) em memória para um formato universal e estável que pode ser entendido por qualquer tecnologia em qualquer circunstância para reformar o objeto em outro local através de uma desserialização, com esse objetivo e não apenas por acaso.

Por exemplo, criar um XML de NFe geralmente não ocorre por serialização. Não é um formato universal para recriar o objeto do outro lado. Por acaso é criado um XML, obviamente em um formato que uma instituição definiu e ela usará como quiser lá, podendo criar um objeto completamente diferente quando eles recebem.

Algumas tecnologias permitem obter os dados serializados de forma mais automática que outras, e algumas mais eficiente que outras.

Outra questão é quantidade de mecanismos que podem usar. Você pode criar o seu, usar uma biblioteca externa ou usar um dos vários mecanismos contidos no .NET ou outra tecnologia se não estiver usando C#.

O .NET hoje tem uma forma muito boa, eficiente para gerar e recriar (nem tanto para transmitir, mas pelo menos é uma forma JSON mais universal). Não é mais tão recomendado usar o NewSoft como era no passado. Veja mais sobre esse [mecanismo novo em outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174637/101) que eu dei.

Veja uma [comparação dos vários formatos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data-serialization_formats) que são usados hoje em dia (pena não ter um indicador de popularidade, ainda que JSON ou algo parecido é claramente mais popular que todo o resto. [Protobuf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) é forte em alguns cenários por ser binário e mais eficiente. Eu gosto de alguns formatos que suportem *zero copy* para alguns usos, como o [Flatbuffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlatBuffers), mas não pode usar com qualquer tecnologia.

Na minha opinião, na maioria dos cenários é uma bobagem querer que a serialização seja legível por um humano.

## Como implementar no C#?

O mecanismo é melhor não, use um pronto.

Usar um mecanismo depende do que vai usar. Pode ser só chamar um simples método para serializar e outro para desserializar, ou ter algo mais sofisticado.

É comum em sistemas que fazem muita serialização usar [anotações para indicar o que deve ou não deve ser serializado](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?view=net-7.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), sejam tipos ou membros do tipo.

Note que só campos explícitos ou implícitos através de propriedades podem ser serializados, métodos e análogos a eles não podem.

Um exemplo retirado da [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397):

```
using System.Text.Json;

namespace SerializeExtra {
    public class WeatherForecast {
        public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureCelsius { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public string? SummaryField;
        public IList<DateTimeOffset>? DatesAvailable { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, HighLowTemps>? TemperatureRanges { get; set; }
        public string[]? SummaryWords { get; set; }
    }

    public class HighLowTemps {
        public int High { get; set; }
        public int Low { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            var weatherForecast = new WeatherForecast {
                Date = DateTime.Parse("2019-08-01"),
                TemperatureCelsius = 25,
                Summary = "Hot",
                SummaryField = "Hot",
                DatesAvailable = new List<DateTimeOffset>() { DateTime.Parse("2019-08-01"), DateTime.Parse("2019-08-02") },
                TemperatureRanges = new Dictionary<string, HighLowTemps> {
                        ["Cold"] = new HighLowTemps { High = 20, Low = -10 },
                        ["Hot"] = new HighLowTemps { High = 60 , Low = 20 }
                    },
                SummaryWords = new[] { "Cool", "Windy", "Humid" }
            };
            var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true };
            string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast, options);
            Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8mCMdt). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/Serializable.cs).

## Quais as alternativas para não precisar serializar um objeto?

Grande parte dos trabalhos não precisa de serialização. Em muitos casos você pode apenas escolher manualmente em um formato específico ou sem formato o que vai transmitir ou armazenar sem ler todo objeto e usar algo mais universal. Quando guarda em um banco de dados, talvez com uma *query* SQL não está usando serialização. O mesmo quando gera um arquivo XML, CSV ou algo assim com dados específicos que não podem, não devem ou não tem intenção de reproduzir exatamente o objeto em memória em outra circunstância. Se tiver muita serialização é um caso específico ou abuso.

Veja também:

- [Qual é o propósito da serialização?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/392202/101)
- [O que é JSON? Para que serve e como funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4042/101)
- [Qual a finalidade da interface Serializable?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88270/101)