# Como ler xml com c#

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin

Quero criar uma aplicação para android com C# usando Xamarin, ela pega em uma "base de dados" xml umas informações e coloca ela na tela, porém não estou conseguindo manipular o xml.

Preciso procurar o "simbolo" no xml e se achar pegar as informações e colocar em variáveis, porem não estou conseguindo:

Exemplo do xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Itens>
  <tb>
    <simbolo>G</simbolo>
    <nAtomic>56</nAtomic>
    <valencia>5</valencia>
  </tb>
  <tb>
    <simbolo>Ga</simbolo>
    <nAtomic>565</nAtomic>
    <valencia>55</valencia>
  </tb>          
</Itens>
```

Quando uso o `StreamReader`:

```
StreamReader strm = new StreamReader ("Db.xml"); 
XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(strm); //......
```

Dá o seguinte erro:

> Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StreamReader' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)

Pensei em usar o `XmlTextReader` mas nao sei como faço, alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: adicione using System.IO; no início do arquivo.

Comment: agora o erro que tem é esse:  Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'XDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)

Comment: Você pode colocar seu código completo na pergunta, por favor?

Comment: @Lucas faça referência a `System.Xml.Linq` no seu projecto e adicione o `using System.Xml.Linq` no seu `.cs`.

Comment: @Lucas quem é que cria o XML? O schema foi definido por si?

Comment: Da uma olhadinha nessa pergunta, espero que ela o ajude no que você precisa. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13087/o-que-%C3%A9-serializa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-quando-usar-como-implementar-no-c

Comment: adicione using System.Xml.Linq; no início do arquivo.

Comment: Obrigado a todos, mas... alguem sabe de algum tutorial que encina como manipilar arquivos xml com a classe XDocument? c.c

Answer (score 3):

Eis uma demo básica usando o W3C DOM e XPath. Você pode incluir em um método que receba o símbolo (DOM é uma API burocrática - se seu problema for mais complexo talvez fique mais simples se você usar Linq.)

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace XmlTest
{
    public class TesteXML
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("Db.xml");
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument(); 
            doc.Load(reader);
            reader.Dispose();

            string simbolo = "G";
            XmlElement tb = doc.SelectSingleNode("//tb[simbolo='"+simbolo+"']") as XmlElement;

            Console.WriteLine("simbolo: "  + tb.GetElementsByTagName("simbolo")[0].InnerText);
            Console.WriteLine ("nAtomic: " + tb.GetElementsByTagName ("nAtomic")[0].InnerText);
            Console.WriteLine("valencia: " + tb.GetElementsByTagName("valencia")[0].InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

Usando o arquivo que você forneceu, ao executar o programa acima você obtém:

```
simbolo: G
nAtomic: 56
valencia: 5
```

Comment: Um detalhe. O `XmlTextReader` é desnecessário, basta passar o caminho do ficheiro para o método `.Load(string)` do XmlDocument. No entanto se quiser usar o `XmlTextReader` não se esqueça de chamar o `.Dispose()`.

Comment: O `.Close()` nao chama o `.Dispose()` @Omni?

Comment: não. Mas o `.Dispose()` chama o `.Close()`.

Comment: Ah, eh o contrario :) Vou corrigir. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra forma é XDocument e Linq.

```
var resultado = (from x in System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(".\\Db.Xml"))
                   .Descendants("tb")
                   let simbolo = x.Element("simbolo").Value
                   let nAtomic = x.Element("nAtomic").Value
                   let valencia = x.Element("valencia").Value
                   select new 
                   {
                           simbolo, 
                           nAtomic, 
                           valencia
                   })
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: A não ser que use o `let` para verificar que o elemento existe (i.e `where simbolo != null`, não são necessários e pode colocar o `x.Element(...).Value` directamente no `select` de forma a tornar mais intuitivo o código.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16366/discussion-between-omni-and-maria).