# Retornar valores do BD via ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

Possuo uma tela onde devo popular com valores do banco de dados utilizando ajax.

Quando clico no botão para preencher os campos aparece o seguinte erro:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

Não sei o que está acontecendo.

Código Model:

```
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string client_id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string client_cnpj { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string client_companyname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string client_fantasyname { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string client_namerepresentative { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string client_cep { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(255)]
    public string client_street { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string client_number { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(55)]
    public string client_complement { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string client_neighborhood { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string client_city { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2)]
    public string client_uf { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string client_email { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string client_phone1 { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(15)]
    public string client_phone2 { get; set; }

    public int? client_currentcarrier { get; set; }

    public int? client_voice { get; set; }

    public int? client_web { get; set; }

    public int? client_renegotiation { get; set; }

    public DateTime? client_datevisitorcontact { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string client_note { get; set; }

    public int? client_statusnegotiation { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string client_company_id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string client_supervisingconsultant { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string client_supervisingsalessupport { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string client_consultant { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string client_salessupport { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string client_source { get; set; }

    public bool client_return { get; set; }

    public bool client_sendemail { get; set; }

    public DateTime client_dateregister { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("client_company_id")]
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HistoricFunnel> HistoricFunnel { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ActivityClient> ActivityClient { get; set; }
}
```

Código Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ReturnVisit(string id)
{
    var visit = _clientAppService.GetById(id);
    return Json(new { visit = visit });
}
```

Código JavaScript:

```
$(".visits-table tr a").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Visits/ReturnVisit",
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("entrou")
            alert(data)
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Comment: falta uma virgula após data: { id: id },

Comment: No código tem a virgula rs, apaguei um comentario que tinha embaixo, ai a virgula foi junto. Ele vai ate o servidor, so nao retorna a class.

Comment: tenta fazer igual exemplo abaixo retirando [HttpPost]

Answer (score 1):

O erro 500 é um erro HTTP genérico, não dá pra saber o que esta acontecendo. Você precisa ler a página com o resultado da requisição. Além disso, se o seu IIS não estiver configurado para mostrar os erros não vai resolver.
Tente configurar o IIS para desligar o "customErrors" configurando no Web.onfig

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
</system.web>
```

Depois execute seu código com erro e verifique exatamente qual o erro que está ocorrendo. Se você está usando para debugar o Firefox, use o Firebug e veja o resultado da Request Ajax na aba Console. No Chrome é a mesma coisa. Para entrar neste console tecle F12.

Outra coisa, parece que você esta tentando retornar uma classe de domínio "visit". Você nunca deve expor uma classe de domínio, sempre transforme sua classe de domínio em uma classe de ViewModel (POCO). Isso evita referência cíclica e outros problemas ao expor uma classe de domínio.

Comment: Vou fazer as modificações. Vou utilizar o Mapper pra resolver o problema do domínio.

Comment: Apareceu este erro no retorno: 
Não é possível encontrar o recurso.

Descrição: HTTP 404. O recurso que você está procurando (ou uma de suas dependências) não pôde ser removido, seu nome foi alterado ou está temporariamente indisponível. Examine o URL e certifique-se de que está digitado corretamente. 

URL solicitada: /Visits/ReturnVisit

Comment: HTTP 404 quer dizer página não encontrada. De alguma forma a requisição não encontrou seu método. Se você mudou seu ajax para fazer um GET e o método ainda está com o atributo HttpPost ele não irá encontrar seu me´todo /Visits/ReturnVisit

Comment: Ele esta como post no ajax tbm, por isso nao to entendendo.

Comment: Olha no console a URL que está sendo requisitada. Veja com atenção se não tem nenhum erro de digitação. HTTP 40 é Not Found. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmessages.asp

Comment: Mas quando modifico o tipo de retorno do controller funciona normalmente.

Comment: Quando coloco este retorno funciona: var resultado = new
            {
                client = "Linha de Código",
                URL = "www.linhadecodigo.com.br"
            };
            return Json(resultado, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);

Comment: Só olhando o código. HTTP 404 é Not found. Http 500 é erro genérico. Se você manda um POST, seu método espera um parametro ID e você não envia um ID, acredito que retorne 404 também. Uma boa prática é você definir uma classe no método que recebe o post invés de colocar como parâmetro um tipo primitivo. Tente algo como public class ReturnVisit(VisitPost post) { var c = _db.GetById(post.Id); return Json(c);  } e crie a classe: public class VisitPost { public int Id { get;set;} }

Comment: Vou testar aqui.

Comment: Qualquer coisa posta seu código aqui: http://collabedit.com/xyyht

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer por GET

```
$(".visits-table tr a").click(function () {
var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");

$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Visits/ReturnVisit",
    data: { id: id },
    success: function (data) {
        alert("entrou");
        alert(data);
    }
});

return false;
```

});

```
public JsonResult ReturnVisit(string id)
{
    var visit = _clientAppService.GetAll();
    return Json(visit,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Tentei desta maneira, tbm nao da.

Answer (score 0):

Dependendo da publicação no IIS da sua aplicação, colocar a URL direta da `controller/action` pode não ser legal. Utilize o poder do `razor`.

```
$(".visits-table tr a").click(function () {
    var id = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("ReturnVisit", "Visits")',
        data: { id: id }
        success: function (data) {
            alert("entrou")
            alert(data)
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Tome cuidado nas requisições... se o método da controller estiver anotado como `[HttpGet]` você deve fazer uma requisição `GET`. Se estiver como `[HttpPost]` você deve fazer uma requisição `POST`.

Sua controller

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ReturnVisit(string id)
{
    var visit = _clientAppService.GetAll();
    return new JsonResult { Data = visit };
}
```

Seu modelo tem que ser `[Serializable]`:

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class Client
{

....

}
```

Toda propriedade que for uma Classe, essa classe tem que ser serializada também.

[Mais a respeito da serialização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13087/o-que-%C3%A9-serializa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-quando-usar-como-implementar-no-c)

Comment: Ela esta HttpPost, a url funciona perfeitamente, na hora de retornar q da pau.

Comment: Vou testar com esse codigo.

Comment: Coloquei uma edição no retorno da controller...já testou o retorno do `_clientAppService.GetAll()`? Porque o `id` que você recebe por parâmetro não é nem usado....

Comment: Ele retorna um unico cliente, estava testando com uma lista, mas tbm nao funcionou, o correto é GetById(id).

Comment: Qual o objeto que você retorna? Tem como colocar a classe dele aí na pergunta?

Comment: Vou colocar agora.

Comment: E você precisa retornar todos as propriedades preenchidas? Você tem que serializar essa classe aí... vou editar minha resposta pra você ver.

Comment: Não, somente algumas. Vou modificar aqui.

Comment: Não funcionou Marllon.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47003/discussion-between-marllon-nasser-and-samuel-phellip).