# C# tem serialização nativa?

Tags: c#, serialização, desserialização

Em PHP existe um recurso de serialização de dados próprio da linguagem. Quero dizer: Não estou falando de usar `JSON` ou `XML`, mas falo de uma serialização em um formato que é próprio da linguagem.

Por exemplo, se eu quiser serializar um `array` ou um `objeto`, consigo fazer isso facilmente.

```
serialize(['a' => 1, 'b' => 2])
```

O resultado será:

```
'a:2:{s:1:"a";i:1;s:1:"b";i:2;}'
```

Se eu quiser desserializar esses dados, eu posso invocar a função `unserialize` para converter esses dados para um valor válido em PHP.

Veja:

```
unserialize('a:2:{s:1:"a";i:1;s:1:"b";i:2;}')
```

O resultado será:

```
[
  "a" => 1,
  "b" => 2,
]
```

Concluíndo, trata-se de um formato específico, onde a própria linguagem entenderá quais dados precisam ser convertidos.

Em C# existe algo similar? Existe alguma forma de serialização de dados nativa da linguagem?

**Nota**: Apenas reforçando: Não estou falando de JSON ou XML, mas de uma forma nativa, como demonstrada no exemplo do PHP.

Comment: Pode notar que serialização pode ser qualquer formato, uma linguagem pode adotar o Json como padrão por exemplo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sim, é possível, o .NET fornece essa possibilidade através de reflexão. Mas não se preocupe, não tem que fazer nada demais, basta dizer o que deseja que seja serializável. Basta usar o atributo [`Serializable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.serializableattribute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) que o *framework* sabe o que tem que fazer. E se precisar que alguns membros não participem da serialização pode usar [`NonSerializable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nonserializedattribute?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0).

É possível obter a serialização em formatos diferentes conforme a necessidade, seja texto ou binário ([exemplo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0)) que é considerado mais ou menos obsoleto, pelas dificuldades que ele impõe. É preciso algum formato. Se quer saber se há uma formato inventado pelo .NET, só o binário, em geral se usa JSON para texto.

Obviamente que alguns casos precisam de algo mais personalizado e a serialização padrão não funciona. Aí a solução é implementar a interface [`ISerializable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) com a lógica que seja mais adequada para o que precisa.

Nem sempre precisa pedir para serializar ou deserializar, o *framework* usado pode cuidar disso para você nos casos que ele sabe que é o que precisa. Obviamente não o fará em tipos não serializáveis.

Existem algumas bibliotecas externas que são mais performáticas e muitas pessoas dão preferência ao nativo. Um deles é o [NewtonSoft Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), o mais usado hoje em dia (que é usado por alguns *frameworks*). Outro é o [protobuf.NET](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) criado por um funcionário da SE. Mas agora o .NET tem uma forma [oficial melhor que todas as outras](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) pelo menos em alguns pontos.

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). E [novo mecanismo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Não conheço profundamente a serialização do PHP, mas deve funcionar de forma muito semelhante.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: No Java tem o problema da versão, de uma versão para outra pode mudar o formato e aí as serializações dos objetos ficam incompatíveis. No C# tem isso também? (desculpe se já está respondido, li por cima e não entendo muito de C#)

Comment: @Piovezan depende, não tem problema de versão de serialização, pode ter se você usar serializações totalmente diferentes e tem problema de versão do objeto. Isso não tem muito jeito sem um mecanismo que cuide disso. Esses mecanismos costumam ter alguma forma de lidar com versões e não dão problemas fáceis de resolver, mas nem tudo é simples e sua aplicação precisa lidar com isso..

Comment: É isso, versão do objeto, confundi.

Answer (score 0):

O dot net tem nativamente o `BinaryFormatter`, a serialização é até que rápida, mas se seu objeto é um grafo muito grande e complexo, a deserialização pode ser lenta. Para uso em produção normalmente usa-se bibliotecas de terceiros.

Como já foi dito, é só marcar a classe (e as classes contidas) com `[Serializable]`.

```cs
/*
    Importe:
    using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
*/

SeuObjeto objeto = new SeuObjeto(); // Pode ser qualquer tipo serializavel

BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

MemoryStream data = new MemoryStream();

// Para serializar:
formatter.Serialize(data, objeto);

data.Position = 0;

// Para deserializar
objeto = (SeuObjeto)formatter.Deserialize(data);
```

Se quiser excluir algo da serialização marque com `[NonSerialized]`

Outro detalhe, o binary formatter usa disposição `little endian`, não precisa se preocupar com isso.

Answer (score -1):

A Microsoft adotou o Newtonsoft.NET, um pacote terceiro adotado como Oficial, como o cara responsável para fazer serializações dentro do ambiente .NET.

Sua utilização é extremamente simples, basta primeiro instalar o pacote [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json) no seu projeto via [NuGet Packager Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManager) ou via [Packager Manager Console](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/package-manager-console):

> PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

Depois, para serializar:

```
Product product = new Product();
product.Name = "Apple";
product.Expiry = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small" };

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
// {
//   "Name": "Apple",
//   "Expiry": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//   "Sizes": [
//     "Small"
//   ]
// }
```

Para desserializar:

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
// Bad Boys
```

Ou usando LINQ:

```
JArray array = new JArray();
array.Add("Manual text");
array.Add(new DateTime(2000, 5, 23));

JObject o = new JObject();
o["MyArray"] = array;

string json = o.ToString();
// {
//   "MyArray": [
//     "Manual text",
//     "2000-05-23T00:00:00"
//   ]
// }
```

Para saber mais, veja a página oficial do [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Comment: Olá Thiago, blz? Então, a pergunta pede algo nativo e que não trate especificamente com JSON ou XML. Acho que sua resposta vai contra as duas premissas feitas na pergunta, por isso que votei negativo.

Comment: @Randrade O fato é que não existe nada nativo no .NET. A Microsoft adotou a lib Json.NET como oficial para realizar Serializações e vice versa. Ela não possui um formato especifico, proprietário, como o PHP, ela simplismente deixou a cargo da Newtonsoft definir isso, e ela usa o JSON como formato de serialização.

Comment: Então, se eu for responder exatamente, ficaria algo como "Nao há nada nativo sobre isso no .NET, nem serializador, nem formato de serialização". Mas isso não quer dizer que não exista algo Oficial. E se for tratar o Oficial como Nativo, então a resposta seria a mesma: "Instala Json.NET como NuGet package e o formato nativo adotado é o JSON".

Comment: @Randrade de qualquer forma, obrigado por explicar a negativa. Poucos fazem isso, e os que fazem merecem devido reconhecimento. :)

Comment: Bom, sobre não existir isso não é verdade. A resposta abaixo mostra que tem o `SerializableAttribute` e se quiser pensar mais além (e em Json), também existe o `DataContractJsonSerializer`. Ambos nativos.

Comment: Sobre a parte da MS tornar a Json.NET como lib oficial e JSON como formato oficial de serialização, eu desconheço essa informação. Se possuir algum link falando isso, ficarei grato por me mostrar essa informação.

Comment: @Randrade  Sobre o Json.NET ser o oficial, nao creio que exista esse anuncio formal, mas basta conferir que todas as libs oficiais Microsoft que dependem de um serializador, usam Json.NET como o Oficial. Vide dependencias do package [Microsoft Asp.Net Web API](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/).

Comment: Então @Thiago, você está focando em JSON (Web API é mais utilizado para Json hoje em dia) e o AP deu ênfase que não está querendo uma resposta sobre esse assunto, por isso meus comentários. Sobre as notações, o Json.NET utiliza elas por ser conveniente, mas uma coisa não tem relação com a outra. Se observar bem, o [SerializeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx) está disponível desde a versão 1.1 do .Net.

Comment: Como as finalidades são similares, foi conveniente a utilização. Porém, o Json.NET poderia criar seu próprio attributo para isso, assim como é o caso de várias coisas únicas do pacote. Lembrando também que existe até [uma comparação](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonNetVsDotNetSerializers.htm) entre 3 Serializers no próprio site do Json.NET.

Comment: Devo ressaltar que concordo com a utilização dele e acho sim que é o melhor para essa finalidade. Porém, só ressalto que essa não foi a pergunta do AP.

Comment: .NET não tem formato de serializacao nativo ou proprietário como o PHP. O formato adotado inicialmente desde .NET 1.1 é o XML - por isso o `SerializeAttribute` desde então. Em seguida adotou o JSON como formato Oficial, e usando a lib Json.NET como lib oficial de serialização.