# O que é uma variável persistente?

Tags: terminologia

Estava lendo um artigo acadêmico que falava sobre variáveis transientes e persistentes. O artigo descrevia estes como "classes de variáveis" e definia transientes como:

- abstração de uma célula ou conjunto de células de memória
- atualizadas através de atribuição

Pela definição acima, para ser uma variável comum que utilizamos no dia a dia. O problema é a definição vaga que o artigo dá para variáveis persistentes:

- tempo de vida transcende a ativação de qualquer
  programa
- arquivos e bancos de dados

Pesquisando um pouco mais na internet, vi que esses termos estão bastante associados também com sistemas de distribuição e otimização.

Eu gostaria de saber a definição formal e detalhada destes dois conceitos, e suas possíveis vantagens e desvantagens.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Uma variável transiente, assim como comentado pelo autor da pergunta, é a variável que nós utilizamos comumente nas linguagens de programação, isto é: uma variável que aponta para um espaço na memória e armazena um valor temporariamente, até que o seu tempo de vida se encerre — no término de uma *stack* ou do processo.

Uma variável persistente é uma variável que armazena a informação por tempo indeterminado, mantendo o seu estado mesmo após o término de um processo. Talvez, na prática, não seja adequado utilizar o termo "variável" para tal, contudo esse termo pode ser utilizado como uma abstração da persistência da informação de uma aplicação em um espaço de memória.

Dizemos que uma variável persistente guarda um valor ou objeto persistente, que nada mais é do que um objeto [*serializable*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13087/157404). Sendo assim, no geral, uma variável persistente não é uma "variável", mas sim uma implementação — estrutura de dados ou sequência de instruções — que permite salvar a informação, geralmente vinda de uma variável transiente.

Veja o exemplo — suponha que a classe abaixo esteja implementada na linguagem Python:

```
import atexit
import os

class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, nome=None, idade=None):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade

        if os.path.exists("pessoa.txt"):
            self.__recover()

        atexit.register(self.__exit)

    def __exit(self):
        with open("pessoa.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(f"{self.nome}={self.idade}")

    def __recover(self):
        with open("pessoa.txt") as file:
            self.nome, self.idade = file.read().split("=")
            self.idade = int(self.idade) + 1
```

Agora iremos utilizá-la, sem saber como a classe está implementada:

```
# Apenas uma variável, ou objeto, qualquer neste ponto de vista...
pessoa = Pessoa("Lucas", 20)

print(f"Meu nome é {pessoa.nome} e tenho {pessoa.idade} anos.")
```

Esse é um exemplo bem radical, porém exemplifica bastante o conceito. No código acima, embora seja definido na criação do objeto uma idade para `Pessoa`, conseguimos sempre recuperar a informação da execução anterior do código, somando (+1) à idade.

Por este viés, o artigo que você leu citava arquivos e bancos de dados, pois você pode abstrair o conceito e dizer que aquele grande espaço de memória não volátil, utilizado para armazenar um arquivo ou um banco de dados, é uma variável persistente.

Dito isto, como é de se imaginar, podemos também propagar os dados dessa variável persistente por uma rede e distribuí-la em vários dispositivos ou servidores. Dessa maneira, esse conceito também é aplicável no tema de sistemas distribuídos.

Comment: Por que deram downvote na minha resposta?