# Quais as principais diferenças entre Dart e TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, dart

Já tivemos uma [pergunta comparando duas linguagens que rodam em cima do JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101).

Acho que faltou comparar duas linguagens criadas com o propósito de criar aplicações para navegadores e resolver os problemas do JavaScript com abordagens bem diferentes. Escolhi estas duas porque elas possuem suporte de grandes fornecedores e competem pela atenção dos programadores.

Não é objetivo tentar fechar todas diferenças.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/) é uma linguagem criada pela Google para criar grandes aplicações. O objetivo inicial era prover não só uma linguagem, mas também uma infraestrutura melhor para desenvolver aplicações web. Mas como JavaScript é a língua franca da web Dart só pode viver se ficar o mesmo que CoffeScript, TypeScript e outras linguagens fizeram. Ela gera um código JS que pode rodar em qualquer navegador.

Como toda nova tecnologia precisa de um *killer application* para vingar, e mais recentemente o Flutter foi criado com ela, como caiu no gosto das pessoas Dart começou finalmente ser usada.

Certamente ela teria vantagens se pudesse rodar em sua própria [máquina virtual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_system) mas questões mercadológicas impedem que isto aconteça. Ainda assim a linguagem foi criada sem preocupação com compatibilidade com JS. Isto pode dar mais poder para ela mas pode criar algumas dificuldades com código legado e interoperabilidade. Ela brilha mais quando roda fora de navegadores padrões da web onde pode usar sua própria VM.

[TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) já foi criada desde o princípio não para ser uma linguagem nova, mas adicionar capacidades ao JavaScript existente. A sua ideia é que todo código JS seja automaticamente um código TypeScript válido. Isto limita um pouco a linguagem, não deixa resolver alguns problemas do JS mas é ótimo para a interoperabilidade.

TypeScript adicionou mais sintaxe do que semântica ao JavaScript. E as diferenças podem ser reduzidas já que o o próprio JS pode ter recursos novos que o TS colocou. Não sei como ficaria a compatibilidade disto no futuro. Talvez o objetivo não seja manter compatibilidade total para sempre, mas só aproveitar o que já existe agora.

Como TypeScript parece ter mais adoção, há mais ferramentas disponíveis que Dart. Não só a Microsoft está investindo forte nisto, mas terceiros estão suportando a linguagem. Inclusive há muito apoio da comunidade para gerar [anotações de tipo para bibliotecas JS](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) diversas que melhoram muito a interoperabilidade (que não é impedida se não tiver as anotações, só não provê facilidades de verificação de tipo).

Alguns recursos disponíveis do TypeScript:

- tipagem opcionalmente estática;
- classes, interfaces e *mixins*;
- expressões *lambda* com sintaxe simples;
- módulos;
- enumeração;
- *generics*;
- parâmetros opcionais e com valores *default*;
- tuplas;
- *union types*;
- alias de tipos;
- entre outros.

A linguagem já tem um *roadmap* e diversos outros recursos serão disponibilizados.

Dart provê a maioria destes recursos, mas de uma forma diferente. Além disto a linguagem já está mais avançada em outros recursos e possui algumas coisas que só são possíveis porque a compatibilidade de sintaxe não é necessária. Além disto ela fornece uma biblioteca própria e melhor manipulação do DOM, o que nunca foi o objetivo de TypeScript.

Algumas das coisas que existem em Dart que não existem em TypeScript:

- classes e interfaces estão mais alinhados com os conceitos de OOP e possuem mais recursos;
- baixo *footprint* através de *tree shaking* (só paga pelo que usa);
- *overload* de operador;
- escopo real (agora até JS tem);
- conversão de tipo implícita só onde faz sentido, melhorando o operador de igualdade;
- anotações;
- módulos funcionam de forma diferente;
- melhor uso de *generics*;
- reflexão;
- produz melhores otimizações;

Enquanto é possível ver poucas diferenças entre o código TypeScript e JS, na verdade muito do código TS desaparece por completo após a geração do código algo em JS, o código JS gerado por Dart difere bastante e possui uma estrutura um pouco estranha para um programador acompanhar. É difícil mexer no código gerado por Dart mas se o programador quiser depois de criar e compilar um código em TS ele pode facilmente continuar mexendo no JS (não que seja interessante).

## Conclusão

Fora os motivos psicológicos suscitados por uma ser da Google, outra ser da Microsoft, ambas melhoram a forma de desenvolver grandes aplicações. Elas não ajudam muito para fazer pequenos *scripts*. Ambas adicionam recursos importantes para organizar grandes bases de código e resolvem alguns problemas do JS. Dart faz isto de uma forma mais intensa e mais eficaz. TypeScript aproveita o que já existe.

Dart tem a intenção de ser uma alternativa ao JavaScript. TypeScript é apenas um compilador - cuja principal função é ser um verificador - e um sistema de tipos em cima do JavaScript. Ainda que ambas gerem código JS como alvo.

O tempo passou, Dart foi reposicionado e Flutter o salvou, hoje a linguagem é usada para fazer clientes de formas geral.

As duas linguagens receberam muitas atualizações nos últimos anos e elas melhoraram muito, algumas das avaliações feitas em 2015 não valem mais para 2020.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).