# Alternativas para desenvolver em C# no Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio, mono, .net-core

Meu notebook tenho instalado o sistema operacional Ubuntu 14.
Tenho grande vontade de ingressar no desenvolvimento na linguagem CSharp.

Porém gostaria de saber se existe alguma boa alternativa em SO como o Linux, já que não possui um Visual Studio da vida.

Atualmente utilizo o MonoDeveloper, que dá até para iniciar estudos e familiarizar com a linguagem, porém me disseram que esse IDE possui algumas limitações (em relação ao Visual Studio do Windows).

Existe alguma outra alternativa para desenvolver em C# (aplicações para celular ou web) em Linux?

**Nota**: Lembrando que isso não se trata de um joguinho do tipo "prefiro esse ou aquele", mas estou aqui tentando achar uma alternativa para `Linux` mais próxima do Visual Studio do Windows.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Além do [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) que já usa, pode usar diversos outros editores ([Vim](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vim), [Emacs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CSharpMode), [Sublime](https://github.com/chrokh/csharp-build-singlefile-sublime-text-2), etc.), alguns possuem algumas facilidades para C#. Poucas. Outros possuem algo mais.

O [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) parece promissor e quem sabe um dia chegue perto do Visual Studio completo só para Windows pelo menos para desenvolvimento web e console (duvido que faça muito mais que isto tão cedo). Ele é de código aberto e está na mão da comunidade para ser estendido. Note que ele é um navegador baseado no [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/) e seu código específico é basicamente [TypeScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49408/101). Ele foi baseado no [Atom](https://atom.io/). Entenda que isto sempre trará limitações, ainda que não tanto quanto um navegador tradicional. Hoje ele é o queridinho de muita gente.

Tem também o [OmniSharp](http://www.omnisharp.net/), mas desconheço sua qualidade.

É possível encontrar alguns *plugins* bem fracos para outros IDEs como o Eclipse. Mas não vejo as pessoas usando.

A [JetBrains criou um IDE para C# multiplataforma](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) que é muito bom e nem precisa do Resharper :)

Ou alternativamente vá para o Windows, use o Visual Studio, de preferência com o Resharper e outros *plugins*, e seja feliz. Só evite rodá-lo em VM. Não sei se as VMs melhoraram muito do tempo que tentei, mas o VS é pesado e exige muito da máquina, não acho ideal.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 7):

Eu gosto de utilizar uma plataforma similar ao Sublime text , chamada Atom e tem muitas linguagens que se pode usar e alguns plugins que podem ser usados para testes mas nada muito visual (tudo na base do editor de texto mesmo), mas vale apena dar uma olhada no youtube pra ver seu funcionamento.

Answer (score 4):

Infelizmente, desconheço uma solução melhor para desenvolvimento em Mono do que o Mono Develop. O Mono é a implementação da plataforma .NET para linux, e que serve de base para o Xamarin também. Mais detalhes nos links abaixo:

http://www.mono-project.com/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_(software)

Talvez uma boa alternativa seja o Visual Studio Code, mas ainda acho o mono develop o melhor