# Diferença entre o Visual Studio Community, Enterprise e Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Pretendendo aprender a programar **C#** e **.NET** para web e me deparei numa situação no momento de fazer o download do **Visual Studio**. Não sei exatamente qual das versões devo fazer *download*. Qual real diferença entre as edições?

Comment: https://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs 
nesse link você pode comparar as versões do visual studio.

Com relação a qual versão você deve baixar, eu particularmente tenho usado a versão Community que é gratuita e tenho achando bem satisfatório para o que preciso.

Comment: Esta questão se difere por incluir o Visual Studio Code, todo o resto é igual ou semelhante (já que lá tem até mais informações).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

O próprio site da Microsoft tem várias informações sobre as diferenças de cada um e ninguém vai conseguir de forma tão completa aqui.

Eu [já falei sobre as diferenças entre as edições diferentes do Visual Studio tradicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/121997/101) e não vou repetir aqui. Essa parte é duplicata.

| Feature | Visual Studio Code | Visual Studio |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Plataformas | Windows, Linux, Mac | Windows |
| Projeto aberto | Sim | Não |
| Custo | Gratuito | Tem opção gratuita |
| Leve e rápido | Sim (até onde dá, é web) | Não |
| Melhor adequação para aplicações | Front-end web/scripts | Todas |
| Extensibilidade | Fácil | Não tão fácil |
| Extensões disponíveis | Crescendo rápido | Ampla |
| Recursos padrões de IDE | Limitação | "Completo" |
| Capacidade de debug | Limitada | Completa |
| Organização em projetos e soluções | Não | Sim |
| Experiência de uso | Boa | Ótima |

O Visual Studio Code é um produto completamente diferente. Dá para usar bem para algumas coisas, especialmente TypeScript. A capacidade para C# pode melhorar, mas tem alguma limitação e nunca superará o VS normal, que é uma importante desvantagem.

Ele é bem mais leve e roda em todas principais plataformas existentes. Faz parte da iniciativa da Microsoft de disponibilizar suas tecnologias de desenvolvimento em diversas plataformas. Ele é totalmente gratuito (serve a qualquer propósito sem restrições) e aberto. Acredito que essas são as principais vantagens. Mas se for para usar em outra plataforma, [prefiro usar MonoDevelop ou Xamarin Studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/125953/101), dá para fazer muito mais e com experiência melhor.

Ele não começou do zero, é baseado no [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) que é um navegador web como ambiente de execução. Então tudo o que está vendo ali são aplicações web. O que mostra como dá para fazer coisas bem interessantes via web, e conforme a pessoa vai usando percebe que a experiência não é tão boa assim. Essa é uma desvantagem. Se não dependesse de um navegador seria mais leve ainda.

Parece que configurá-lo e estendê-lo é mais fácil que o VS. Outra vantagem, se precisar disso.

Ele não escala tão bem, cada vez mais vejo reclamações de quem começa ter soluções complexas nele.

Ele está em rápida mutação, e sinceramente colocar o que ele faz aqui tornará a resposta defasada muito rapidamente. O que eu acho mais interessante dele é acompanhar seu desenvolvimento e ver até onde pode chegar, é algo que desperta a curiosidade até onde pode chegar. Vou deixar alguns *links* para acompanhá-lo:

- [Página oficial](https://code.visualstudio.com/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [Github oficial](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code)

Isso pode ser útil: [Qual é o jeito correto de chamar as versões do C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21672/101)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 7):

As diferenças, de modo rápido, são as seguintes:

- **Visual Studio Community:** versão gratuita e completa para estudantes, desenvolvedores individuais ou para projetos de código livre.
- **Visual Studio Enterprise:** versão paga e completa, ideal para empresas.
- **Visual Studio Code:** versão *[opensource](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode)*, gratuita e multiplataforma (Windows, Linux e OS X). Serve para edição e *debugging* de código em diversas linguagens.
- **Visual Studio Professional:** versão paga com mais funções e serviços para desenvolvedores individuais ou equipes menores.

[Neste link](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-2015-products-vs) você pode comparar **com detalhes** as versões do Visual Studio 2015.

---

[image]

No seu caso, como você quer aprender a programar, o ideal seria a versão **[Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx)**, que conta com diversas funções úteis para seu aprendizado:

- **Produtividade:** *designer*, editor, *debugger*, *profiler* em uma só ferramenta.
- **Linguagens de programação:** programe em [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net), [f#](/questions/tagged/f%23), [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [python](/questions/tagged/python) e mais.
- **Xamarin**: você pode programar para Windows, Android e iOS em uma só linguagem.

Answer (score 3):

A versão do Visual Studio Code, funciona mais como um editor de texto avançado para programação, incluindo opções de debug. Comparo como se fosse um NotePad++ mais avançado e em evolução, é muito bom e continua crescendo.

Para o teu caso sugiro o Visual Studio Community, é de fato uma IDE com componentes, onde vc consegue programara, fazer compilação e um debug melhor.

O Visual Studio Pro é melhor se vc for fazer aplicação do tipo client server, aplicações em rede, por isso é ideal para profissionais que geralmente trabalham pelo menos em pequenas empresas ou projetos envolvendo banco de dados.

Já a versão Enterprise, aborda outras funcionalidades além da programação, entrando em aspectos de gerência, de poder visualizar em equipe e existe uma abordagem de testes, definitivamente é para quando se trata de programação por mais de 1 programador.