# O que é "Orientado a objeto" e quais outros métodos?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, orientação-a-objetos

Eu trabalho muito em `AngularJS` (JavaScript) e com a versão 2.0 batendo à porta, que terá como principal mudança a utilização de `ECMAS6` leio muito a respeito da Programação Orientada a Objeto. Se puderem manter as respostas nessa linguagem, já olhando para frente (ou melhor dizer, com base no `ECMAS6`), seria melhor.

Primeira dúvida: Já ouvi muito falar sobre programação "Orientada a objeto", quais outros tipos de programação existem?

Segunda dúvida, e mais importante:

O que é Programação Orientada a Objeto? Para qual fim ela é usada? Quando deve ser usada? Quando deve ser evitada?

Muitas das outras respostas tratam esse assunto de um modo muito técnico. Gostaria de uma resposta mais prática, consigo aprender melhor se eu vejo a aplicação da teoria. Então, se alguém puder responder isso com uma aplicação real da programação, seria ótimo. É por isso que estou fazendo essa questão, pois não consegui nenhum exemplo prático.

Comment: Relacionado: [Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos. O que são e quais suas principais diferenças?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13372/programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-funcional-e-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-orientada-a-objetos-o-que-s%C3%A3o-e-quais-suas)

Comment: A dificuldade de dar uma "resposta mais prática" é que é possível se programar bem em qualquer paradigma, de modo que alguém pode dar um exemplo de um sistema extremamente bem feito usando OO, e outra pessoa pode dar um exemplo tão bom ou melhor sem usar nada de OO. Isso diz pouco sobre o mérito relativo de uma ou outra abordagem. O que eu percebo é que existem algumas aplicações bem específicas em que o paradigma A ou B "se encaixa como uma luva" e acaba por realmente entregar as vantagens que promete, mas em outras não é assim tão bom como as alternativas. Difícil é listar todos esses casos.

Comment: Concordo com o @mgibsonbr, não é fácil responder isto com estes requisitos. Fiz o meu melhor ainda que eu ache que não está ideal. Se for orientando mais, eu vou melhorando a resposta.

Comment: Você programa com outra linguagem além de javascritpt? (uma que não seja OO)

Comment: Atualmente trabalho com AngularJS (e também HTML/CSS para web e webApp) e em conjunto com o pessoal do back-end (que é PHP). Se entendi bem as respostas, atualmente não, não trabalho.

Comment: Independente do trabalho, você programa (mesmo que por hobby) alguma outra linguagem ? É que com exemplos, ou prática de outras linguagens, fica mais fácil explicar.

Comment: @Intruso não não, exclusivamente essas, pelo menos até hoje, só essas. Até por que sou mais ligado à UX, web design, enfim.. Mais para parte de design e front-end. Mas por que?

Comment: Por que a resposta fica mais fácil de entender quando você pode comparar experiências de modelagem ou manutenção. Certos aspectos, como a definição de objetos, polimorfismo e herança (apenas alguns) são facilmente mostrados na prática, mas, as vezes, quando a pessoa usa outra linguagem, ficam dúvidas em qual a diferença disto para outras similaridades em outras linguagens, e o propósito da coisa fica muito nebuloso. Eu vou tentar montar uma resposta, mas, como tua área é mais o front-end, algumas coisas podem parecer estranhas... no princípio.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Já ouvi muito falar sobre programação "Orientada a objeto", quais outros tipos de programação existem?

Imperativa, Declarativa, Funcional, Lógica, *Dataflow*, *Function-level*, Concorrente, baseada em Autômatos, baseada em Arrays,... A lista é enorme, veja a caixa à direita [desse artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm) (em inglês) pra ter uma ideia.

> O que é programação orientada a objeto?

Ela consiste em dividir o design do sistema em pequenos módulos - chamados "objetos" - que unem **estado** e **comportamento** (i.e. dados e código que atue nesses dados). Cada objeto deve idealmente possuir responsabilidade limitada ("faz só uma coisa e faz bem") e não precisa (idealmente, nem deve) ter ter consciência do restante dos objetos que compõe o sistema (i.e. sua **dependência** a outros objetos deve ser limitada). Por fim, um objeto pode ter um ciclo de vida, mas a sequência exata em que seus diversos métodos serão chamados não é necessariamente definida *a priori* - em particular, quando um objeto é projetado não se precisa ter ainda uma visão do todo.

Um programa pode *utilizar* objetos esporadicamente, mas se os objetos são um aspecto central seja do sistema específico ou da linguagem/plataforma utilizada, então diz-se que ele é "orientado por objetos" (*object oriented*; ou no popular, "orientado *a* objeto"). Um sistema orientado por objetos consiste essencialmente em um conjunto de objetos trocando **mensagens** entre si. Uma mensagem é a chamada de um método, basicamente: se invoca uma função específica daquele objeto, passando argumentos, essa função age tanto nesses argumentos quanto no estado interno do objeto, e por fim retorna uma resposta a quem invocou a função. No decorrer disso, esse método pode enviar mensagens por sua vez a outros objetos, que também agirão de acordo.

A ideia do objeto é que ele seja projetado sem uma visão do todo, podendo ser incluído em diferentes sistemas sem alteração (i.e. reutilizado). Um bom objeto é projetado separadamente de qualquer sistema, e um bom sistema tem um mínimo de lógica própria além de "instanciar um bando de objetos" e "fazê-los trocar mensagens entre si". Pelo menos a teoria é essa (na prática, é difícil ver um sistema que segue esse protocolo à risca).

> Para qual fim ela é usada?

As *técnicas* da OO têm finalidades específicas: os objetos em si servem para reduzir o acoplamento e tornar o sistema bastante modular; a herança e a composição servem pra reutilizar objetos prontos em circunstâncias diferentes, sem modificação; o polimorfismo serve para criar funções "genéricas" que atuem em dados parecidos mas não idênticos; etc. Não sei dizer se a orientação por objetos como um todo tem um fim, exceto como proposta de organização lógica do código (que não é de forma alguma a única possível, como já visto no início da resposta).

> Quando deve ser usada? Quando deve ser evitada?

Quando as vantagens que promete forem de fato realizadas. Quando o domínio do problema não se "encaixar" bem no modelo OO, ou ainda quando outro modelo trouxer vantagens melhores.

Sério, não dá pra responder isso de forma genérica. Orientação a objetos é um conceito amplo, que engloba uma série de técnicas cada uma delas com suas vantagens e desvantagens. Felizmente, não há nada que nos obrigue a seguir um único paradigma a ferro e fogo, e as linguagens modernas têm incorporado mais e mais aspectos de paradigmas distintos (aumentando o ferramental que o programador tem à disposição para escolher). Assim, cabe ao programador analisar caso a caso se determinada técnica é necessária/desejável ou se ela pode ser deixada de lado caso o benefício não justifique o custo.

> Então, se alguém puder responder isso com uma aplicação real da programação, seria ótimo.

Imagine a seguinte situação: "pegue um número, e crie uma função a partir desse número, que cada vez que for invocada retorne esse mesmo número incrementado em N".

Uma solução orientada a objeto seria:

```
class Incremento {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    incrementar(n) {
        this.x += n;
        return this.x;
    }
}

// Uso

var inc = new Incremento(10);
inc.incrementar(2); // 12
inc.incrementar(3); // 15
inc.incrementar(1); // 16
```

Uma solução não orientada a objeto poderia ser (usando *closures* e funções de primeira classe):

```
function incremento(x) {
    return function(n) {
        x += n;
        return x;
    }
}

// Uso

var inc = incremento(10);
inc(2); // 12
inc(3); // 15
inc(1); // 16
```

Comment: `Ela consiste em dividir o design do sistema em pequenos módulos - chamados 'objetos' `. Simples e claro. Resposta perfeita! Já encontrei outras boas respostas, mas com muitos termos técnicos que não havia ficado claro pra mim. Digamos então, a grosso modo, que o OO é mais um "facilitador", criando pequenas execuções de tarefas para posteriormente montar o "Todo" (ou no caso, um sistema).

Comment: Isso mesmo! Um professor meu uma vez disse que idealmente deveriam existir dois tipos de programadores OO: os que criam objetos genéricos sem um sistema específico em mente, e os que simplesmente *usam* objetos prontos para "montar" um sistema (i.e. pegam uma coleção de objetos prontos, instanciam e os botam pra trocar mensagens entre si). Na prática, entretanto, isso raramente acontece - os objetos já são projetados com o sistema final em mente,e muitas vezes têm dependências implícitas ou explícitas a outras partes do mesmo que impedem de serem reutilizados em outras situações.

Comment: Sim, perfeito. Consegui compreender bem a lógica por trás disso. Tinha uma certa preocupação pois li que no ecmas6 (ou pelo menos AngularJs 2.0) seria utilizado muito OO, e como não sabia bem a finalidade, não sabia como seria o cenário.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade eu dei uma resposta, porque eu não acho esta definição que você citou muito boa (`Ela consiste em dividir o design do sistema em pequenos módulos`). Entendo que algumas pessoas se apegam a ela. Mas ela pode ser aplicada para outros paradigmas, talvez para todos eles. A resposta do mgibsonbr como um todo é muito boa. É claro que vou olhar o contexto, não só a frase solta.

Comment: @bigown com certeza, dentro do contexto da explicação dele, essa frase resumiu muito bem. Mas estou lendo sua resposta sim, e pelo pouco que vi, já estou com outros horizontes abertos.. O problema em tudo isso vai ser em qual resposta aceitar, só está vindo coisa top! hahaha

Comment: @bigown Realmente é uma definição simplista, mas a segunda parte - não citada - é o que eu considero o "ponto de ruptura" entre a programação imperativa tradicional e a baseada em objetos: unir o estado ao comportamento. Pois embora o conceito de "tipo" preceda o de "objeto", os tipos de dados eram normalmente dissociados das operações que atuavam sobre esses dados. Essa coesão (não necessariamente boa, diga-se de passagem) pra mim é um dos pontos centrais (embora pela minha idade eu nunca tenha chegado a experimentar de fato a programação estruturada, então meu ponto de vista é limitado).

Comment: @mgibsonbr eu concordo. Mesmo não tendo muito espaço, eu tomei o cuidado de não passar a ideia que tem erro aí e que o todo deixa mais claro. Se não houvesse o *comment* lá em cima com a frase solta, passaria desapercebido. E concordo mais ainda que a coesão e o acoplamento do estado com o comportamento pode ser bem maléfico e derrotar o intuito mais básico de modernizarem os estilos de programação. Você faz programação estruturada o tempo todo. Sabe bem o que é isto? Somente estruturada, sem mais nada talvez você nunca tenha feito mesmo. Eu já fiz :D

Comment: @bigown " Você faz programação estruturada o tempo todo. Sabe bem o que é isto?" sim, eu me refiro de fato a "somente estruturada". Eu tive um pouquinho de programação não estruturada também, mas só na faculdade, estudando software básico (*assembly*). E eu me lembro de ter feito um joguinho em C na adolescência, mas como eu aprendi sozinho, não faço ideia se minhas práticas eram boas ou não (provavelmente eram horríveis rsrs). Mas eu nunca tive contato com um sistema profissional que não fosse OO, por isso minha dificuldade de entender o quão diferentes eles são.

Comment: Eu dou tanta risada dos meus código antigos. de 84, de 94. 2004 e 2014 :D Você deve imaginar que eu acho uma pena como OOP entrou na cabeça deas pessoas da forma como entrou. E sabe que não sou *hater* do paradigma (talvez do uso excessivo dele :) ), mas tem gente que lê meus *posts* e acha que sou. Deve ser culpa minha, mas fazer oque, é meu jeito... :D

Comment: @mgibsonbr resposta muito boa, parabéns! Mas só pra ver se eu entendi bem, em seu último exemplo eu poderia dizer que está usando o paradigma funcional?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Não, pois no paradigma [puramente] funcional não existem variáveis de estado - então não dá pra implementar a função `incremento` sem usar alguns "truques" (como *monads*). Uma função no paradigma funcional sempre vai retornar o mesmo valor dados os mesmos argumentos (em outras palavras, ela não pode ter efeitos colaterais). Aqui, se eu fizer `inc(1)`, `inc(1)`, `inc(1)` ele vai retornar `11`, `12` e `13` - valores diferentes para o mesmo argumento. Pois essa função depende da variável de estado `x`, que muda de valor sempre que a função é invocada. Ou seja, não é funcional.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @mgibsonbr , então esse último exemplo poderia ser classificado em que paradigma?

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Não existe uma resposta única, pois os paradigmas não são mutuamente excludentes. Eu diria que esse exemplo é [imperativo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_imperativa), [procedural](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_procedural), [estruturado](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_estruturada) e [*value-level*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value-level_programming), mas pode haver outros paradigmas não citados no qual ele também se encaixe... Mas certamente não é declarativo (inclui funcional e lógico) nem orientado a objeto.

Answer (score 10):

## Paradigma

Na [Wikipedia tem um artigo que explica bem o que são os paradigmas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_paradigm), que é o nome correto do que está chamando de "método". Tem muitos, basta ver a tabela do lado direito do artigo. Disparado o mais usado é o imperativo. Praticamente todas linguagens *mainstrem* o usam de forma intensiva. Falo sobre isso com mais detalhes [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101).

> Um paradigma de programação fornece e determina a visão que o programador possui sobre a estruturação e execução do programa. Por exemplo, em programação orientada a objetos, os programadores podem abstrair um programa como uma coleção de objetos que interagem entre si, enquanto em programação funcional os programadores abstraem o programa como uma sequência de funções executadas de modo empilhado.
>
> Assim como diferentes grupos em engenharia de software propõem diferentes metodologias, diferentes linguagens de programação propõem diferentes paradigmas de programação. Algumas linguagens foram desenvolvidas para suportar um paradigma específico (Smalltalk suporta o paradigma de orientação a objetos enquanto Haskell suporta o paradigma funcional), enquanto outras linguagens suportam múltiplos paradigmas (como o LISP, Perl, Python, C++ e Oz).
>
> Os paradigmas de programação são muitas vezes diferenciados pelas técnicas de programação que proíbem ou permitem. Por exemplo, a programação estruturada não permite o uso de goto. Esse é um dos motivos pelo qual novos paradigmas são considerados mais rígidos que estilos tradicionais. Apesar disso, evitar certos tipos de técnicas pode facilitar a prova de conceito de um sistema, podendo até mesmo facilitar o desenvolvimento de algoritmos.

## Exemplos de paradigmas mais conhecidos

O paradigma da [orientação a objeto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) é o que está mais na [moda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_circus). Boa parte das linguagens o aceitam nativamente adicionalmente ao [imperativo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_imperativa) e outros, como o [funcional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) que é outro que também é muito adotado nas linguagens modernas, e em algumas menos usadas é o paradigma principal ou único.

Linguagens mais úteis e mais gerais são mais pragmáticas e multi-paradigma. Ultimamente a [generacidade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_programming), [refletividade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)) ou [meta-programação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming) ganhoram força.

A [orientação a aspectos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) ou a [eventos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) e [concorrência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_object-oriented_programming) ganharam força também, ainda que em menor grau.

A [forma declarativa de programar](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_declarativa) também é forte. Muitas vezes ela é usada para auxiliar a programação, como é o caso de SQL, XML e derivados.

O paradigma pode eventualmente determinar a [dinamicidade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language) da linguagem (não confundir com tipagem dinâmica, que normalmente está presente neste tipo de linguagem, também). Este é outro paradigma. E ele pode ser um substituto da meta-programação em muitos casos, ainda que eles não sejam "concorrentes" diretos, seus objetivos são diferentes.

Eu sempre quis aprender [programação lógica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_programming), mas "nunca tive tempo". Parece algo bem interessante que deveria ser mais *mainstream*.

Poderia continuar citando outros, mas dificilmente vou falar de algo que seja amplamente usado. É fato que sempre usamos algum paradigma menos conhecido em várias partes do código. Alguns paradigmas são muito simples, exigindo algo bem contido, então praticamente qualquer linguagem que implemente um paradigma mais geral, deve implementar estes paradigmas secundários.

## Classificação da linguagem por paradigmas

Alguns paradigmas são muito parecidos com outros, alguns possuem uma sub-divisão. OOP, por exemplo, tem dois "sabores": [baseado em classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming) ou [baseado em protótipos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming).

Note que no artigo da Wikipedia há uma hierarquia de paradigmas. Não sei o quanto isto é uma classificação formal, mas dá uma ideia de como há dependência de alguns deles. Acho que há mais dependência do que mostra ali. Pra falar a verdade acho aquele verbete bem falho.

Alguns paradigmas são bem arcaicos e não devem mais ser usados em nenhuma circunstância. Outros ainda não estão no ponto que podem trazer bons resultados sem grandes prejuízos na maioria dos casos. Os mais maldosos dirão que é o caso de OO :)

Mas só porque a linguagem tem um recurso deste tipo não significa que ela seja deste paradigma. A análise é um pouco mais complexa que olhar para um aspecto apenas.

Nem sempre estas definições são muito claras.

Só um exemplo do que define se uma linguagem é de um paradigma, no caso o funcional:

- Presença de funções de [alta ordem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) e [primeira classe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)
- [Pureza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purely_functional)
- [Recursão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) pra representar algoritmos repetitivos
- [Avaliação preguiçosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy) (opcional em algumas formas)
- Costuma ter uma [forma de tipagem específica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typed_lambda_calculus)
- [Transparência referencial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency)

Nem todos concordam com todas estas definições, mas é raro fugir muito disto, pode ser que um ou outro seja mais discutível. Tem linguagens que a discussão é bem maior. Vamos falar de uma delas, que é o foco da pergunta.

#### Estilo X paradigma

Usar o paradigma pode parecer mas não é a mesma coisa que usar o estilo do paradigma. PHP, por exemplo, costuma ter muita coisa podendo ser [expressada com estilo procedural e estilo OOP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101). Isso não quer dizer que está seguindo o paradigma no seu código. E possivelmente a pessoa nem percebe quando está usando o estilo ou o paradigma. O que é preocupante.

No início dos anos 90 muitas linguagens se definiram como OOP, mesmo que elas sequer permitiam criar uma classe ou outra forma de definir objetos. O estilo era OOP, o paradigma não. Não vendia se não dissesse que era OOP. Depois evoluíram, mas até hoje força-se o uso de OOP para "vender".

Procedural:

```
$conn= mysqli_connect(...);
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$results = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

Procedural com estilo OOP:

```
$conn = new MySQLi(...);
$res = $conn->query($query);
$results = array();
while ($row = $conn->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $results[] = $row;
}
```

Modular com classes parecendo OOP:

```
class GetResults { //poderia ter outras coisas aqui
    public function getResults() {
        $conn = new MySQLi(...);
        $res = $conn->query($query);
        $results = array();
        while ($row = $conn->fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $results[] = $row;
        }
        return $results;
    }
}
```

Um pouco mais OOP:

```
class GetResults extends Results { //tem um monte de coisa pronta em Results
    public function getResults() { //Results já tem um getResults pronto, este substituiu
        $res = $conn->query($query); //notou que conn existe em outro escopo?
        $results = array();
        while ($row = $conn->fetch_assoc($res)) {
            $results[] = $row;
        }
        return $results;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/OOP/CompareProcedural.php).

É um pouco sacanagem perguntar isso, mas qual você acha mais simples? :) Claro que os últimos exemplos estão adicionando funcionalidade que os primeiros não tinham. Perceba que os últimos tentam abstrair mais o que está sendo feito. Isso pode ser bom ou ruim. Eu vejo muita gente abstraindo o que não precisa, o que não dá ganho.

De uma certa forma podemos dizer que o código do PHP para lidar com os resultados do MySQL são um pouco o estilo funcional, principalmente como o `fetch_assoc()` opera.

## Orientação a objeto.

Não sei se posso acrescentar muito mais do que já postei em outras perguntas:

- [Significado da terminologia: "Orientado a objeto"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101)
- [PHP mistura códigos de orientação a objetos e linguagem procedural?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/104340/101)
- [Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos. O que são e quais suas principais diferenças?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/101)

#### Quando usar

É difícil afirmar categoricamente quando usar OOP ou não. Claro que é óbvio que se a linguagem não dá suporte, deve ser evitado. E se a linguagem força OOP ajuda se segui-lo. Há uma [pergunta que tenta chegar a uma conclusão sobre isso em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108204/101).

O tipo de problema deveria ser o que dirige a escolha. Mas olhando só para o problema, nem sempre é possível determinar se deve ou não optar por OOP. Há aspectos "políticos" a serem considerados.

Se você vai programar sozinho, se vai fazer algo pequeno, se não será muito durável e terá relativamente pouca manutenção, OOP não é muito indicado. Por exemplo, sites web não costumam ser complexos, é comum uma única pessoa ou uma equipe de programadores muito pequena dar manutenção. É comum ter pouca relação entre os vários componentes da aplicação, a execução costuma ser fragmentada. Claro que isto depende um pouco da linguagem usada também, se está usando algum *framework* complexo para "ajudar".

É comum ser fácil e simples usar um paradigma mais [procedural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming) e/ou [modular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) ou [**orientado a componentes**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering). Este último possui um modelo mental mais próximo do que o ser humano entende e reproduz bem melhor o mundo real (outra definição usada em OOP), e de fato algumas linguagens que se vendem como OOP são bem mais COP :P. Mas o marketing deste paradigma não foi tão bom. E é claro que ele tem seus defeitos. E é claro que se abusado fica difícil manipulá-lo.

OOP pode ser um fardo em vários casos. É como usar uma Ferrari em uma cidade brasileira, tem rua que simplesmente não dá para passar com um carro desses. É ruim usar um caminhão pra entregar uma única carta (lembra daquele papel que vai dentro de um envelope pra se comunicar com outras pessoas? :) ), mas [as pessoas vão usar quando elas só possuem o caminhão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument). Como funciona, elas acham que está bom assim.

OOP é bom quando você tem hierarquias de objetos, como o caso de GUI, a [*killer application*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aplicativo_matador) do OOP. Sem precisar de hierarquias, ou seja, sem precisar da ajuda de herança, pra que vai precisar de OOP?

Alguns vão dar outros motivos, mas aí começa falar de outro paradigma e chamar de OOP. Eu vejo algumas definições tão genéricas sobre OOP que podem ser aplicadas para "metade" dos paradigmas existentes. Aí fica parecendo que realmente ele é uma panaceia e todo mundo pode puxar o paradigma pro lado que achar melhor. Coisa típica de marketeiros. Eu prefiro decisões baseadas em engenharia.

Eu vejo muito os recursos de OOP serem usados para adotar a modularização. Isso é bom. Mas as pessoas o fazem sem consciência do que estão usando de fato.

OOP pode dar mais legibilidade para o código em certos casos, mas pode piorar em outros. OOP pode fazer o mesmo que outros paradigmas fazem, de outra forma. OOP pode agradar mais algumas pessoas que outras.

Vejo muitos casos de grandes *frameworks* se beneficiarem dele, mas não acho que é o único caminho para esse tipo de aplicação. Os consumidores desses *frameworks* se beneficiam bem menos de OOP, mas podem também, em alguns casos mais que outros.

Eu acho que [OOP não deveria ser a escolha *default*](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhatIsObjectOrientedProgramming.html) como muitas pessoas fazem. Pra decidir por sua adoção deveria existir uma boa justificativa, mesmo que mais política do que técnica.

Eu acho bastante curioso que muitos proponentes de OOP passaram, indiretamente, a [desincentivar o seu uso no que é único para ele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11378/101).

Escolher um paradigma até tem a ver com o fato da equipe saber usá-lo melhor. Não quer dizer que será a melhor decisão técnica, mas será a melhor política. É comum se escolher OOP por julgar que é o mais adaptado à equipe, mesmo que nem seja o melhor para o problema. Curiosamente, vejo acontecer o oposto, a equipe não sabe usá-lo mas acha que sabe e o adota por isso. Ela poderia fazer melhor em outro paradigma, não só porque o problema seria melhor expressado nele, mas também porque a equipe domina o outro melhor.

#### Definição

Não vou ficar repetindo as definições adotadas, porque nas perguntas *linkadas* acima já têm bastante coisa.

O fato de haver pouca concordância sobre o que é OOP dá uma ideia como é algo bem menos científico do que algumas pessoas pensam. Nota-se que alguns paradigmas possuem uma definição mais clara e universal.

Alguns vão dizer que já é OOP se o objeto é o centro da programação, que é a partir dele que tudo acontece. Eu acho isso simplista. Se for isso, eu acho que ele cabe bem quase sempre, mas também posso dizer o mesmo de usar de outra forma. Essa definição não me dá algo que me faz querer usá-lo em alguma coisa. E sabendo que pra dar essa sensação do objeto ser rei é necessário fazer coisas extras e [acoplar demais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101).

Eu prefiro o jeito mais simples, mais procedural/modular. Muitas pessoas preferem OOP para isso porque o material existente deste paradigma incentiva modularizar bem. Material de outros paradigmas não o fazem tão bem. O legado de códigos macarrônicos de certos paradigmas prejudicaram muito eles. O fato de nenhuma linguagem *mainstream* implementar algum paradigma que resolvia os problemas dos paradigmas mais antigos, ajudou dar gás para OOP. Este paradigma subiu por uma boa razão, depois acharam que era para usar em tudo.

Vejo pessoas dizendo que ele é sobre o reuso. Claro, é, mas uma forma específica de reuso. A criação de funções é a forma mais forte de reuso que existe, e isto está em quase todos paradigmas, especialmente o procedural (ao contrário do que alguns acreditam, procedural não é o paradigma que tem procedimentos e funcional é o que tem funções, pelo menos não de forma tão simplista e mutuamente exclusiva, como acham).

Obviamente que algumas das "ferramentas" usadas pra obter a tal da OO, podem ser aplicadas isoladamente, mas não pode dizer que está programando orientado a objeto só porque está usando uma linguagem que suporta isso e/ou que usa uma das ideias fundamentais do paradigma isoladamente.

OOP é um brinquedo de Lego, outros paradigmas também são. OOP coloca regras que ajudam evitar construir coisas muito esquisitas, mas também dificulta montar certas formas.

A definição da resposta do mgibsonbr é boa, eu concordo com ela, mas acho que muito do que está ali serve para outros paradigmas. Concordo mais ainda que é difícil definir quando usar. As pessoas esperam uma resposta mágica e definitiva. mas isso não existe.

#### Uso errado

OOP se vende bem, mas vende sua ideia real muito mal. Tanto que a maioria dos códigos OOP que se vê por aí são verdadeiras atrocidades. Como a pessoa não entende o paradigma mas quer usar porque está na moda ela faz pior do que se usasse algo que ela consegue entender melhor.

## JavaScript

[JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) foi originalmente concebida e continua sendo uma linguagem imperativa, com características procedurais, funcionais e é orientada a objeto por protótipos. Não me lembro se adota algum outro paradigma de forma clara e substancial (talvez podemos chamar de linguagem dinâmica, o que pode permitir, por tabela, diversos outros paradigmas, ainda que isso pode não ser o mais recomendado - o `eval()`, especialmente, opera "milagres" e o uso de eventos é muito forte nela). Agora foi adotado também a OO baseada em classes e parece que vai adotando novas funcionalidades que vão facilitando outros paradigmas. E se ela evoluir para o que o [TypeScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101) (a linguagem de AngularJS 2) está adotando então adotará outros paradigmas, como o de generacidade, que passou ser fundamental em linguagens estáticas (isto pode acontecer com JS, há muita vantagem nisso e JS, hoje, precisa disto mais que PHP, por exemplo).

Até onde sei, Angular adota bem todos esses paradigmas que a linguagem fornece. O que não quer dizer necessariamente que você tenha que fazer o mesmo, sempre. Consumir um paradigma não é o mesmo que produzir código que implementa o paradigma. Infelizmente meu conhecimento sobre esta tecnologia não me permite falar muito mais que isto :P.

Comment: +1 muito boa a resposta, em particular a primeira parte que descreve os paradigmas. E vê se arruma um tempinho pra aprender programação em lógica! Eu acho Prolog fantástico (E/S é uma desgraça, mas o resto é show), se me perguntassem qual seria uma única funcionalidade que eu acrescentaria numa linguagem que já considero excelente (tipo Python) eu certamente responderia programação em lógica. :)

Comment: Não consegui nem aprender Haskell ainda que é prioridade (funcional como um todo eu ainda preciso aprender de verdade)

Comment: Pra mim, o pior com Lisp foi mudar a cabeça pra não usar variaveis. O paradigma funcional é muito prático em relação a uma modelagem matemática da coisa, mas, o hábito é uma coisa terrivel :).

Comment: @mgibsonbr nem acho que esteja tão boa. Dei uma melhorada agora. Mas também não acho que mereça negativo. Mas agora todo dia eu recebo vários negativos. Aparentemente é coisa normal já que não é em série, mas é estranho ter épocas que eu recebo negativos em boa parte do que respondo. Daqui a pouco a pessoa cansa e vê não não mexe na minha reputação. Pena que o conteúdo fica prejudicado.

Answer (score 2):

Orientação a objetos é uma paradigma de programação ou seja é uma forma de pensamento de como modelar e organizar software, além dos recursos já conhecidos como herença, polimorfismo e encapsulamento ou 'vantagem' que vendem é de que o software criado com essa abordagem é mais fácil de entender pois os objetos devem simular seus comportamentos e relacionamentos quase da mesma forma que ocorre no mundo real(abstração).

Outros paradigmas que existem são: funcional, procedural, orientado  a aspectos etc.

Comment: OE, Orientada a Eventos.