# Orientação de objetos é a parte do c# usada para jogos?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, unity3d

Que existem diferenças entre a linguagem c# para programação de formulários e para outras áreas, eu tenho noção, mas tenho uma dúvida: A orientação de Objetos é a parte usada para programação de jogos? Caso não: Qual o objetivo da Orientação de Objetos?

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_a_objetos

Comment: Escrevem jogos em linguagem de máquina, C puro, C#, Java e até mesmo em [sed](http://aurelio.net/projects/sedsokoban/). O que se utiliza de uma linguagem de programação para fazer jogos é sua capacidade de resolver problemas. No caso, a Unity escolheu usar C# como uma de suas linguagens de programação, junto a JavaScript. O uso de C# na Unity foi uma escolha para facilitar o reuso de soluções e, também, a parte relativa à estender uma solução para fim específico. A orientação a objetos torna esses reusos mais evidentes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Faça essa pergunta a si mesmo:

> O que define algo como um jogo?

Linguagens de programação, sendo baseadas em orientação a objetos, procedurais ou outros possíveis tipos não definem a qualidade necessária para se criar um jogo.

Existem vários tipos de jogos:

1. jogos de perguntas, que bastaria digitar um texto ou numero em um `input` (games estilo RPG de texto costumam ser assim)
2. Jogos 2d de plataforma
3. Jogos 3d variados

Mas o que definiu eles como jogos?

**Do meu ponto de vista** é a interação do usuário (e o tipo de interação), então uma linguagem de programação pode criar algo usado recursos gráficos e **não** necessariamente ser um jogo, mas sim uma animação que conte uma história baseado no movimento de elementos gráficos, ou seja seria um pequeno filme.

Agora falando só da parte gráfica, até mesmo com a combinação de [css](/questions/tagged/css)+[svg](/questions/tagged/svg)+[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) você pode criar um pequeno jogo (ou até mesmo um grande), não é a linguagem que é voltada para criar jogos, são os "recursos" que você dispõe, por exemplo, no passado não haviam plataformas, IDEs avançadas e nem linguagens como as de hoje, muitas coisas eram criadas "manualmente", claro que empresas grandes tinham ferramentas e *engines* para seus games, mas existiam pessoas que criavam algumas coisas do zero, inclusive criar uma *engine* geralmente devia ser algo criado quase que do zero.

Vou resumir então, em [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) não é a linguagem que lhe da a capacidade total e muito menos orientação a objetos para criar jogos de maneira eficiente, o que talvez "defina" isto são as APIs, ferramentas ou *engine* que você dispõe, como exemplo do [*Unity 3d*](https://unity3d.com), algo assim facilita a criação.

Isto não quer dizer que você não seja capaz de criar um game do zero, muito pelo contrário, qualquer linguagem que permita o mínimo o uso de recursos gráficos (geralmente pelo uso de APIs que controlem algum recurso de vídeo ou API gráfica do sistema operacional) seria quase que o suficiente para se criar algo.

Se tivéssemos a necessidade de uma linguagem especifica ou de orientação a objetos então "programadores" no passado, antes de existirem ferramentas como as de hoje, jamais teriam conseguido criar qualquer jogo.

### Respondendo as perguntas

> Que existem diferenças entre a linguagem c# para programação de formulários e para outras áreas, eu tenho noção

Isto não é uma pergunta, mas vou responder, a linguagem é a mesma, o que muda são as APIs ou pacotes usados, mas a linguagem não

> A orientação de Objetos é a parte usada para programação de jogos?

Não, a orientação seria mais para organizar, seja lá qual for o objetivo do programa

> Qual o objetivo da Orientação de Objetos?

Como respondi "organizar", mas de resto vou indicar os mesmos links que estavam relacionados (indicados pelo Maniero):

- [Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos. O que são e quais suas principais diferenças?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/3635)
- [O que é "Orientado a objeto" e quais outros métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108047/3635)
- [Significado da terminologia: "Orientado a objeto"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/3635)

Answer (score 3):

Veja [o que significa orientação a objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101). E [o que é](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108047/101). E ainda uma [comparação com o paradigma funcional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/101). E entenda [o que é paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101).

Então OOP é só uma forma secundária de organizar códigos. É uma forma que ajuda, mas é dispensável em todos os casos. Inclusive tem linguagens mais modernas que deliberadamente dispensaram a sua adoção.

De fato GUI e jogos são alguns dos mais beneficiados do seu uso, mas hoje se abusa e procuram fazer OOP não nem há vantagem. Mas ela em si não é parte de GUI ou de jogos.

Jogos dependem de bibliotecas e não de linguagens.