# Código JavaScript não executa prompt

Tags: javascript

O `prompt` não está aparecendo:

```
<script>
function numero(int num) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * num);
};
var chute = prompt("Qual e o numero? ");
var numeroPensado = numero(10);
if(chute == numeroPensado) {
    document.write("Acertou! " + numeroPensado + " era o numero");
} else {
    document.write("Erro! " + numeroPensado +  " era o numero");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript não possui anotação de tipos de dados nas variáveis e parâmetros, então o `int` causa o problema. Tem que tirar isto. Se deseja usar tipos, deve optar pelo [TypeScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101).

```js
function numero(num) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * num);
}
var chute = prompt("Qual e o numero? ");
var numeroPensado = numero(10);
if (chute == numeroPensado) {
    document.write("Acertou! " + numeroPensado + " era o numero");
} else {
    document.write("Erro! " + numeroPensado + " era o numero");
}
```

Ou mais simplesmente:

```js
var numeroPensado = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
document.write((prompt("Qual e o numero? ") ==  numeroPensado ? "Acertou! " : "Erro! ") + numeroPensado + " era o numero");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Prompt.js).

Comment: Eu acabei esquecendo por causa da sintaxe é diferente.

Answer (score 3):

O erro está em `function numero(int num)` o int não é necessário.

```
<script>
function numero(num) {
  return Math.round(Math.random() * num);
};
var chute = prompt("Qual e o numero? ");
var numeroPensado = numero(10);
if(chute == numeroPensado) {
    document.write("Acertou! " + numeroPensado + " era o numero");
} else {
    document.write("Erro! " + numeroPensado +  " era o numero");
}
</script>
```