# O que é especificação ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)?

Tags: javascript, terminologia, ecmascript-6

Recentemente iniciei um projeto com Cordova + Ionic e, em determinado momento, entrei num impasse no qual encontrei a afirmativa que o *framework* segue os padrões web "mais recentes", como a nova especificação ES6 (ou ECMAScript 2015 ou, ainda, ES2015).

O que seria especificação ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)?

Comment: Vinculada: [CoffeeScript, TypeScript e JavaScript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/18246)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Especificação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/111284/101) é um conjunto de regras que vão regular as implementações da linguagem. Ela vai tendo evoluções, novas versões são criadas com novidades do que a linguagem deve ter e as implementações que desejem se conformar com a especificação mais atual devem implementar.

ES6 é ECMAScript 6. [ECMAcript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript) é o nome oficial do que conhecemos como JavaScript que na verdade é o nome criado pela Mozilla. Esta versão também é conhecida pelo ano de sua publicação, no caso 2015.

JavaScript é uma implementação da ECMAScript. Tem [mais informações sobre isso em outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101).

[ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/) é uma entidade internacional de regulação de origem europeia. Semelhante ao ISO que é mais mundial. Assim como temos a ABNT no Brasil. Em geral aprovar um regulamento ECMA é mais fácil que ISO, por isso é comum optar-se por ela, e pode ser um caminho para depois conseguir a ISO. E em alguns lugares da Europa exige essa regulamentação para adoção em muitas circunstâncias, em outros lugares não.

Existe um [site com todas as novidades da ES6](http://es6-features.org/#Constants). A [especificação oficial pode ser obtida no site oficial](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/).

Você pode acompanhar como anda a implementação dessa versão nos navegadores. Por exemplo [no Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_2015_support_in_Mozilla). Também pode ver uma [tabela comparativa](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/).

Já estamos trabalhando com a [versão 7 (2016)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/). Em breve teremos a ES.Next, que ainda não tem nome definitivo. Bom, isso ficou defasado, cada ano tem uma nova ES.Next.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: JavaScript então já foi chamado de ECMAScript? Na pare te na pergunta que falo sobre framework segue os padrões web "mais recentes", então seria como você quase disse, uma especie de norma?

Comment: Na verdade a linguagem chama EcmaScript, JavaScript é a implementação da Mozilla. Todo mundo fala errado. Ninguém quer fazer só para a implementação de um navegador, quer fazer para todos, e o que roda em todos é a EcmaScript. Eles usam os recursos que já estão disponíveis nessa versão da linguagem..

Comment: Obrigado! Legal, deu pra esclarecer um pouco! Vou fazer uma busca mais profunda para entender melhor. Abs.

Comment: @AckLay botei um *link* que tem + informação sobre ES. Não muito :)

Answer (score 10):

### É simplesmente a mais nova versão do JavaScript.

Na verdade, o nome mais usado atualmente é ES2016. A ideia do comitê responsável (conhecido como TC39) pelas atualizações da linguagem é justamente fazer um release anual. Então nesse ano teremos o ES2017 (ou ES8). E assim sucessivamente.

### Objetivos do ES6

O TC39 focou em alguns objetivos no desenvolvimento do ES6:

- Ser uma linguagem melhor para construir aplicações complexas;
- Resolver problemas antigos do JavaScript;
- Facilidade no desenvolvimento de libraries.

Esses objetivos ficarão mais claros quando olharmos na prática as features do ES6.

### Principais Features

- let;
- const;
- arrow functions;
- destructuring;

Além de algumas relacionadas a Orientação a Objetos. Como a syntax sugar para os famosos get/setters e entre outros.

[Fonte](https://medium.com/@matheusml/o-guia-do-es6-tudo-que-voc%C3%AA-precisa-saber-8c287876325f#.pwrjjagm1)

Comment: Na verdade ES6 não é o ES2016, você pode ver na [documentação oficial](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html) que o ECMAScript 2016 é a 7ª edição.