# Verificar Disponibilidade do CEP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou tentando desenvolver mas não me é muito familiar a programação com *Ajax*, *jQuery* e *JavaScript*, então gostaria de ajuda tenho um campo que pega o *CEP* do cliente e um botão para que quando ele clicar no botão retornar se aquele *CEP* esta abrangido ali para entrega, se não estiver exibir que não entregamos na quela região mas isso tudo sem sair da pagina que eu estou tudo na mesma pagina.

Comment: Recentemente eu estava justamente escrevendo um em *JavaScript* para pesquisa de *CEPs*, usando algumas *APIs* disponivéis, o que você já tentou ? Teria como [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/253379/edit) sua pergunta e colocar o código ?

Comment: tipo pelo que eu entendi que o cara que e um script que o usuário vai digitar um cep e se o cep não for igual a algum do array ele vai retornar que não esta disponível para entrega.

Comment: isso ai que meu xará disse, ja tentei ver api's mas o esquema de entrega não é pelos correios então não tem como usar a api o sistema de entrega e propio

Comment: Sim, isso ai eu entendi, veja como você quer verificar a região abrangida ? Por *Estado*, *Cidades* ?

Comment: abrangendo cidades de ceps específicos.

Comment: @TúlioGomes dupla personalidade ?? **:D**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui alguns exemplos de como fazer a verificação de *CEP* por *Cidades*, para utilizar basta criar um objeto com os cinco primeiros dígitos do intervalo de *CEPs*, exemplo:

A cidade de *Campinas* que fica no estado de *São Paulo* os *CEPs* começam com *13000* e vai até *13139*.

### jQuery e PHP

> Arquivo *consultaCEP.php*

```
$getCEP = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'cep');
// A variável $Abranage pode ser o retorno de consulta
$Abrange = [
    // CAMPINAS
    [
        'inicio' => 13000,
        'fim' => 13139,
        'cidade' => 'Campinas'
    ],
    // PAULINIA
    [
        'inicio' => 13140,
        'fim' => 13140,
        'cidade' => 'Paulinia'
    ],
    // COSMOPOLIS
    [
        'inicio' => 13150,
        'fim' => 13150,
        'cidade' => 'Cosmopolis'
    ]
];
// Pega os cinco primeiros digitos do CEP informado pelo usuário
$CincoPrimeirosDigitos = substr($getCEP, 0,5);
$Check = false;
foreach($Abrange as $cidade) {
  // Verifica se é igual ou se esta entre INICIO e FIM
  if ($CincoPrimeirosDigitos >= $cidade['inicio'] && $CincoPrimeirosDigitos <= $cidade['fim']) {
    $Check = true;
  }
}
if ($Check) {
  echo json_encode(true);
} else {
  echo json_encode(false);
}
```

> *HTML*

```
<div class="alert success">Entregamos em sua região</div>
<div class="alert info">Lamentamos, não entregamos em sua região!</div>
<input type="text" name="cep" id="cep" placeholder="Informe um CEP" />
<input type="button" id="VerificarCEP" value="Verificar" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#VerificarCEP").on('click', function(e) {
  var campo = $('#cep');
  var check = false;
  // Verifica a quantidade de digitos
  if (campo.val().length < 8) return;
  var url = 'consultaCEP.php?cep=${cep}'.replace('${cep}', campo.val());

  $.getJSON(url, function (retorno) {
      console.log(retorno);
    if (retorno) {
        $(".success").show();
        $(".info").hide();
    } else {
        $(".success").hide();
        $(".info").show();
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

> Nos dois exemplos abaixo estou utilizando a *API* do site [ViaCEP](https://viacep.com.br/) para realizar a consulta.

### jQuery

```js
// Por Cidade
// Coloque somente os 5 primeiros digitos, exe:
// Campinas os CEPs tem a númeração començando por
// 13000 e vai até 13139
const abrange = [
  // CAMPINAS
  {
    inicio: 13000,
    fim: 13139,
    cidade: 'Campinas'
  },
  // PAULINIA
  {
    inicio: 13140,
    fim: 13140,
    cidade: 'Paulinia'
  },
  // COSMOPOLIS
  {
    inicio: 13150,
    fim: 13150,
    cidade: 'Cosmopolis'
  }
];

$("#VerificarCEP").on('click', function(e) {
  var campo = $('#cep');
  var check = false;
  // Verifica a quantidade de digitos
  if (campo.val().length < 8) return;
  var url = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/'.replace('${cep}', campo.val());
  
  $.getJSON(url, function (retorno) {
    if (retorno.erro) {
      $(".success, .info").hide();
      $(".erro").show();
    } else {
      var ini = retorno.cep.substring(0, 5);
      var t = $.grep(abrange, function(cep, i){
        if(ini >= cep.inicio && ini <= cep.fim) {
          check = true;
        }
      });
      
      if (check) {
        $(".erro, .info").hide();
        $(".success").show();
      } else {
        $(".erro, .success").hide();
        $(".info").show();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: none;
}
.erro {
  background-color: #f44336;
}
.success {
  background-color: green;
}
.info {
  background-color: #069;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert success">Entregamos em sua região</div>
<div class="alert erro">CEP Inválido</div>
<div class="alert info">Lamentamos, não entregamos em sua região!</div>
<input type="text" name="cep" id="cep" placeholder="Informe um CEP" />
<input type="button" id="VerificarCEP" value="Verificar" />
```

### ES6

```js
// Por Cidade
// Coloque somente os 5 primeiros digitos, exe:
// Campinas os CEPs tem a númeração començando por
// 13000 e vai até 13139
const abrange = [
  // CAMPINAS
  {
    inicio: 13000,
    fim: 13139,
    cidade: 'Campinas'
  },
    // PAULINIA
  {
    inicio: 13140,
    fim: 13140,
    cidade: 'Paulinia'
  },
  // COSMOPOLIS
  {
    inicio: 13150,
    fim: 13150,
    cidade: 'Cosmopolis'
  }
  // Basta adicionar mais cidades, ou retornar através de dados cadastrados no banco de dados.
];
const buscarCEP = (cep) => {
  let check = false;
  if (cep.length < 8) return;
  let url = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/${cep}/json/'.replace('${cep}', cep);
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => {
    if (res.ok) {
      res.json().then((json) => {
        if (json.erro) {
            document.querySelector('.success').style.display = 'none'; 
            document.querySelector('.info').style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector('.erro').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          abrange.forEach((e) => {
            // Pega os 5 primeiros digitos
            let ini = json.cep.substring(0, 5);
            // Verifica o intervalo
            if (ini >= e.inicio && ini <= e.fim) {
              console.log('Abrange');
              check = true;
            }
          });
      
          if (check) {
            document.querySelector('.success').style.display = 'block';
            document.querySelector('.info').style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector('.erro').style.display = 'none';
          } else {
            document.querySelector('.success').style.display = 'none';
            document.querySelector('.info').style.display = 'block';
            document.querySelector('.erro').style.display = 'none';
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

let btnVerificarCEP = document.querySelector('#VerificarCEP');
// Adiciona o evento click
btnVerificarCEP.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let campoCEP = document.querySelector('#cep');
  buscarCEP(campoCEP.value);
});
```

```css
.alert {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: none;
}
.erro {
  background-color: #f44336;
}
.success {
  background-color: green;
}
.info {
  background-color: #069;
}
```

```html
<div class="alert success">Entregamos em sua região</div>
<div class="alert erro">CEP Inválido</div>
<div class="alert info">Lamentamos, não entregamos em sua região!</div>
<input type="text" name="cep" id="cep" placeholder="Informe um CEP" />
<input type="button" id="VerificarCEP" value="Verificar" />
```

Comment: A pessoa que negativou, por favor de uma explicação do que está errado ? Para que posso ser corrigido!

Comment: qual a diferença entre um código e outro pode explicar?

Comment: Ambos fazem o mesmo, a diferença é que o *jQuery* é um biblioteca de funções e para utilizar essas funções você precisa importar o *jQuery*, para saber sobre *EcmaScript* leia essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/181079/60376) aqui no *SOpt*.

Comment: estou com basicamente o mesmo problema testei sua função aqui ela esta certa só que os campos divis Entregamos em sua região e as demais não ficam escondidas

Comment: @TulioVieira você está fazendo o primeiro que é só o *PHP* com *jQuery* ?

Comment: já entendi o porque kkk nao coloquei o style

Comment: @TulioVieira isso acontece rsrs, caso a resposta tenha ajudado a solucionar seu problema / dúvida, considere marcar como aceita / util.

Comment: sou dono do post nao kkk

Answer (score 2):

Você possui armazenados os CEPs disponíveis para entrega, certo?

Basta fazer uma chamada ajax no seguinte modelo:

```
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET', //ou POST
                url: 'nome_da_pagina.php',
                data: {cep: $('#cep').val()},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    //retorno uma variável booleana chamada success no json
                    if (data.success){
                        //sucesso: o cep verificado está disponível para entrega
                    }else{
                        //o cep verificado não está disponível
                    }
                },
                error: function(xhr){
                    //tratar o erro na chamada ajax
                }
            });
```

No exemplo a tag *input* possui a id cep, assim como o script PHP receberá a variável como cep também. Pode receber o valor com a seguinte linha:

```
$cep = isset($_GET['cep']) ? $_GET['cep'] : '';
```

Dentro do PHP você fará uma consulta ao banco que verificará se o valor da variável existe na tabela.

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: eu queria o o Ajax ja fizesse essa verificação e não o php

Comment: esta lista de CEPs possíveis para entrega está onde? base de dados? txt? a linguagem que voce usa, qual é? existem milhares de resoluções bem simples no próprio stack.

Comment: tinha pensado em um array. não achei nada do tipo que estou querendo aqui @MichelSimões

Answer (score 1):

Não vou me ater explicando, mas basicamente, tem um array com as frutas, "Banana", "Laranja", "Maçã", "Manga" se vc digitar uma delas no campo ele te da a resposta que há, se não, não há, coloquei inclusive os ifs para que manipule sua resposta. abraço e boa sorte!

```js
function myFunction() {
    variavel = document.getElementById("campo").value;
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Laranja", "Maçã", "Manga"];
    var a = fruits.indexOf(variavel);
if(a >= 0){
   retorno = "Há a variável";
} else {
   retorno = "nao há a variavel";
}
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = retorno;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="campo" name="campo" >
<button onclick=" myFunction()">verificar</button>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Já imaginou a quantidade de *CEPs* disponíveis ? Isso não seria uma ótima ideia, já que ele teria que informar *CEP* por *CEP* para poder fazer a verificação.

Comment: por isso que eu perguntei antes pro usuário como ELE pensa em fazer isso, antes de sugerir algo absurdo...