# Para que serve as chaves nas variáveis?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-service, design-pattern

Em um dos códigos que pesquisei encontrei uma variável declarada o nome entre chaves conforme o exemplo abaixo:

`const { home } = app.controllers;`

Sei como funciona esta função mas gostaria de entender para que serve as chaves, pois quando tiro elas o código apresenta erro.

Qual a diferença entre
`const { home } = app.controllers;`e `const home  = app.controllers;`?

Comment: [O que é especificação ES6?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/181071)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A designação para a expressão dada como exemplo é ["Atribuição via desestruturação (destructuring assignment)"](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao).

> [**Atribuição via desestruturação (destructuring assignment)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao).
>
> A sintaxe de **atribuição via desestruturação (destructuring assignment)** é uma expressão JavaScript que possibilita extrair dados de arrays ou objetos em variáveis distintas.
>
> ```
> var a, b, rest;
> [a, b] = [1, 2];
> console.log(a); // 1
> console.log(b); // 2
>
> [a, b, ...rest] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
> console.log(a); // 1
> console.log(b); // 2
> console.log(rest); // [3, 4, 5]
>
> ({a, b} = {a:1, b:2});
> console.log(a); // 1
> console.log(b); // 2
> ```

No seu exemplo você está atribuindo a propriedade `home` da variável `app.controllers` diretamente a uma constante de mesmo nome. Outros modos de realizar a mesma atribuição seriam:

```
const home = app.controllers.home;

// Ou

const { controller: { home } } = app;
```