# Como funciona a atribuição via desestruturação?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Não entendi como funciona a atribuição via desestruturação. É algo especifico do JSON?

Um exemplo do corpo de uma requisição ao Node.js:

```
{
  "title": "Caso 1",
  "description": "Detalhes do caso",
  "value": 1100
}
```

```
async create(request, response) {
  const { title, description, value } = request.body;
}
```

Para cada valor uma variável é criada.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Para que serve as chaves nas variaveis do node.js](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/340773/para-que-serve-as-chaves-nas-variaveis-do-node-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A atribuição via desestruturação é um recurso introduzido no ECMAScript 2015 (ES6). Ele é basicamente um *syntactic sugar* para obter valores de objetos ou *arrays*.

No seu exemplo, você está desestruturando as propriedades `title`, `description` e `value` do objeto `request.body`:

```js
const body = {
  title: 'Sou o "Title"',
  description: 'Sou a "Description"',
  value: 'Sou o "Value"',
  foo: 'Foo'
};

const { title, description, value } = body;

console.log(title, description, value);
```

Perceba que o objeto pode ter mais propriedades. Só iremos obter, contudo, aquelas que desestruturamos.

A título de comparação, para fazer a mesma coisa em versões anteriores ao ES6, você teria que fazer:

```js
const body = {
  title: 'Sou o "Title"',
  description: 'Sou a "Description"',
  value: 'Sou o "Value"',
  foo: 'Foo'
};

const title = body.title;
const description = body.description;
const value = body.value;

console.log(title, description, value);
```

Note que há uma significativa economia de linhas, que cresce à medida que desestruturamos mais propriedades. A sintaxe vai muito além disso, consulte a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao) para saber mais sobre os diversos casos-de-uso.

Há também desestruturação de *arrays*. Veja um simples exemplo:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const [one, two] = arr;

console.log(one, two);
```

---

Por fim, é importante dizer que isso não é algo "específico do JSON". JSON é um formato de transferência de dados compatível com objetos do JavaScript. Assim, você consegue desestruturar qualquer objeto ou *array* utilizando essas sintaxes. Veja o exemplo abaixo, que ilustra a desestruturação da propriedade `name` de uma função:

```js
function doStuff() {}

const { name } = doStuff;

console.log(`O nome é: "${name}".`);
```

Enfim, é uma adição bem útil e que facilita basante.

---

[Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/430322/o-que-s%c3%a3o-nomes-computados-em-javascript/430325#430325) explica como funcionam os nomes computados, um recurso mais complexo da atribuição via desestruturação.