# Utilizar método reduce() para reordenar array de objetos!

Tags: javascript

Pessoal tenho o seguindo array de objetos:

```
  old: [
    {
      id: 1,
      date: '2020-08-27T00:00:00',
      title: 'Title 1',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      date: '2020-08-27T00:00:00',
      title: 'Title 2',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      date: '2020-08-25T00:00:00',
      title: 'Title 3',
    }
  ],
```

Preciso que ele fique reordenado onde o campo `date` for igual.. segue o exemplo:

```
  items: [
    {
      date: '2020-08-27T00:00:00',
      childrens: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'Title 1',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'Title 2',
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      date: '2020-08-27T00:00:00',
      childrens: [
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'Title 3',
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Pensei em utilizar o método `reduce()` para isso, mais acho que não estou fazendo certo.. mais ta quase la.. segue meu código:

```js
const old = [
  {
    id: 1,
    date: '2020-08-27T00:00:00',
    title: 'Title 1',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    date: '2020-08-27T00:00:00',
    title: 'Title 2',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    date: '2020-08-25T00:00:00',
    title: 'Title 3',
  }
];

const items = old.reduce((acc, item) => {
  if (!acc[item.date]) {
    acc[item.date] = { childrens: [item] };
    
    return acc;
  } 
  
  acc[item.date].childrens.push(item);

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(items)
```

Comment: Você já tem um objeto separado, agora só precisa usar algo como `Object.entries` com um `map` depois pra transformar do objeto em um array no formato que você precisa. :)

Comment: Talvez [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/459413/verificar-quantas-vezes-um-n%c3%bamero-aparece-no-array/459416#459416) possa te dar uma ideia geral de como fazer isso. Tem boas alternativas lá.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Talvez seja mais fácil - pelo menos eu acho - fazer sem `reduce`. Basta fazer um *loop* simples pelo array `old` e ir montando o novo objeto:

```js
const old = [
    { id: 1, date: '2020-08-27T00:00:00', title: 'Title 1' },
    { id: 2, date: '2020-08-27T00:00:00', title: 'Title 2' },
    { id: 3, date: '2020-08-25T00:00:00', title: 'Title 3' }
];

let items = {};
for (let i = 0; i < old.length; i++) {
    const e = old[i];
    const novoItem = { id: e.id, title: e.title};
    if (! items[e.date]) { // ainda não tem nada nesta data, criar um novo
        items[e.date] = { date: e.date, children: [ novoItem ]};
    } else { // já existe registro para a data, adiciona no array children já existente
        items[e.date].children.push(novoItem);
    }
}
console.log(items);

// ou, se quiser que items seja um array:
items = Object.values(items);
console.log(items);
```

Ou seja, para cada elemento em `old` eu verifico se já existe um elemento correspondente à sua data em `items`. Se não tiver, eu crio um novo, se já tiver eu adiciono no array `children`.

Só não ficou claro a saída, por isso eu dei 2 opções. A primeira é um objeto cujas chaves são as datas e os valores são os objetos contendo a data e o array de `children`:

```
{
  "2020-08-27T00:00:00": {
    "date": "2020-08-27T00:00:00",
    "children": [
      { "id": 1, "title": "Title 1" },
      { "id": 2, "title": "Title 2" }
    ]
  },
  "2020-08-25T00:00:00": {
    "date": "2020-08-25T00:00:00",
    "children": [
      { "id": 3, "title": "Title 3" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Mas nesse caso a data ficaria redundante. Se a ideia é ter um array (como parece ser no exemplo da pergunta), basta pegar somente os valores (`Object.values(items)`), e nesse caso ficaria:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2020-08-27T00:00:00",
    "children": [
      { "id": 1, "title": "Title 1" },
      { "id": 2, "title": "Title 2" }
    ]
  },
  {
    "date": "2020-08-25T00:00:00",
    "children": [
      { "id": 3, "title": "Title 3" }
    ]
  }
]
```

Se quiser, também pode trocar o `for` acima por um [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of):

```
for (const e of old) {
    const novoItem = { id: e.id, title: e.title};
    if (! items[e.date]) { // ainda não tem nada nesta data, criar um novo
        items[e.date] = { date: e.date, children: [ novoItem ]};
    } else { // já existe registro para a data, adiciona no array children já existente
        items[e.date].children.push(novoItem);
    }
}
```

Ou ainda, usando [atribuição via desestruturação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/441913/112052) juntamente com a [sintaxe de espalhamento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-PT/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```
let items = {};
for (const e of old) {
    const { date, ...novoItem } = { ...e };
    if (! items[date]) {
        items[date] = { date, children: [ novoItem ]};
    } else {
        items[date].children.push(novoItem);
    }
}
```

---

Será que precisa mesmo de `reduce`? Ficaria quase igual, mas talvez adicionando uma complexidade desnecessária:

```js
const old = [
    { id: 1, date: '2020-08-27T00:00:00', title: 'Title 1' },
    { id: 2, date: '2020-08-27T00:00:00', title: 'Title 2' },
    { id: 3, date: '2020-08-25T00:00:00', title: 'Title 3' }
];

let items = old.reduce(function(acc, item) {
  const newItem = { id: item.id, title: item.title };
  if (!acc[item.date]) {
    acc[item.date] = { date: item.date, children: [ newItem ] };
  } else {
    acc[item.date].children.push(newItem);
  }

  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(items);

// ou, se quiser que items seja um array:
items = Object.values(items);
console.log(items);
```

Eu acho que não precisa de `reduce`. Apesar do algoritmo ficar bem parecido, ele adiciona uma complexidade que, apesar de não ser *tão* grande assim, na minha opinião é desnecessária (criar uma função de *callback* que é chamada várias vezes). Se um `for` simples já resolve, para que complicar?

---

<modo-pedante>Também mudei o nome da propriedade de `childrens` para `children`, afinal, ["children" já está no plural](https://www.quora.com/What-is-plural-children-or-childens).</modo-pedante>

Comment: Vlw mano! mandou muito bem na resposta, varias formas de solucionar! Sucesso!