# Php Formato Numerico de 000 000 000 0

Tags: php

Boas,

Estou criando um input onde o mesmo faz o envio de um codigo.
Este codigo deverá ser inserido assim.

```
 INPUT-TEXT Formato -> 000 000 000 0
```

qual a melhor maneira de o fazer neste formato?

Exemplo, vou escrever no input 213213123, e fica como 000 000 000 0.

Answer (score 3):

Por sua tag estar PHP, você poderia fazer:

```
$text = "1234567890";

echo implode(" ", str_split($text, 3));
```

Considerando que o `$text` a fonte de entrada da informação, como um `$_POST`... O `str_split()` irá retornar uma array onde cada valor terá 3 bytes *(unicode não é suportado)*, enquanto o `implode()` irá adicionar espaços em cada valor da array.

Comment: Sensacional, simples e com funções nativas! +1

Comment: certo fanatstico, mas gostaria de fazer também no Input... Ao adicionar os numeros ele metia exatamente dessa forma... isso é javascript ne..

Comment: @Snoopy12, sim. Neste caso terá que usar javascript.

Comment: que codigo uso? :D

Comment: @Snoopy12 Recomendo: [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/261364/99718](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/261364/99718) ou [https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin)

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar a função `chunk_split`, que é usada para dividir a string por um caractere em sequencia de interva-los, um exemplo de uso é dividir um BASE64 em um formato compatível com *RFC 2045*, para o seu caso são espaços, então pode fazer assim:

```
<?php

$str = '1234567890';
$str2 = trim( chunk_split($str, 3, ' ') );

var_dump( $str2 );
```

> O `trim` é para remover os possíveis espaços extras no final.

outras sugestões que pode adaptar para ti estão em:

- [Inserção de ponto a cada 5 caracteres](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44639/3635)

Para suporte para unicode esta solução parece atender:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44686/3635