# Angular com TypeScript ou JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Pesquisando um pouco sobre o Angular (v 2+) vi que em muitos lugares é comentado que o Angular tem suporte para TypeScript e que é mais comum o seu uso do que o JavaScript puro, então quais as vantagens e desvantagens de usar TypeScript ou JavaScript no Angular?

Comment: Pra mim isso vai de cada um, eu curti demais o `TypeScript`, pra mim nada mais é do que um `Javascript` melhorado!

Comment: Possível duplicata de [CoffeeScript, TypeScript e JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15998/coffeescript-typescript-e-javascript)

Comment: @NoobSaibot já tinha visto essa pergunta porém achei ela abrangente demais, gostaria de algo mais específico

Comment: No final das contas, tudo se torna JavaScript rsrs

Comment: Na verdade não vejo muita vantagem em usar uma linguagem que, como você mesmo disse, no final das contas é javascript, porém se para conseguir fazer algo legal com Angular + JS eu tenha que ficar uma semana quebrando a cabeça e com TS eu faça em alguns minutos, acaba sendo uma necessidade

Comment: Essa sua pegunta é até bem fácil de ser respondida. Tente fazer uma funcionalidade em uma aplicação utilizando Angular, React, Vue, etc... aplicando o paradigma de orientação a objetos com Typescript e depois a mesma funcionalidade utilizando Vanila.

Comment: O typescript e so features adicionais sobre o typescript por exemplo vc pode usar any em qualquer lugar e seria praticamente a mesma coisa que o js.

Comment: @EduardoVargas e se usar, melhor nem fazer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Especificamente pelo Angular a vantagem é usar a mesma linguagem que ele é escrito.

A maior vantagem é mais geral, é a linguagem ser estaticamente tipada (pelo menos na superfície), que deixa o código mais escalável de trabalhar que um de tipagem dinâmica. Tipagem dinâmica é para *scripts*, funciona bem quando JS era usado para *scripts*, quando começaram fazer aplicações nele ficou complicado. TypeScript dá mais robustez.

E claro que a linguagem tem mais *features*, tem evoluído muito rápido porque não é uma linguagem de comitê. Não sei qual o futuro do Angular com o advento do [WebAssembly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/199158/101), pode ser que muitas pessoas optem até por uma solução que não use nem JS, nem TS, nem Angular.

Para ver diferenças gerais pode consultar: [CoffeeScript, TypeScript e JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101).

A desvantagem é que é mais uma camada, você programa em uma linguagem que será convertida para outra. Com as ferramentas existentes conseguiram fazer algo surpreendentemente bom.

Passado algum tempo depois da resposta dá para dizer que todo mundo está indo para TypeScript (ou sair do ecossistema inteiro). Alguns vão demorar mais e não vão largar o osso, mas está claro que o tipo de aplicação que Angular é usado o TS é bem melhor, mesmo que ainda dê para usar o JS. O mesmo já vale pra Vue e React, como como esses demoraram mais pra suportar TS, a adoção é mais lenta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não sabia que o Angular foi escrito em TypeScript. Pela sua experiência, usar o TypeScrit no Angular pode acabar se tornando uma necessidade, pela facilidade, por ser mais usado, por ter maior conteúdo, ou até mesmo porque em algum versão futura o Angular só possa ser usado com TS?

Comment: O Angular atual sim, o primeiro não. Não sei se seria necessidade, mas é mais natural. JS e TS são muito compatíveis, pelo menos em uma direção, não acho que mude muito, e como eu falei é mais fácil o Angular se tornar irrelevante. É possível que o TS acabe dominando, mas essas coisas não dá pra prever.

Comment: O que quer dizer com _"TypeScript dá mais robustez."_? Se no final tudo é JavaScript, fazer algo em JS ou TS, no final, não daria na mesma robustez, performance, etc?

Comment: De maneira alguma, robustez tem a ver com a forma como você escreve, não é que no final é tudo a mesma coisa, no máximo no final se transforma na mesma linguagem, mas não no mesmo código. É possível em teoria ter o mesmo resultado, mas na prática não acontece.