# Como criar Interface em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Acredito que boa parte de vocês conhecem o conceito de **Interface**, bastante difundido em POO, mas em JavaScript em todos os projetos que trabalhei até hoje não vi usarem esse conceito.

Pesquisei um pouco sobre, porém a maioria dos *posts* são antigos, então eu gostaria de saber se nessas novas atualizações do JS surgiu alguma forma similar as usadas em outras linguagens para declarar interface? Senão, qual o modo adequado de se criar uma interface hoje?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Não é exatamente possível, mesmo nas versões mais novas da linguagem. É possível em TypeScript, e [muita gente está indo pra ela](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/308357/101), justamente por ser mais robusta e completa.

O que pode fazer em JS é só adotar certos padrões. Pode criar uma classe com métodos sem implementação. Está longe de ser ideal, não vai fazer o que é mais importante na interface que é fazer cumprir um contrato, mas é algo parecido. Tem umas [tentativas para se fazer algo próximo](https://hackernoon.com/implementing-interfaces-in-javascript-with-implement-js-8746838f8caa), mas é feio. Tem outras formas de fazer isto, mas sinceramente se precisar mesmo é hora de ir pro TS.

Fora isso apenas posso dizer que não faz parte da filosofia da linguagem ter este tipo de verificação. JavaScript é uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica, flexível, nunca se comprometeu com contratos.

É curioso, porque ele é um mecanismo de contratos e não orientação a objetos, o que mostra que as pessoas não entendem OOP. Note que "todo mundo" acha isso porque ele sempre vem vinculado com essa tipo de técnica. Por isso sempre falo para as pessoas estudarem em vez de decorar receitas de bolo. OO não prega contratos. Muitos programadores experientes, mas que não estudaram o assunto, acham que prega. Não confie nas pessoas só pela sua experiência.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas informações, estava com essa percepção, não sabia se era falta de conhecimento de minha parte ou se realmente hoje ainda não tinha tal recurso na linguagem. E realmente as maneiras que vi ficam bem feias mesmo kk.

Comment: Interessante este link enviado @Maniero, mas o Flow JS não faz algo parecido?

Comment: @VagnerWentz não o conheço então não posso dizer, parece, mas se é para usar isso melhor usar TS.

Comment: Interessante! Uso TyepScript na veia e achei massa a abordagem deste link enviado e quis discutir sobre a utilização do Flow JS, caso queira, da uma pesquisa, acho que irá gostar.