# É possível "forçar" tipagem em JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, tipagem

Em PHP estou a costumado a criar uma função e consigo declarar os tipos de parâmetros que quero, mesmo sabendo que a linguagem é fracamente tipada, mas em JS eu consigo fazer isso?

Exemplo em PHP:

```
<?php

class Teste {

    private $names;

    /**
     * setNames
     *
     * @param array $name
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function setNames(array $names) {

        $this->names = $names;

    }

    /**
     * getNames
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getNames() : array {

        return $this->names;

    }
}

$nome = new Teste();

$nome->setNames('Lucas');
var_dump($nome->getNames());
```

Dará o erro:

> Argument 1 passed to Teste::setNames() must be of the type array, string given

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Declarar tipos nada tem a ver com a linguagem ser fortemente tipada. Na verdade, nem ser estaticamente tipada, que eu acho que era o que queria dizer. Pode ler mais sobre isto em [Qual a diferença entre uma linguagem de programação estática e dinâmica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101). As pessoas usam os termos equivocadamente por não entenderem os conceitos corretos.

De fato, PHP e JavaScript são fracamente tipadas e dinamicamente tipadas. PHP começou permitir colocar tipos e impor alguma limitação, embora ela continua dinamicamente tipada. Ajuda, mas não a torna estaticamente tipada.

Se precisa desse tipo de ajuda, e ela é realmente muito boa, provavelmente deveria usar outra linguagem que é não só estaticamente tipada, mas também fortemente tipada, que aí sim ajuda 100%. Não faz sentido usar a ferramenta errada para a tarefa. Uma linguagem que começou de uma forma nunca será boa na outra. Inclusive essa forma de programar é melhor fazer em Java ou C#. PHP deveria ser mais simples, a vantagem dela é ser simples. Quando começa se programar de forma *enterprise* nela, a ferramenta se torna errada.

[image: Carro com um cavalo dentro no banco de trás com a cabeça para fora]

JavaScript não tem nada disso e dizem que nunca terá, por isso criaram [TypeScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/101) que resolve de forma bem melhor, embora não 100% por manter compatibilidade com JS. Infelizmente, embora TS seja estaticamente tipada na maior parte do tempo, nem sempre é, continua fracamente tipada e por converter para JS muito da vantagem se perde, mas ainda considero melhor para grandes bases de código.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Excelente explanação!!!!