# O que significa o [] depois de uma variável?

Tags: javascript, sintaxe

Gostaria de saber o que é isso, quando uma variável recebe esse `[]`:

```
let teste;
    
teste[id]
```

Comment: Um indexador...

Comment: Pesquise por indexação no google

Comment: aonde se viu isso? não está faltando código ai?

Comment: Sobre o `let`, está respondido [aqui](/q/47165/112052). Sobre o `[]`, leia a [documentação sobre arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem um contexto maior com relação ao código, o máximo que dá para dizer é:

O `let` é uma das formas de se declarar uma variável, e influencia no escopo da mesma - tudo isso já foi explicado em detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/112052). Então `let teste;` só está declarando uma variável chamada `teste` (e o escopo dela seguirá as regras explicadas no *link* já citado, então vai depender muito de onde ela foi declarada - e sem mais contexto, é tudo que dá para dizer).

[Outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/464225/112052) disse que "*isso é a declaração da variável teste do tipo any*", mas na verdade [o tipo `any` só existe em TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any). Em JavaScript qualquer variável pode ser de qualquer tipo, e você não declara o tipo no código (diferente de outras linguagens nas quais você é obrigado a informar o tipo - leia mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/355530/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15998/112052)). E [como já indicado anteriormente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47165/112052), `let` só serve para definir o escopo, não o tipo.

---

Já sobre `teste[id]`, esta é uma sintaxe para acessar um elemento ou propriedade de `teste`, dependendo do caso. A [mesma resposta já citada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/464225/112052) disse que "*isso torna a varável teste em um array*", o que não é verdade. A variável só "se torna" um array se atribuirmos um valor à mesma, desde que, é claro, esse valor seja um array. Por exemplo:

```
let teste = [1, 2, 3]; // array com os números 1, 2 e 3
```

Ou

```
let teste = Array(10); // array com 10 posições
```

Enfim, leia a [documentação sobre arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) para entender melhor o que é e as várias formas de se criar um.

A partir daí, podemos acessar os elementos deste array, usando os colchetes. Ex:

```js
let teste = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(teste[0]); // 'a'
console.log(teste[1]); // 'b'
console.log(teste[2]); // 'c'
```

O primeiro elemento está no índice 0, o segundo no índice 1 e assim por diante. Mas também podemos usar uma variável como índice, em vez de um valor fixo:

```js
let teste = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let id = 2;
console.log(teste[id]); // 'c'
```

Ou seja, `teste[id]` está acessando o elemento cuja posição é o valor indicado pela variável `id`. Isso não "torna" a variável `teste` em um array (pois ela já era um array antes).

---

Mas isso não se restringe a arrays. [Qualquer propriedade de qualquer objeto pode ser acessada assim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

```js
let teste = { 'nome': 'Fulano', 'idade': 20 };
// acessando a propriedade "nome"
let id = 'nome';
console.log(teste[id]); // 'Fulano'

// mas também poderia ser assim:
console.log(teste['nome']); // 'Fulano'
console.log(teste.nome); // 'Fulano'
```

Vale lembrar ainda que arrays também podem ter propriedades:

```js
let teste = [1, 2, 3];
// criando a propriedade "nome"
teste['nome'] = 'sou um array';

// acessando a propriedade "nome"
let id = 'nome';
console.log(teste[id]); // 'sou um array'

// mas também poderia ser assim:
console.log(teste['nome']); // 'sou um array'
console.log(teste.nome); // 'sou um array'
```

Enfim, sobre `teste[id]`, é "só" isso, mas você pode se aprofundar no assundo lendo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/463578/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40682/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122341/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/362777/112052).

Answer (score 0):

Quando se fala em array, o indexador é a posição do elemento dentro do array, já se este modelo for utilizado em objetos, estaremos nos referenciando a uma key do objeto.

Exemplo:

```
let arr = ['posicao1', 'posicao2', 'posicao3'];

let obj = {
  nome: 'Teste',
  idade: 25
}

console.log(arr[2]); // retorno será 'posicao3', pois é o elemento 2 do array, lembrando que array começa em 0,1,2...

console.log(obj['nome']); // Em objeto, o indexador é a key do objeto, neste caso o retorno será o valor da propriedade nome, ou seja 'Teste';
```

Answer (score -3):

`let teste;` <- isso é a declaração da variável teste do tipo any, ou seja uma variável que pode ser quaquer coisa.

`teste[id]` <- isso torna a varável teste em um array e id é outra variável que está sendo usada como indexador de uma posição no array.

Comment: como assim indexador?

Comment: "torna a variável teste em um array"?

Comment: "*isso torna a varável teste em um array*" - não, o que torna ela um array seria algo como `teste = [ 1, 2 ]`. Já `teste[id]` só serve para acessar um elemento específico, mas a variável já era um array antes disso (ela já "se tornou" um array **antes** dessa declaração, e não **por causa** dela). E o tipo `any` só existe em TypeScript. Em JavaScript qualquer variável pode ser de qualquer tipo, e de qq forma [o `let` só influencia no escopo da variável](/q/47165/112052), e não no tipo. Vale lembrar tb que `teste` poderia ser um objeto (não só um array) e `id` conteria o nome da propriedade