# O que é e pra que serve YAML?

Tags: yaml

- Resumidamente, o que é YAML?
- Quais são as vantagens de utilizá-lo?
- Quais são as vantagem desvantagens em seu uso em relação ao XML e/ou JSON?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Definição

**YAML** (acrónimo recursivo para YAML Ain't Markup Language) é um formato de codificação de dados legíveis por humanos.

## Vantagens

O *YAML* foi feito essencialmente, para guardar dados (assim como os bancos de dados).

Em relação ao XML e JSON a legibilidade é muito mais fácil e você escreve mais facilmente. Além disso, ele é muito bem documentado e possui diversas bibliotecas.

**Não confirmei**, mas parece que JSON pode ser parcialmente interpretado por um *parser* de YAML.

**YAML**

```
blog:
       nome: Café = linhas
       url: http://exemplo.com

       post:
              titulo: hello world
              data: 12/04/2011
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "blog": {
    "nome": "Café = linhas",
    "url": "http://exemplo.com",
    "post": {
      "titulo": "hello world",
      "data": "12/04/2011"
    }
  }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<blog>
    <nome>Café = linhas</nome>
    <url>http://exemplo.com</url>
    <post>
        <titulo>hello world</titulo>
        <data>12/04/2011</data>
    </post>
</blog>
```

## Desvantagens

- O YAML precisa ser identado com espaços, se você usar TAB um erro ocorrerá, isso pode ser bem irritante as vezes.
- Devido a essa necessidade de espaços o YAML pode rapidamente ocupar mais espaço que o JSON e o XML.

  Apesar de que, nos dias atuais espaço não é mais um grande problema, mas se seu projeto precisa que os dados sejam pequenos, o YAML pode não ser para você.
- A **performance** do JSON é mais rápida para interpretar os dados. (Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451732/how-is-it-that-json-serialization-is-so-much-faster-than-yaml-serialization-in-p)
- **Depêndencias**, muitas linguagens suportam XML e JSON como padrão, mas não o YAML.

### Minha conclusão

Se o seu arquivo pode ser editado manualmente por um usuário (como era o caso do projeto Bukkit). YAML pode ser uma boa escolha, mas não vejo vantagem para quaisquer outro casos.

Ele pode ocupar mais espaço e é menos performático, além disso você provavelmente precisará usar bibliotecas de terceiros para fazer ele funcionar.

Se eu fosse para usar o YAML para guardar dados eu preferiria usar logo um *banco de dados* como MySQL ou SQLite. Se eu fosse enviar dados para uma API eu escolheria JSON ou XML, preferencialmente JSON por ocupar menos espaço, e consequentemente, dados de internet do usuário.

### Fontes e referência

- http://yaml.org/
- https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308536/yaml-compared-to-xml
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561286/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantes-of-yaml-vs-xml-for-object-graph-de-seria
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726802/what-is-the-difference-between-yaml-and-json-when-to-prefer-one-over-the-other

Comment: 1. `O YAML precisa ser identado com espaços, se você usar TAB um erro ocorrerá, isso pode ser bem irritante as vezes.` - isso não é desvantagem, é vantagem para consistência.

Comment: 2. `Devido a essa necessidade de espaços o YAML pode rapidamente ocupar mais espaço que o JSON e o XML.` - essa afirmação só não está completamente errada porque você usou o "pode"! JSON tem aspas para chave/valor, colchetes, chaves. Nem vou falar sobre o XML porque é extremamente verboso: o YAML é justamente para ser um XML enxugado para dados. Mesmo em código para máquinas, lembre-se que o YAML também pode ser minificado, se aproveitando do fato de conter o JSON como subconjunto parcial.

Answer (score 7):

### **Yaml**

Acrônimo recursivo para `YAML Ain’t Markup Language`.

É um formato de serialização de dados legível por humanos, que se inspirou em conceitos de linguagens como o `XML`, `C`, `Python`, `Perl` e também o formato do correio eletrônico especificado no `RFC 2822`. Foi proposto por Clark Evans em 2001 e desenhado em conjunto com Ingy döt Net e Oren BenKiki.

Embora não seja menos genérico que o `XML`, o `YAML` é em grande parte mais simples de ler, editar, modiﬁcar e produzir que o `XML`. Ou seja, quase tudo o que é possível de representar em `XML` pode ser representado em `YAML`, e ao mesmo tempo, de uma forma mais compacta. O `YAML` foi deﬁnido para suportar apenas caracteres no sistema UTF8 ou UTF16, sendo o comportamento dos parsers indefinido quando a stream `YAML` está em qualquer outra codifição.

**Vantagens**

- Legível por Humanos.
- Portátil entre linguagens de programação.
- Modelo consistente para suportar ferramentas genéricas.
- Expressivo e extensível.
- Fácil de implementar e usar.

**Quais são as vantagem desvantagens em seu uso em relação ao XML e/ou JSON?**

Vantagem é que é mais fácil para ler, desvantagem que é mais complexo para gerar e analisar.

Referência:

[Documentação YAML](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html)