# Como fazer um valueBox dinâmico no flexdashboard em R

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

Estou tentando construir um painel em que ao selecionar um Estado em uma lista suspensa o valor de uma `valueBox` altere dinamicamente de acordo com o valor da coluna no banco de dados, mas em todas as tentativas tenho retorno de erro.

Abaixo, o código utilizado:

```
library(dplyr)
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
 
UF = c('AC', 'AM', 'AP', 'BA', 'CE', 'ES', 'PB', 'PE')
Coluna = c(30, 200, 7, 12, 854, 2, 78, 965)
df <- data.frame(UF,Coluna)

Row {data-width=200 .sidebar}
--------------------------------------------------------------

{r}
selectInput(inputId = "estados",
            label="Selecione o Estado:",
            choices = unique(df$UF),
            selected = "",
            multiple=FALSE
            )
Row 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
{r}
renderValueBox({
b <- df %>%
  filter(UF %in% input$estados) %>%
  select(df$Coluna)

valueBox(value = b, icon = "fa-users")
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em primeiro lugar, se quer que seu documento `.Rmd` seja renderizado, precisa adicionar o argumento `runtime: shiny` abaixo de `title` no cabeçalho [`YAML`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80881/o-que-%c3%a9-e-pra-que-serve-yaml). Dessa forma:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---
```

Já agora, se pretende renderizar o resultado de sua análise, precisará usar a função `shiny::reactive` para que `flexdashboard::renderValueBox` funcione. No seu caso, você precisa que:

*ao selecionar um Estado em uma lista suspensa o valor de uma valueBox altere dinamicamente de acordo com o valor da coluna no banco de dados*

Se entendi bem, seu código ficaria assim:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(tibble)
```

```{r}
UF = c('AC', 'AM', 'AP', 'BA', 'CE', 'ES', 'PB', 'PE')
Coluna = c(30, 200, 7, 12, 854, 2, 78, 965)
df <- data.frame(UF,Coluna)

f_1 <- function(x) {
  df$Coluna[df$UF == x] # retorna o valor da Coluna correspondente a `UF`
}

reac <- reactive({
  tibble(
    input$UF
  )
})

pred <- reactive({
  temp <- reac()
  input$UF
})
```

side1{.sidebar}
---------------------------------

**Control panel**
```{r}
selectInput(inputId = "UF",
            label="Unidade federativa:",
            choices = unique(df$UF),
            selected = "",
            multiple=FALSE
            )
```

calc1{}
---------------------------------

###
```{r}
renderValueBox({
  expr = valueBox(
    value = f_1(x = pred()), 
    caption = "Coluna", 
    color = "#008bbb", 
    icon = "fa-users"
  )
})
```
````

Após, execute o documento com <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: muito obrigado!