# Como o JSON funciona em um projeto

Tags: json, node.js

Olá, venho fazendo muitas perguntas, que parecem basicas, mas me causa confusões, então melhor perguntar, rs.

Gostaria de saber como o arquivo .json funciona em um projeto, o que ele faz.

Obrigado!

Comment: Encontrei essa pergunta no Stackoverflow em Inglês que pode responder a sua pergunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383692/what-is-json-and-why-would-i-use-it. Seja bem-vindo ao Stackoverflow, confira o Tour (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) e cuidado quanto a perguntas muito amplas.

Comment: Por acaso você está falando do arquivo `package.json`? Ou qualquer JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON é uma estrutura similar ao XML, de notação, que pode ser reconhecida através de javascript, que basicamente pode conter, valores, arrays e objetos, você pode conferir mais informações aqui:
[O que é JSON? Para que serve e como funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4042/o-que-%C3%A9-json-para-que-serve-e-como-funciona)

Você pode ler através de várias formas, aqui tem um exemplo em jQuery:

```
   $.getJSON('arquivo.json', function(data) {
    //aqui exibe seu retorno no console do navegador
    console.log(data);
    }
```

Comment: -1. Justificativa: JSON não é uma linguagem, e não é estruturado em Javascript.

Comment: @OnoSendai, concordo com você, obrigado por me informar do problema, eu corrigi, espero que tenha ficado mais claro.

Comment: Substancial melhora, agradeço o esforço.

Comment: Obrigado a todos! me esclareceu muito!