# Definição : document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

Alguem me pode dar uma boa explicação sobre document.getElementById ... Estou a ler/aprender JSON e estou com algumas dúvidas relacionado com a função !

Comment: Atenção que JSON não tem nada a haver com Javascript no que diz respeito ao seu propósito, JSON é tal e qual XML, serve apenas para ser interpretado/manipulado por software, apenas um formato que permite a comunicação de informação entre sistemas/linguagens diferentes. JSON (Javascript Object Notation) só tem em comum a sintaxe de declaração de um objeto em JS

Comment: Ok Ja percebi que e uma Função de JV e não de JSON ... Ou seja qual e a função de document.getElementById ?

Comment: Sim... ja dei conta que o JSON server como Ponto de Comunicação com um Servidor atravez de JavaScript Manipulado... Something Like That

Answer (score 9):

### Sobre o `getElementById`

Basicamente o `document.getElementById`, como o nome já diz, é uma função do JavaScript que serve para retornar um elemento do DOM que é identificado por um ID específico.

Veja a definição da MDN:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Para ilustrar, se você tem

```
<div id="aaa">Hoje</div>
<div id="bbb">Amanha</div>
<div id="ccc">Ontem</div>
```

E em JS faz um

```
var teste = document.getElementById('bbb');
```

está recuperando na variável `teste` a segunda `div` do HTML acima.

Veja aqui um exemplo bem simples de como alterar o valor da `div` do exemplo:

> http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/LxGXjv

### Sobre o `JSON`

Aqui mesmo no site temos uma pergunta com o que você procura:

> [O que é JSON? Para que serve e como funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4042/70)

Comment: De certa forma, é mais adequado usar o `getElementById` do que o `querySelector` ou varia de caso para caso??

Comment: O getElementByID retorna UM item específico, o querySelector já é uma espécie de filtro que retorna o primeiro ítem que atender ao critério passado. Cada um tem sua função, normalmente não são intercambiáveis. O segundo tem que varrer o DOM para localizar o que está sendo buscado.

Answer (score 4):

Atenção que JSON não tem nada a haver com Javascript no que diz respeito ao seu propósito, JSON é tal e qual XML, serve para ser lido/manipulado por software, apenas um formato que permite a comunicação de informação entre sistemas/linguagens diferentes. JSON (Javascript Object Notation) só tem em comum a sintaxe um objeto em JS.

Quanto à função [`document.getElementById()`](https://www.w3.org/DOM/)

> Retorna a referência do elemento através do seu ID.

Ou seja, serve para conseguires "agarrar" um elemento do [DOM](https://www.w3.org/DOM/) (documento, HTML) através do seu id, ex:

```js
var elemento = document.getElementById('meu_id');
console.log("este é o elemento de que agora (graças a document.getElementById('meu_id')) temos a referência: ", elemento);

console.log('Vamos por ex mudar o seu comprimento/altura/cor de fundo');

elemento.style.width = "100px";
elemento.style.height = "120px";
elemento.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

console.log('Agora o elemento tem ' +elemento.style.width+ ' de comprimento, tem ' +elemento.style.height+ ' de altura e tem ' +elemento.style.backgroundColor+ ' como cor de fundo');
```

```html
<div id="meu_id"></div>
```