# JavaScript não executa

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```js
function idade() {

  var idade = document.getElementById('idade')

  alert("A idade do cliente é: " + idade);
}
```

```html
<form name="cliente">

  Nome: <input type="text" name="nome" /></br>
  </br>
  Endereço: <input type="text" name="endereco" /></br>
  </br>
  Cidade: <input type="text" name="cidade" /></br>
  </br>
  Sexo: <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="M" />Masculino
  <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="F" />Feminino</br>
  </br>
  Idade: <input type="text" name="idade" /></br>
  </br>

  <input type="submit" onclick="idade()" />

</form>
```

Porém, na hora que eu clico no botão nada acontece.

Comment: tem que por os id no input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta o `id="cliente"` no input  `Idade: <input type="text" name="idade"/>`

O `.value` depois do `document.getElementById('idade')`

E a função tinha o mesmo nome que a variável **idade**.

```js
function idadeCliente(){
 var idade = document.getElementById('idade').value;
 alert("A idade do cliente é: " + idade);
}
```

```html
<form name="cliente">

        Nome: <input type="text" name="nome"/></br></br>
        Endereço: <input type="text" name="endereco"/></br></br>
        Cidade: <input type="text" name="cidade"/></br></br>
        Sexo: <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="M"/>Masculino
              <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="F"/>Feminino</br></br>
        Idade: <input type="text" id="idade" name="idade"/></br></br>

        <input type="submit" onclick="idadeCliente()"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você selecionou um elemento com base na identificação exclusiva (id) com o método [getElementById()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/176652/defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o-document-getelementbyid) do objeto document. `document.getElementById('idade')`

O propósito do atributo global id, no seu caso `idade`, que deve ser único por todo o documento, é identificar o elemento quando manipulado por scripts ou estilizado com CSS.

Bem, no seu script, uma vez selecionado o elemento, só faltou obter o valor do elemento fazendo uso da propriedade **value** `document.getElementById('idade').value;`

> Outra coisa, o nome da função pode ser igual ao nome da variável porém pelo que testei **não deve ser igual ao id do input**.

```js
function idade() {
    var idade = document.getElementById('age').value;

    console.log("A idade do cliente é: " + idade);
}
```

```html
<form name="cliente">

    Nome: <input type="text" name="nome"/><br><br>
    Endereço: <input type="text" name="endereco"/><br><br>
    Cidade: <input type="text" name="cidade"/><br><br>
    Sexo: <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="M"/>Masculino
          <input type="radio" name="sexo" value="F"/>Feminino<br><br>
    Idade: <input id="age" type="text" name="age"/><br><br>

    <input type="button" value="Gerar" onclick="idade()">

</form>
```

> `</br>` não é uma tag HTML válida. É apenas `<br>`(ou `<br />`se você estiver usando o XHTML, mas se você estivesse usando o XHTML, você saberia disso)