# Como listar resultados da requisição feita em uma API REST utlizando React com Axios?

Tags: react, api, typescript, axios, jsx

Boa tarde, estou aprendendo a desenvolver em React e TypeScript, mas encontro dificuldades para implementar uma solução que envia uma requisição GET para a API REST e retorna dados para o projeto de um gerenciador de terminais no qual estou trabalhando.

**Problema:** No projeto em React, estou usando Axios para enviar requisições GET para a API REST e estou tendo dificuldades para encontrar uma solução para retornar os dados em TypeScript e JSX, linguagens e tecnologias onde não tenho muita experiência. Os códigos que já fiz e a solução que tentei encontrar podem ser observados logo abaixo.

`FirstComponent.tsx`

```js
import * as React from "react";
import { DropdownButton, FormControl, FormGroup, InputGroup, MenuItem, Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Button, ButtonGroup, ButtonToolbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { IndexLinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";
import "../App.css";
import API from "./FifthComponent";

export default class Terminal extends React.Component<{}> {
    public render() {
        // fazendo uma requisição GET na API com a URL e os dados a serem enviados
    
        const api = new API("https://api-homolog.ongocargas.com.br/v1/api/Terminal/get-terminal-listagem", "get", {pageSize: 10, pageIndex: 0, pesquisa: ""});
        
        // criando um array onde será guardado as linhas (registros) da tabela
        
        const htmltable: JSX.Element[] = [];
        
        // #1 exemplo para ver se a tabela será carregada
        
        htmltable.push(<i>foi apenas este</i>);
        
        // chamando um callback para retornar o resultado da requisição
        
        api.axiosReq.then((response) => {
            // criando uma variável para armazenar os dados dos terminais da API
        
            const terminals = response.data.data.data;
            
            // iterando os terminais e adicionando um por um no array dos registros
            
            for (let i = 0; i < terminals.length; i++) {
                htmltable.push(
                    <IndexLinkContainer to="/FourthComponent?terminal_id={terminals.id}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>{terminals.endereco.logradouro}</td>
                            <td>{terminals.endereco.cidade}</td>
                            <td>{terminals.endereco.estado}</td>
                            <td><IndexLinkContainer to="/ThirdComponent?terminal_id={terminals.id}"><i className="bi bi-pencil-square" /></IndexLinkContainer></td>
                        </tr>
                    </IndexLinkContainer>
                );
            }
        }).catch((err: any) => {
            // se houver erro de conexão, a tabela terá uma única linha com as informações da falha
            
            htmltable.push(<i>{JSON.stringify(err)}</i>);
        });
        
        // retornando a tabela na view com as linhas armazenadas no array 'htmltable'
        
        return (
            <><Table striped={true}>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Terminal</th>
                        <th>Cidade</th>
                        <th>Estado</th>
                        <th/>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {htmltable}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        );
    }
}
```

`FifthComponent.tsx`

```js
import axios, { AxiosInstance, AxiosPromise } from 'axios';
import '../App.css';

export default class API {
    private url: string;
    private typed: string;
    private data: object;
    private token: string;
    private headers = {};
    private axiosObj: AxiosInstance;
    private axiosRequest: AxiosPromise;
    private responseData: object;

    constructor (url: string, type: string, data?: object) {
        this.url = url;
        this.typed = type;
        this.token = "{TOKEN}";
        this.headers = {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.token,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        };

        if (data != null) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        this.axiosObj = axios.create({ headers: this.headers });

        switch (this.typed) {
            case "get":
                if (this.data != null) {
                    this.axiosRequest = this.axiosObj.get(this.url, {data: this.data});
                } else {
                    this.axiosRequest = this.axiosObj.get(this.url);
                }
            break;
            case "post":
                if (this.data != null) {
                    this.axiosRequest = this.axiosObj.post(this.url, {data: this.data});
                } else {
                    this.axiosRequest = this.axiosObj.post(this.url);
                }
            break;
            case "delete":
                if (this.data != null) {
                    this.axiosRequest = this.axiosObj.put(this.url, {data: this.data});
                } else {
                    this.axiosRequest = this.axiosObj.put(this.url);
                }
            break;
            case "put":
                if (this.data != null) {
                    this.axiosRequest = this.axiosObj.delete(this.url, {data: this.data});
                } else {
                    this.axiosRequest = this.axiosObj.delete(this.url);
                }
            break;
            default:
                
            break;
        }
    }

    get Url() {
        return this.url;
    }

    set Url(url: string) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    get tokenStr() {
        return this.token;
    }

    set tokenStr(token: string) {
        this.token = token;
    }

    set type(type: string) {
        this.typed = type;
    }

    get type() {
        return this.typed;
    }

    set dataSend(data: object) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    get dataSend() {
        return this.data;
    }

    set axiosOb(axiosOb: AxiosInstance) {
        this.axiosObj = axiosOb;
    }

    get axiosOb() {
        return this.axiosObj;
    }

    set axiosReq(axiosReq: AxiosPromise) {
        this.axiosRequest = axiosReq;
    }

    get axiosReq() {
        return this.axiosRequest;
    }

    set response(response: object) {
        this.responseData = response;
    }

    get response() {
        return this.responseData;
    }

    set headersData(headers) {
        this.headers = headers;
    }

    get headersData() {
        return this.headers;
    }
}
```

**Resultado:**

[image: Não aparece as outras linhas da tabela, apenas a primeira #1]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando acrescento a linha

`document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(terminals);`

após

`const terminals = response.data.data.data;`

O resultado aparece normalmente na tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **Problema:** Não consigo retornar todos os dados da API para listar os terminais na tabela. Tenho uma hipótese de que a função `api.axiosReq.then()` está sendo ignorada por algum motivo ou erro que fiz e não foi identificado na IDE. Desde então, quando vou executar o projeto no servidor aparece apenas a primeira linha #1 e não as restantes. **Qual a possível solução para este problema?**

Comment: Tem várias coisas estranhas no seu código, entre elas, um switch case no construtor que realiza requests com o axios, essa estratégia é bem estranha, e também os getters/setters anêmicos que estão só poluindo seu código. Além disso, acredito que você não esteja acostumado com Promise no JS/TS (async/await), sugiro ler com atenção sobre isso. Outra coisa, o axios geralmente retorna um objeto com a propriedade "data" com o conteúdo da response do seu request, não vi você tratando isso.

Comment: Percebi mais uma coisa, você está usando React com classes e não com function components, não é que esteja errado mas não é a maneira com a qual normalmente se trabalhar em novos projetos React/React Native. Outra coisa, você está fazendo uma requisição para API dentro da function render do component, isso pode gerar um gargalo enorme por conta das reenderizações que o React faz. Separe a renderização da request para a API.

Comment: Estou começando a usar React agora, por isso não tenho muita experiência.

Comment: Este código que fiz já estava pronto, foi apenas um modelo para usar como base no desenvolvimento da aplicação. Em relação com Promise no JS/TS, não tenho muita base no assunto, mas já tentei usar o (async/await) na função que havia declarado logo acima do render() e retornou o seguinte erro: ```Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. TypeScript```. Por isso deixei o código desse jeito.

Comment: E até cheguei a ver sobre React com function components, mas como a solução tem que ser criada com TypeScript + TSX, por isso optei por utilizar POO para desenvolver a estrutura da projeto, foi onde comecei a aprender TypeScript utilizando classes, namespaces e getters/setters.

Comment: Eu uso React com Typescript e function components normalmente, da mesma forma que você pode usar classes com Javascript puro. O TS para não é para adicionar classes ao JS. Cada vez mais as novidades do React serão voltadas mais para function components, o uso de hooks por exemplo, acredito que nem seja possível ou simples de usar usando classe component. E uma dica, OO é orientação a objetos e não orientação a classes, é possível programar OO sem nenhuma classe, principalmente em JS/TS.

Comment: Mas de toda forma, o erro que está tendo, acredito ser por conta da maneira que está usando axios, não com ser classes ou function components. Tem certeza que você deve fazer as requests no construtor da classe? Isso tá bem estranho.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129332/discussion-between-pe-math-and-jhonny-freire).

Comment: Entendo, tanto faz o modo que poderia fazer pois existem várias maneiras de conectar a API dentro desse projeto. Por exemplo, a maneira mais correta poderia ser a requisição com axios dentro de uma função na classe do ```Terminal```, que é onde mostra todos os registros da tabela que não foi construída por causa desse erro.

Comment: Talvez acredito que seja pela chamada de uma função anônima dentro da função then((response) => {}), que não interage diretamente com variáveis que chamo fora dela, por exemplo, a linha ```htmltable.push(...)``` não funciona dentro do `then` e o array ```htmltable``` foi declarado fora dela.

Comment: Se eu adicionar a linha ```document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(terminals);``` após a declaração da variável ```terminals``` dentro do ```then```, olha só o que acontece:

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CnhQ.png

Comment: Na imagem acima, o resultado da requisição está sendo mostrado na tela normalmente. O axios é semelhante ao AJAX em JavaScript, apenas queria alguma possível solução para este problema. O AJAX é uma função assíncrona, então todos os resultados dentro da callback devem ser retornados utlizando DOM em JavaScript puro ou em JS + jQuery. Em axios, é a mesma coisa, por isso estou precisando de ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei por encontrar uma solução que resolveu grande parte do meu problema. Após o `then()`, tive que usar outra função [`document.getElementById`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/176657/133502) dentro da função anônima `(response) => { ... }` para retornar os dados da [API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17552/133502) diretamente na [DOM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/40855/133502), ou seja na estrutura da página HTML.

Pelo que estava vendo e estudando, o [Axios](https://axios-http.com/) e [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) tem muitas semelhanças em comum, mas ambos trabalham de diversas maneiras em plataformas e linguagens diferentes. Por exemplo em [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), a solução encontrada no código abaixo não foi bem a desejada, pois tentei de diversas maneiras criar uma forma de jogar todos os elementos na tabela utilizando tags [JSX](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html) e HTML, mas pelos erros de código e renderização que a IDE estava retornando, optei por resolver este problema da forma mais simples. Após a declaração da variável `api`, escrevi:

`FirstComponent.tsx #37`

```js
api.axiosReq.then((response) => {
    const terminals = response.data.data.data;
    const tablebody = document.getElementById("table_body"); // <tbody id="table_body"/>

    if (tablebody != null) { // #2 verificação da variável para evitar erros de conteúdo nulo da IDE
        const tbody = tablebody;

        for (const terminal of terminals) {
            let htmlrow = "<tr>"; // criando a variável para armazenar as informações de cada linha da tabela
                htmlrow += "<td>" + terminal.nome + "</td>";
                htmlrow += "<td>" + terminal.endereco.cidade + "</td>";
                htmlrow += "<td>" + terminal.endereco.nomeEstado + "</td>";
                htmlrow += "<td>editar</td>";
            htmlrow += "</tr>";
            tbody.innerHTML += htmlrow; // acrescenta a linha htmlrow no corpo da tabela
        }
    }
}).catch((err: any) => {
    tbody.innerHTML += "Erro: " + JSON.stringify(err);
});
```

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Faz um bom tempo que não uso React com Class Component, mas vou te ajudar a organizar melhor e provavelmente resolver esse problema que está tendo. (Não rodei esse código, acredito que precisa de ajustes).

```
// api.ts
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from "axios";

export default class API {
  private baseUrl: string;
  private axiosInstance: AxiosInstance;

  constructor(url: string) {
    this.baseUrl = url;
    this.createAxios(url, "{TOKEN}");
  }

  get url(): string {
    return this.baseUrl;
  }

  private createAxios(url: string, token: string = ""): void {
    this.axiosInstance = axios.create({
      baseURL: url,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
  }

  async get<T = any>(url: string, params = {}): Promise<T> {
    return this.axiosInstance
      .get(url, params)
      .then((response) => response.data);
  }

  async post<T = any>(url: string, params = {}): Promise<T> {
    return this.axiosInstance
      .post(url, params)
      .then((response) => response.data);
  }

  async delete<T = any>(url: string, params = {}): Promise<T> {
    return this.axiosInstance
      .delete(url, params)
      .then((response) => response.data);
  }

  async put<T = any>(url: string, params = {}): Promise<T> {
    return this.axiosInstance
      .put(url, params)
      .then((response) => response.data);
  }
}
```

Veja que criei um tipo TerminalServerResponse para definir o retorno do servidor, mas você precisa sempre adequar a sua realidade. Vi no seu código um data.data.data, então precisa verificar a estrutura do seu retorno para o formato mais correto.

```
// terminal.tsx
import React from "react";
import { Table } from "react-bootstrap";
import { IndexLinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";
import API from "./api";

type TerminalServerResponse = {
  id: number;
  endereco: {
    logradouro: string;
    cidade: string;
    estado: string;
  };
};

export default class Terminal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      loading: true,
      content: null,
    };
  }

  createTerminalTableRow = (terminal: TerminalServerResponse): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <IndexLinkContainer to={`/FourthComponent?terminal_id=${terminal.id}`}>
        <tr>
          <td>{terminal.endereco.logradouro}</td>
          <td>{terminal.endereco.cidade}</td>
          <td>{terminal.endereco.estado}</td>
          <td>
            <IndexLinkContainer to={`/ThirdComponent?terminal_id=${terminal.id}`}>
              <i className="bi bi-pencil-square" />
            </IndexLinkContainer>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </IndexLinkContainer>
    );
  };

  getFromServer = async () => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    const api = new API("https://api-homolog.ongocargas.com.br/v1/api");

    try {
      const dataResult = await api.get<TerminalServerResponse[]>(
        "/Terminal/get-terminal-listagem",
        { pageSize: 10, pageIndex: 0, pesquisa: "" }
      );
      const htmltable: JSX.Element[] = [];

      dataResult.forEach((terminal) => {
        htmltable.push(this.createTerminalTableRow(terminal));
      });

      this.setState({ data: dataResult, content: htmltable, loading: false });
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ loading: false });
      alert("Erro");
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getFromServer();
  }

  public render() {
    const { loading, content } = this.state;

    if (loading) {
      // retormar algum tipo de spinner ou coisa assim
    }

    return (
      <Table striped={true}>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Terminal</th>
            <th>Cidade</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th />
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{content}</tbody>
      </Table>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Na classe API no arquivo api.ts, os métodos com a visibilidade ```async``` estão retornando o seguinte erro:

Comment: async não é uma visibilidade, é a definição de uma função/método assíncrono. Mas de qualquer forma no seu comentário não tem os dados do erro, poderia descrever melhor?

Comment: Ops, desculpe, acabei apertando o enter sem querer. Mas de qualquer forma, consegui resolver o problema. Como Axios tem uma funcionalidade semelhante ao AJAX, acabei por optar em usar JavaScript puro para preencher a tabela de acordo com a DOM. Mas preciso treinar ainda em React com TypeScript como utilizo hooks e variáveis de estado para serem definidas em funções anônimas utilizando callbacks.