# É possível ter um array de arrays?

Tags: javascript

É possível inserir em um array, como elemento, outro array? Ou seja, fazer um array de arrays? I.e.:

```
array[

       [0] => valor => array( 
                             [0]=> valor 1, 
                             [1]=> valor 2,
                             [2]=> valor 3 
                            )

     ];
```

Comment: O que você esteve tentando? E o formato não ficou muito claro pra mim George.

Comment: No javascript você irá usar objetos para arrays multidimensionais https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: tipo assim no index de um array se poderia adicionar outro array

Comment: Pelo que vi você quer algo como o [tag:JSON] veja nesta minha resposta sobre o que é o JSON, caso você ainda não o conheça: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4171/3082

Answer (score 2):

**Edição**

De acordo com o autor da pergunta, em comentário a esta resposta:

> tem como ficar nesse formato { "1":[ {"name":"John","Age":"21"} ] "2":[ {"name":"Jone","Age":"22"} ] }

Aparentemente você deseja montar um JSON, onde cada propriedade é um número sequencial. O que você precisa então não é de um array, e sim de um objeto.

Ao converter um array para JSON, você terá apenas os seus elementos:

```
JSON.stringify(['fus', 'ro', 'dah']);
// resulta em "["fus", "ro", "dah"]"
```

Para que cada chave esteja representada textualmente no JSON, você precisa da seguinte construção. Experimente no console:

```
var objeto = {};
objeto["1"] = { name: "John", age: "21"};
objeto["2"] = { name: "Jone", age: "22"};
JSON.stringify(objeto);
```

Note que:

- Você tem um objeto que têm por propriedades outros objetos. Isso não é um array de arrays;
- Dessa forma as chaves não são necessariamente sequenciais - você pode usar qualquer coisa no lugar dos números. Note também que poderá não existir garantia de ordem das propriedades, caso você rode em ambientes diferentes do navegador.

**Resposta original**

Sim, é possível. Experimente o seguinte código no console do navegador:

```
var foo = [];
foo[0] = [1, 2, 3];
foo[1] = [4, 5, 6];
foo;
```

Note que isso não é a melhor prática. Se você for inserir diretamente em índices específicos, a responsabilidade de manter os índices contínuos e de garantir que não haja sobrescrita acidental é sua. Isso é simples em um código de exemplo como o código acima, mas conforme seu código cresce isso se torna mais complicado e aberto a bugs.

A melhor forma é utilizando a inserção padrão do array:

```
var foo = [];
foo.push([1, 2, 3]);
foo.push([4, 5, 6]);
foo;
```

Comment: tem como ficar nesse formato                                                                  {
     "1":[
        {"name":"John","Age":"21"}
      ]
     "2":[
        {"name":"Jone","Age":"22"}
      ]
    }

Comment: @George essa estrutura que você quer é um [tag:JSON] que é diferente de um simples array, teste inserir este trecho no site http://json.parser.online.fr

Comment: @George editei a resposta. O que você queria no final das contas é algo diferente do que você perguntou.

Comment: Eis um belo exemplo: `JSON.stringify(['fus', 'ro', 'dah']);` só os fortes entenderam