# Dúvida simples sobre json

Tags: jquery, json

Gostaria de ter certeza do que é considerado um código json. Por exemplo o código abaixo seria considerado um json ?

```
$(".hide").css("display","block");
```

Se sim por quê? Se não quais formatos de código são considerados json?

Comment: Json não executa nada, são como dados, logo o código acima executa uma função logo não são dados e não pode ser um json. De resto a resposta esta na pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4042/o-que-%c3%a9-json-para-que-serve-e-como-funciona

Answer (score 2):

Este código que você postou é somente um trecho de jquery.

**JSON: JavaScript Object Notation**

Como o proprio nome diz é apenas uma notação, ou seja uma forma de escrever.

Veja um exemplo de um código JSON:

```
{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }
```

Ele é muito usado para construção de webservices, a maioria das linguagens tem suporte tornado um meio de comunicação entre elas e também entre sistemas.

Uma linguagem que tem uma função parecida que você pode conhecer e o xml.

Expliquei de uma maneira fácil e simples, para saber mais leia sobre neste link: http://www.json.org