# Como enviar essa requisição ajax?

Tags: php, json

Vejam esse print:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na verdade aí acima se trata de uma requisição ajax já enviada, e eu quero aprender como escrever isso, olha como eu fiz e não tá dando certo:

```
$.ajax({ 

    url:'linkdeumsitequaisquer.com.br',
    type:'post',
    data:{questionId: 1, questionKey: "IDENTITY_SAFETYQUESTION_1},
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(res) {
        alert(res);

   }






});
```

Eu sinto que está faltando alguma coisa, pois tem esse 0 e 1 aí , no caso deve ser vetor dentro do data né? Alguma coisa assim não sei muito de teoria, tem outra coisa que o povo fala de objeto eu também não sei objetos relaciona ao javascript não to entendendo isso, eu sei que objeto é class carro { } no *PHP* fora isso não sei.

Mas resumindo é:
- Como escrever a requisição *AJAX* como foi enviado na imagem?
- Oque é objeto no javascript esse negocio de manipulação de *JSON* e tal

Comment: Não esta dando certo porque está faltando `"` ... `questionKey: "IDENTITY_SAFETYQUESTION_1}` **<~** não esta fechando.

Comment: Em javascript, [Tudo é objeto.](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Trabalhando_com_Objetos), rs ou quase tudo. Encontrei até o teu exemplo de class carro lá. Aliás é engraçado que o pessoal que aprende OOP sempre começa com `class carro` ou `class pessoa` kkkk.

Comment: Não entendi amigos por favor exemplifique

Comment: Já verificou a falta das aspas como apontado no primeiro comentário? O que aparece no console do navegador?

Comment: Tenta `[{questionId: 1, questionKey: "IDENTITY_SAFETYQUESTION_1"}]`, você não pode passar apenas o objeto, mas sim um `array` de objetos, por isso ele não mostra os indices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Como escrever a requisição AJAX como foi enviado na imagem?

O seu código tem dois erros, o primeiro é não fechar as aspas, e o segundo é não passar um array, por isso não está igual a imagem, para ter o resultado que procura, seu código deverá ficar assim:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:'linkdeumsitequaisquer.com.br',
    type:'post',
    data: [{questionId: 1, questionKey: "IDENTITY_SAFETYQUESTION_1"}],
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(res) {
        alert(res);
   }
});
```

Do jeito que você fez, só poderia mandar um objeto por vez, você pode mandar vários inserindo cada um dentro de `[]` e separando cada um por `,`

Ex.:

```
data: [{questionId: 1, questionKey: "IDENTITY_SAFETYQUESTION_1"},
       {questionId: 3, questionKey: "IDENTITY_SAFETYQUESTION_3"}]
```

> O que é objeto no javascript

Acho que esse link responde essa pergunta:
[Como funcionam protótipos em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15239/como-funcionam-prot%C3%B3tipos-em-javascript/)

> esse negócio de manipulação de JSON

E esse também responde a última pergunta:
[O que é JSON? Para que serve e como funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4042/o-que-%C3%A9-json-para-que-serve-e-como-funciona)