# Salvar um arquivo JSON dentro de colchetes e separados por virgula

Tags: php, json

Estou querendo salvar um arquivo `dados.json`, onde os dados do formulário são enviados via POST para um arquivo `dados.php` por AJAX.

O código do `dados.php` é o seguinte:

```php
$array = array();
$fp = fopen("dados.json", "a");
$escreve = fwrite($fp, $array[0] = json_encode($_POST));
fclose($fp);
```

A estrutura dos dados que o `dados.php` gera para o `dados.json` é:

```js
{"nome":"fulano","numero":"1"}
```

O problema é que eu queria fazer uma estrutura em que esses dados enviados estivessem dentro colchetes e que no final de cada chave tivesse uma virgula, mas toda vez que envio os dados, eles são salvos no `dados.json` é gerado assiim:

```js
{"nome":"fulano","numero":"1"}{"nome":"fulano2","numero":"3"}
```

Não está separado por virgula. Tentei de outra forma com o seguinte código:

```php
$array = array($_POST);
$jsonDados = json_encode($array);
$fp = fopen("dados.json", "a");
$escreve = fwrite($fp, $jsonDados);
fclose($fp);
```

Mas agora o `dados.json` ficou assim:

```js
[{"nome":"fulano","numero":"1"}][{"nome":"fulano2","numero":"3"}]
```

Eu só queira fazer que esses dados sejam salvos assim:

```js
[{"nome":"fulano","numero":"1"},{"nome":"fulano2","numero":"3"}]
```

E que toda vez que houver um envio do formulário para o `dados.php`, ele salve o JSON separando as chaves por virgulas dentro dos colchetes.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer nesse formato:

```js
[{"nome":"fulano","numero":"1"},{"nome":"fulano2","numero":"3"}]
```

Então você tem que gerar um array, no qual cada elemento é um dos objetos contendo o nome e número. Pois segundo a [sintaxe do formato JSON](https://www.json.org), os colchetes servem para delimitar um array (ver mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/517767/112052)).

Mas aí temos que avaliar como fazer. Vamos supor que o conteúdo atual do arquivo seja esse:

```js
[{"nome":"fulano","numero":"1"}]
```

Se a ideia é adicionar outro elemento no mesmo JSON array, não podemos simplesmente concatenar no final. Pois o que queremos é que ele fique igual ao primeiro JSON acima (ou seja, todos os elementos dentro dos colchetes, e separados por vírgula).

Sendo assim, uma solução seria ler o arquivo, fazer o parsing do JSON (gerando um array), adicionar os dados nesse array, converter de volta para JSON e escrever no arquivo:

```php
$arquivo = 'dados.json';
if (file_exists($arquivo)) { // arquivo existe, lê o conteúdo e faz o parsing do JSON
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($arquivo), true);
} else { // arquivo não existe, começa com um array vazio
    $json = [];
}

// adiciona os dados no JSON array
$json[] = $_POST;

// escreve no arquivo
file_put_contents($arquivo, json_encode($json));
```

Assim, na primeira vez (quando o arquivo ainda não existir), será escrito nele:

```js
[{"nome":"fulano","numero":"1"}]
```

Na segunda vez que receber dados, esse arquivo será lido e `json_decode` irá fazer o parsing desse conteúdo, gerando um array. Depois adicionamos o novo conteúdo neste array, usamos `json_encode` para convertê-lo para JSON e escrevemos isso no arquivo. O resultado será:

```js
[{"nome":"fulano","numero":"1"},{"nome":"fulano2","numero":"3"}]
```

E assim por diante. A cada nova chamada, um novo elemento é adicionado no array, como por exemplo:

```js
[{"nome":"fulano","numero":"1"},{"nome":"fulano2","numero":"3"},{"nome":"fulano3","numero":"42"}]
```

---

Claro que isso pode ser tornar um problema no futuro, conforme o arquivo vai ficando grande. Neste caso, talvez precise de [algo assim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4049428). Ou, se chegar a um volume considerável de dados, talvez seja melhor usar um banco de dados mesmo. Mas aí já estamos fugindo demais do escopo...

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
$dados = json_decode(file_get_contents ("dados.json"));
array_push($dados, $_POST);
$fp = fopen("dados.json", "a");
fwrite($fp, json_encode($dados));
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: ok, mas o  resultado no dados.json sempre vai ser `{"nome":"fulano","numero":"1"}` e toda vez que for enviado do formulário os dados vai ser salvo em sequencia ex `{"nome":"fulano","numero":"1"}{"nome":"fulano","numero":"1"}` eu queria uma estrutura em que toda vez que houver um envio do formulário para o dados.php, ele salve o json separando as chaves por virgulas dentro do colchetes, como me referi na pergunta, existe um meio de fazer isso?

Comment: Alterei a resposta