# Buscar conteúdo de um arquivo online

Tags: c#, string, webclient

```
string nome, idade, valores;

WebClient WEBC = new WebClient();

public void Exemplo()
{
    valores = WEBC.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/r4GjhKQ3");
}
```

Eu quero pegar os valores do nome e da idade após o '=' da variável 'valores' (https://pastebin.com/raw/r4GjhKQ3) e depois eu quero salvar esses valores nas variáveis que eu declarei ali em cima (nome e idade).

**EDIT**

E se eu eu precisar colocar mais usuários? Por exemplo:

```
{
    "Users":[{"Nome":"Pedro","Idade":"25"},{"Nome":"Lucas","Idade":"19"}]
}
```

Comment: Esse texto do Pastebin existe padrão ou linguagem de mark-up específica?

Comment: tem a possibilidade de transformar em json como mostrou o perozzo ou necessariamente precisa ser no formato em que está ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente, recomendo que utilize uma estrutura de texto/arquivo bem definida para salvar suas informações, como por exemplo JSON. Isso irá tornar o tratamento dos seus dados mais simples e prático de manipular.

JSON é basicamente um formato leve de troca de informações/dados entre sistemas e significa JavaScript Object Notation. Não se assuste com o "JavaScript", pois não é apenas com Javascript que podemos usar esse tipo de arquivo. Recomendo que leia um pouco mais sobre o assunto e entenda como esse tipo de arquivo funciona e sua estrutura.

**Leitura recomendada**: [O que é JSON?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4042/o-que-%C3%A9-json-para-que-serve-e-como-funciona)

#### Transformando seu arquivo em JSON

Substitua o conteúdo do seu arquivo *User:(nome=Pedro,idade=25)* por:

```
{
    "Nome" : "Pedro",
    "Idade" : "25"
}
```

Você pode salvar o arquivo com o formato `.json` ao invés de `.txt` e enviar para o *Pastebin*. Feito isso, podemos ir para a parte do código.

#### Instalando a biblioteca que irá manipular seu arquivo JSON

No Visual Studio (acredito que esteja usando-o para codificar em C#), dentro do seu projeto, clique com o botão direito em `References` e depois selecione a opção `Manage NuGet Packages`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso, selecione `Browse`, na caixa de texto digite "json", selecione o item `Newtonsoft.Json` e depois clique em instalar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Criando a classe modelo para seu arquivo JSON

Dentro do seu projeto, adicione uma classe que será usada como modelo para seu arquivo JSON. Dado a sua pergunta, estamos falando de um usuário, então, crie uma classe chamada `Usuario` que possua a seguinte estrutura:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Idade { get; set; }
}
```

Perceba que o nome das propriedades da classe são **exatamente** iguais aos nomes que estão na estrutura do seu JSON. Neste primeiro momento e até você se familiarizar com o JSON, temos que manter dessa forma.

#### Manipulando seu arquivo JSON

Agora que temos o nosso ambiente pronto, podemos começar a manipular os dados do nosso arquivo JSON.

Na mesma classe que colocou o código na pergunta, coloque a seguinte diretiva `using` no topo da sua classe:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Agora, faça o download do seu arquivo e transforme ele em um objeto do tipo `Usuario`, que foi a classe modelo que criamos anteriormente:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();

string result = web.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/j0P175Wq");

Usuario usuario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Usuario>(result);
```

O link que usei é de um arquivo que coloquei no Pastebin para usar de exemplo. Lembre de alterar o link para o link do seu arquivo.

Ao executar o código acima, você irá perceber que o conteúdo do seu arquivo JSON que estava no *Pastbin* foi transformado para um objeto do tipo `Usuario` que no código acima chamei de `usuario`. Com isso, conseguimos acessar o objeto e verificar suas propriedades `Nome` e `Idade`, as quais irão conter exatamente o que está no seu arquivo JSON:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para finalizar, coloque o conteúdo do objeto `usuario`, nas variáveis desejadas:

```
string nome = usuario.Nome;
string idade = usuario.Idade;
```

#### E caso queira colocar mais usuários?

Do modelo que expliquei, apenas 1 usuário por arquivo seria permitido (esperei surgir sua dúvida para que pudesse concluir em definitivo a pergunta). Agora vamos as modificações para que seja possível buscar mais usuários do arquivo.

Vi que já criou uma estrutura bem bacana para seu arquivo, vamos mantê-la e modificar apenas nosso código.

Dada sua estrutura, o arquivo possui um objeto `Users` que é uma lista de usuários, ou seja, uma lista da nossa classe `Usuario` anteriormente criada.

Vamos criar agora uma outra classe, chamada `Arquivo`, que servirá como o **novo** modelo do arquivo JSON:

```
public class Arquivo
{
    public List<Usuario> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Perceba que essa nova classe possui a propriedade `Users`, que é exatamente igual ao nome que deu para sua lista de usuários no seu arquivo JSON. Perceba também que a propriedade é uma lista de `Usuario`. Lembre-se de usar a diretiva `using System.Collections.Generic` para ter acesso ao `List`.

Feito isso, modifique o seu trecho de código que faz a manipulação do arquivo JSON para que se pareça com isso:

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();

string result = web.DownloadString("https://pastebin.com/raw/j0P175Wq");

Arquivo arquivo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Arquivo>(result);

List<Usuario> usuarios = arquivo.Users;
```

Aqui, perceba que não é mais a classe `Usuario` que serve como modelo para o arquivo JSON, e sim a classe `Arquivo` através da linha `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Arquivo>`.

Ao executar o código acima, irá perceber que a lista de usuários está dentro do objeto `arquivo` e dentro da propriedade `Users`.

Comment: Valeu mesmo! Não conhecia esse método.