# Por que objetos JavaScript nem sempre são JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Isso por exemplo:

```
{
   "nome": "Meu nome",
   "sobrenome": "Meu sobrenome"
}
```

Pode ser considerado um Objeto e também um Json? Se não, por que não? O que vai diferenciar um do outro é na hora de instanciar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***"Pode ser considerado um Objeto e também um Json? Se não, por que não?"***
Porque objetos `javascript` existem desde que a linguagem foi criada, e o `JSON` é uma forma de representar os objetos e foi criada depois, em formato texto, que é utilizada para transferir esse objetos, por exemplo executando um serviço. Inclusive não precisa necessariamente ser um objeto Javascript, pode ser convertido para um objeto em outra linguagem.

Ou seja, um objeto é uma coisa, JSON é uma forma de representá-lo apenas. Tanto que é que, para trabalhar com ou JSON como objeto, é necessário convertê-lo para um objeto.

***"O que vai diferenciar um do outro é na hora de instanciar?"***
Existem estruturas em objetos que não podem ser convertidas para JSON, portanto nem todo objeto pode ser convertido para JSON.

Um exemplo é que JSON não permite elementos vazios em array como Javascript permite, por exemplo assim: `[1, , 2]`.

Você pode ler mais aqui nessa outra pergunta: [o que é json para que serve e como funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4042/o-que-%C3%A9-json-para-que-serve-e-como-funciona)

Aqui um ótimo link do SO sobre as limitações de converter um objeto javascript para JSON: [are all json objects also valid javascript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752156/are-all-json-objects-also-valid-javascript-objects)

Comment: Pontual, sua resposta veio em ótima hora </trocadilho>. Pude perceber pelos links que você colou diretamente do browser os links para as perguntas. Se você se preocupar com o seu "impacto na comunidade", esse não é o jeito mais eficiente. Quando você clica no botão "compartilhar", o sistema te gera um link no formato `/q/{qid}/{uid}`, onde o `qid` é o id da questão e `uid` é o id do usuário que compartilhou. Enfim, eu gosto de ter noção do quanto estou impactando, então considero isso importante.

Comment: Bom trocadilho :) 
Vi que você editou e ficou com, eu tinha removido da descrição o dns mas estava meio "sujo" o link no final, além de não ser pelo compartilhar, ficou bem melhor mesmo

Answer (score 10):

JSON é uma notação. No caso, voltada para serializar e desserializar informações.

Ele não é um objeto no sentido de possuir comportamentos, é mais uma estrutura crua. Seria algo semelhante à `struct` do C: apenas um conjunto de dados.

No JavaScript, um objeto contém também comportamento e referência a variáveis. Como o JSON é um dado, ele só contém constantes, portanto não possui estrutura para armazenar nem variáveis, nem métodos/funções.

E, sim, o exemplo que você forneceu, por conter apenas constantes, pode ser caracterizado como JSON. E obviamente é também um objeto JavaScript.

Answer (score 9):

JSON é texto, é uma *String*.
Ele é compatível com JavaScript porque foi criado usando a sintaxe dessa linguagem, mas para um JSON se tornar num objeto ele tem de ser interpretado ("parsed").

Nem todos os Objetos podem ser transformados em JSON. Funções e referências a partes de sí próprio não são permitidas em JSON. Todos as strings JSON podem ser interpretadas para gerar um Objeto.

```js
const json = `
  {
   "nome": "Meu nome",
   "sobrenome": "Meu sobrenome"
  }
`;

const obj = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(json.nome); // udefined
console.log(obj.nome); // "Meu nome"
```