# Existe um padrão para nomenclatura das chaves de um JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

Estou consumindo um JSON, e quero usar as chaves deste JSON como options de um select, porém a nomenclatura está em camelCase e sem acentos, ex:

```
    "destaques": [
      {
        "fornecedoresCompany": [
          {
            "5OouMaisFuncionarios": "value..."
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
```

Tem algum problema se eu utilizar da seguinte forma?

```
    "Destaques": [
      {
        "Fornecedores Company": [
          {
            "5O ou Mais Funcionários": "value..."
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
```

Se não for correto utilizar desta forma, existe alguma outra solução?
Com javascript? Preciso utilizar as chave como option para que seja dinâmico, não adianta fazer somente uma validação no código comparando e alterando a string.

Comment: O problema de variáveis com espaço é caso você precise deserializar, nenhuma linguagem aceita espaço na nomenclatura de variáveis e você vai ter que fazer um mapeamento complexo para resolver isso. Acentos são aceitos, mas em alguns casos podem ser lidos de forma diferente em diferentes editores.(problema de encoding)

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/313493/64969

Answer (score 2):

Não existem limitações à chave JSON, ela é uma string.

[Seção 7 da RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-7) define o que é string, enquanto que a [seção 4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-4) define que um membro é constituído por `<string> <separador> <valor>`, portanto define que a chave do JSON é uma string genérica.

Note que em alguns casos um objeto JSON (não confundir com array JSON) será desserializado como um mapa, e isso não muda em nada o fato de se usar espaços no nome das chaves. Mas tem também alguns frameworks e bibliotecas que tentam associar o nome da chave com o de alguma propriedade de objetos, aí nesses casos você [teria problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/313944/existe-um-padr%C3%A3o-para-nomenclatura-das-chaves-de-um-json#comment637495_313944).

Parece-me que você tem controle sobre a produção do JSON. Nesse caso, talvez você pudesse informar os nomes desejados de exibição não na chave, mas como valor de algum membro do JSON. Sem maiores contextos fica-me complicado tentar bolar algum exemplo significativo:

```
{ "destaques":
  { "nomeExibir": "Destaques",
    "valores":
    [
      { "fornecedoresCompany":
        { "nomeParaExibir": "Fornecedores Company",
          "valores":
          [
            { "nomeParaExibir": "50 ou mais funcionários",
              "valor": "value..."
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```