# Qual a diferença entre usar toString() e JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript, json, string

```
var arr = [1,2,3];

arr.toString(); // "1,2,3"
JSON.stringify(arr); // "[1,2,3]"
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 10):

[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) é uma função do objeto `JSON` que criará uma *string* do objeto dentro do padrão adotado pelo JSON. Por uma quase coincidência (não é 100% porque JSON é baseado na notação do JS) o método [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) dá o mesmo resultado, a princípio.

Se algum objeto criar uma forma especializada do `toString()` o resultado pode ser outro. O `JSON.stringify()` precisa de mais estabilidade. O exemplo já mostra que pode ser diferente.

Uma coisa que eu digo é que [as pessoas usam o `toString()` errado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/101), elas não entendem que não é um método para criar um texto mostrado todo o objeto, ele pode ter resultados bem diferentes do esperado e é comum em muitos objetos só mostrar o nome da classe, o que não tem serventia para quase nada a não ser depuração.

E fica óbvio que o fato de um ser uma função e outro ser um método também é diferente, o segundo pode ter um objeto nulo normalmente, o primeiro não pode.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 8):

- [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) devolve a representação em string do objeto, no caso da pergunta, de um array
- [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) converte um valor javascript, no caso da pergunta um array, num JSON

Se apenas pretende mostrar o resultado na página para o usuário, então pode não fazer diferença uma vez que o usuário percebe a informação estando ela de uma forma ou de outra.

Mas lembre-se que JSON é um formato de dados, e se tiver o JSON correspondente ao array, o `[1,2,3]`, você consegue reconstruir o array utilizando [JSON.Parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```js
console.log(JSON.parse("[1,2,3]"));
```

O mesmo já não acontece se apenas tiver o texto que sai do `toString` pois não é um JSON:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse("1,2,3"));
```

Por isso deve utilizar `JSON.stringify` quando quiser obter um JSON que represente o valor que tem, seja ele um objeto, um array, uma data, etc. Isto é comum em troca de informação, como por exemplo no envio e receção de valores para API's.

Já o `toString` é comum de ser usado para obter uma representação em texto do objeto em questão.

Answer (score 2):

Complementando as outras respostas: a string que `JSON.stringify` retorna sempre é um *JSON Text* válido (ou seja, uma string no [formato JSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4042/112052)). Em alguns casos, **por coincidência**, pode retornar algo igual ao resultado de `toString()` (ou pelo menos "parecido"). Mas `toString` não tem essa obrigatoriedade de retornar em um formato específico.

Uma diferença importante é que `JSON.stringify` não funciona para qualquer tipo. Por exemplo, para `RegExp` retorna uma objeto vazio, e com `BigInt` dá erro (mas vale lembrar que não se limita a esses tipos):

```js
let regex = /\w+/;
console.log(JSON.stringify(regex)); // '{}'
console.log(regex.toString()); // '/^\w+/'

let bigint = 123n;
console.log(bigint.toString()); // 123
console.log(JSON.stringify(bigint)); // erro!
```

Além disso, `JSON.stringify` não suporta referências circulares, seja um objeto apontando para ele mesmo:

```js
var a = [ 1, 2 ];
// array apontando para ele mesmo
a.push(a);

console.log('toString() ->', a.toString()); // 1,2,
console.log('JSON ->', JSON.stringify(a)); // erro!
```

Ou um objeto que aponta para outro, que por sua vez aponta de volta para o primeiro:

```js
var a = { x: 1 };
var b = { y: 2 };
// "a" aponta para "b", que aponta para "a"
a.value = b;
b.value = a;

console.log('toString() ->', a.toString()); // [object Object]
console.log('JSON ->', JSON.stringify(a)); // erro!
```

---

Outro ponto é que se o objeto passado para `JSON.stringify` tiver definido o método `toJSON`, este será usado para serializá-lo:

```js
var a = { x: 1, y: 2 };
a.toString = function() {
    return `toString=${this.x}`;
}

console.log('toString() ->', a.toString()); // toString=1

// por padrão, JSON.stringify gera um JSON Text com todas as propriedades
console.log('JSON ->', JSON.stringify(a)); // {"x":1,"y":1}

// ao definir o método toJSON, JSON.stringify passa a usar o retorno deste
a.toJSON = function() {
    return `toJSON customizado ${this.x}`;
}
console.log('JSON ->', JSON.stringify(a)); // retorna a string "toJSON customizado 1"
```

Assim, seria possível contornar as limitações citadas acima (por exemplo, tornando possível serializar instâncias de [regex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/555343/112052) ou [`BigInt`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/525381/112052)).

---

Por fim, vale reforçar o que já foi dito nas outras respostas, em especial a questão semântica: `toString` retorna (ou pelo menos deveria) uma representação textual do objeto, ([e todas as suas nuances são discutidas aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/212754/112052)), enquanto `JSON.stringify` é mais rígido e deve retornar um *JSON Text* válido, que deve ser reconhecido por `JSON.parse`.