# Como serializar e desserializar objetos contendo valores do tipo BigInt em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, serialização, desserialização, bigint

Vamos adotar um código qualquer de exemplo que contém um valor do tipo [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt):

```
const params = { largeNum: 54740991n }
```

Se eu tentar serializá-lo com `JSON.stringify` é retornado um erro:

```js
const params = { largeNum: 54740991n }

JSON.stringify(params)
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt

Outro exemplo com níveis:

```js
const response = {
  data: {
    number: {
      theBiggestInt: 1n
    }
  },
  status: true
};

JSON.stringify(response);
```

Com base nos exemplos acima, eu pergunto:

- É possível serializar um objeto que contenha uma propriedade (que esteja ou não aninhada no objeto) do tipo `BigInt`?
- Se sim, como desserializar?

Comment: Uai....por que o negativo?? Onde eu posso melhorar a pergunta?

Comment: Usar RegEx para isso pode ser um tanto quanto custoso, partindo da premissa que um sulfixo ou prefixo resolvem (até o momento único meio que resolve mais ou menos) um `val.indexOf('prefixo_bigint::') === 0` + `val.substring(16)` (use i o 16 fixo porque sabemos qual o "prefixo" desejado), imaginando que o cenário (que é a maioria) do parse de JSON seja para enviar grandes payloads, se o payload enviado for pequeno nem de JSON.stringify vai precisar, poderia fazer algo próprio na mão.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Obrigado pela observacao. Concordo com seu ponto, inclusive a solucao do hkotsubo dispensa o uso de regex e segue uma abordagem semelhante ao seu comentário.

Comment: Eu vi, o edit foi depois do meu comment ;) Manterei o comment devido a questão de quando um implementação assim é necessária e quando não é (o que na maioria é provavel que não seja mesmo)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Concordo que regex é um exagero (quase sempre é), por isso revi a resposta e copiei descaradamente sua sugestão :-) Eu só troquei `indexOf` por `startsWith` por me parecer mais semanticamente adequado ao caso (ou talvez seja só "gosto pessoal" da minha parte). E também concordo que dependendo do caso, talvez nem seja necessário tudo isso...

Comment: @hkotsubo vou olhar a resposta com calma, só acho que não é bem questão de semantica, mas sim de "disponibilidade", se esta em um ambiente que suporta, browsers modernos ou Node esta ótimo, se deseja que rode em qualquer lugar sem preocupação um `indexOf` funcionará muito bem e nos testes de benchmark que fiz o `indexOf` foi quase o dobro mais rápido que o `startsWith`, mas não estou falando só de performance, estou só somando "vantagens", claro que o código da resposta funciona. Se puder explicar sobre quando "reimplementar" o `JSON.stringify` é dispensável vai ficar uma resposta sensacional

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Atualizei a resposta. Ainda vou revisá-la mais tarde, pois acho que algumas ideias ainda dá para desenvolver melhor...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não tem nenhum jeito “padrão” para fazer essa serialização.

O jeito mais trivial de contornar esse problema é utilizar o segundo argumento de `JSON.stringify`, que recebe uma função para modificar a forma como os dados são serializados.

Um exemplo, bastante simplista, que converte o `bigint` em string é este:

```js
const obj = { data: 1n };
const json = JSON.stringify(obj, (key, val) =>
  typeof val === 'bigint' ? val.toString() : val
);
console.log(json);
```

O problema com isso é que, uma vez que o valor foi convertido a uma string, o tipo original do dado é *perdido* na serialização.

Como não existe nenhum padrão difundido sobre *como* serializar esse tipo de dado não nativamente suportado pelo `JSON.stringify`, há de se estabelecer uma *convenção interna* ao seu projeto para determinar como essa serialização deverá ser feita, de modo a armazenar não somente a string que representa o `bigint`, mas também uma informação que informe que se trata de um `bigint`. Desse modo, contorna-se o problema de perda de informação ao simplesmente converter o *big int* em string.

Um exemplo é anotar a string com um *prefixo mágico* como `__bigint__:`, de modo que o *big int* `5n` seria serializado como a string `"__bigint__:5"`.

Um outro modo, talvez mais prático, é utilizar um objeto para codificar não apenas a *string* que represente o `bigint`, mas também seu tipo. Assim:

```js
const obj = { data: 5n };
const json = JSON.stringify(obj, (_, val) => {
  if (typeof val === 'bigint') {
    return { $$type: 'bigint', $$str: val.toString() };
  }
  
  return val;
});
console.log(json);
```

<sup>Utilizei os nomes `$$type` e `$$str` para evitar conflitos com outros objetos que, por ventura, poderiam ter as propriedades `type` e `str`. Apesar de improvável, isso demonstra a importância de se definir uma boa convenção para serializar esse tipo de dado; visando, claro, evitar conflitos com padrões já existentes.</sup>

E para deserializar fazer o caminho inverso. Nesse caso, deve-se fazer uso do segundo argumento de `JSON.parse` para tratar o objeto especial (ou forma alternativa de serialização) anteriormente convencionado. Exemplo:

```js
const json = '{"data":{"$$type":"bigint","$$str":"5"}}';

const obj = JSON.parse(json, (_, value) => {
  if (
    typeof value === 'object' &&
    value.$$type === 'bigint' &&
    typeof value.$$str === 'string'  
  ) {
    return BigInt(value.$$str);
  }
  
  return value;
});

console.log(obj); //=> { data: 5n }
                  // tem que olhar pelo console do navegador, o snippet não exibe propriamente
```

---

O intuito é dar uma ideia porque, tal como demonstrado pela [outra excelente resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/526417/69296), dá para ser bem criativo aqui. Mas devo reiterar a importância de se convencionar, internamente, um padrão e garantir que o *novo formato de serialização* não conflite com outros casos de uso.

Vale lembrar que essa técnica vale não somente para serializar `bigint`. Esses mesmos passos podem ser aplicados para serializar qualquer tipo de dados que o JavaScript não suporta nativamente pelo `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 10):

Uma abordagem diferente e que não envolvesse análise de strings seria serializar o valor [BigInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) como um objeto [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-pt.html) personalizado que guarde, em um array, uma versão do valor `BigInt` convertido em uma [base numérica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convers%C3%A3o_de_base_num%C3%A9rica) representável nativamente pelo javascript ou outra linguagem.
A estrutura sugerida acima conteria os seguintes membros:

- `type`: indicativo do tipo do valor que esse objeto encapsula e deve ser `bigint`.
- `base`: a base numérica em que o valor `BigInt` será serializado. Aqui foi adotado o valor da constante [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) que representa o maior inteiro seguramente representável no JavaScript.
- `value`: um array de valores inteiros do tipo nativo [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) representando o valor do tipo `BigInt` a ser serializado na base `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. Esse array estaria com a extremidade ordenada segundo formato [little-endian](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremidade_(ordena%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) ou seja:

  - `b | b ∈ N` é base numérica em que o número estará convertido.
  - `aₙ | n ∈ N, aₙ < aₙ₊₁` é o coeficiente da base numérica.
    O array value terá o seguinte formato:
    [image: Numero em base numérica arbitrária.]
    o array `value` é o array de comprimento `m` dos coeficientes da formula acima, cujo o índice do elemento é o respectivo expoente da base numérica `b`:
    [image: array de coeficientes]

```js
let lnum = 256564545784543535678564677898765644n;

function bigIntToJSON(key, val, base= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) {
  if (typeof val !== "bigint") return val;
  let result = [];
  let b = BigInt(base);
  //Decompõe o número na base numérica.
  for (let n = val; n > 0; n = n / b) {
    result.push(Number(n % b));
  }
  return {
    type: typeof val,
    base: base,
    value: result
  };
}

function JSONToBigInt(key, val) {
  if (typeof val !== 'object') return val;
  if (val.type !== 'bigint') return val;
  //Restaura o número decomposto.
  return val.value.reduce((acc, e, idx) => acc + BigInt(e) * BigInt(val.base) ** BigInt(idx), 0n);
}

//Serializa o número.
let j = JSON.stringify(lnum, bigIntToJSON);
console.log("Número serializado: ", j);

//Desserializa o número.
console.log("Número desserializado: ", JSON.parse(j, JSONToBigInt).toString());
```

Comment: Caraca! essa abordagem foi bastante interessante. Não passou nem perto de eu pensar em algo assim. Nesse caso o padrão seria o uso da função `JSONToBigInt` ao invés de uma _string_ de prefixo.

Comment: Com certeza um caminho muito menos gambiarra, que na verdade resolve muito bem em questão de "entendimento" da comunicação, parabéns! +1

Answer (score 8):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description), `JSON.stringify` verifica se o objeto a ser serializado possui o método `toJSON` (e se tiver, o resultado deste é usado). Podemos ver isso também na [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/structured-data.html#sec-serializejsonproperty):

> 2. If Type(value) is Object or BigInt, then
>       a. Let toJSON be ? GetV(value, "toJSON").
>       b. If IsCallable(toJSON) is true, then
>       i. Set value to ? Call(toJSON, value, « key »).

Então uma forma de serializar um `BigInt` seria definir o método `toJSON` no seu protótipo:

```js
Object.defineProperty(BigInt.prototype, 'toJSON', {
    writable: true, configurable: true, enumerable: false,
    value: function () {
        // converte para uma string em algum formato específico
        return 'BigInt::' + this.toString();
    }
});

const params = { largeNum: 54740991n };
console.log(JSON.stringify(params)); // {"largeNum":"BigInt::54740991"}
```

Lembrando, claro, de [**todos os poréns de se alterar o protótipo de um objeto**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/449732/112052). Eu pessoalmente evito fazê-lo, por isso acho melhor a solução dada na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/525384/112052) (usar uma função como segundo argumento de `JSON.stringify`). De qualquer forma, fica registrada a opção.

As demais considerações da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/525384/112052) também continuam valendo: como o resultado da serialização é uma string, você deve escolher algum formato específico para indicar que aquilo é um `BigInt`, para que seja possível convertê-lo de volta ao desserializar. No exemplo acima eu adicionei o prefixo `BigInt::` ao número, então para converter de volta seria assim:

```js
const json = '{"largeNum":"BigInt::54740991"}';

const params = JSON.parse(json, function(key, val) {
    // se a string começa com o prefixo, pega tudo depois dele
    if (typeof val === 'string' && val.startsWith('BigInt::')) {
        return BigInt(val.substring(8));
    }
    return val;
});
console.log(params.largeNum.toString()); // 54740991
console.log(typeof params.largeNum); // bigint
```

Lembrando de escolher um formato que não gere ambiguidades (por exemplo, se tiver outras strings que comecem com `BigInt::` mas que depois não tenha um número, dará problemas e terá que escolher outro prefixo, ou ajustar a função para tratar estes casos).

Até porque a função usada no `parse` confia "cegamente" no formato usado em `stringify`. Em cenários controlados, nos quais você "sabe" exatamente que todas as strings contendo o prefixo são `BigInt`'s, isso não é um problema. Caso contrário, terá que incluir o tratamento dos casos excepcionais.

Vale notar que `startsWith` não está disponível no IE, [apesar de ter um suporte relativamente bom nos demais browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#browser_compatibility). Se quiser mais compatibilidade, pode trocar por [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf#browser_compatibility):

```js
const params = JSON.parse(json, function(key, val) {
    // se a string começa com o prefixo, pega tudo depois dele
    if (typeof val === 'string' && val.indexOf('BigInt::') === 0) {
        return BigInt(val.substring(8));
    }
    return val;
});
```

---

Por fim, analisando de forma mais geral, o formato JSON (sim, é um [formato de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4042/112052), não é algo exclusivo do JavaScript) é agnóstico com relação aos tipos de cada linguagem. Na [definição do formato](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) só existe `number` (literais numéricos, como `42`, `1.25` ou `3e19`), e cada linguagem mapeia-os para seus respectivos tipos.

Quando os literais não são suficientes, outra opção passa a ser usar strings em um formato específico - como é feito, por exemplo, com datas: geralmente a data é convertida para um formato específico, e fica a cargo de cada *parser* saber interpretá-lo corretamente (daí podem surgir aberrações como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-do-i-format-a-microsoft-json-date)).

No caso do `BigInt`, o problema é similar. Os literais numéricos do formato JSON acabam sendo interpretados como o `Number` do JavaScript. Só que valores acima de [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) acabam dando problema:

```js
const n = JSON.parse('111111111111111111111111111111111111111');
console.log(typeof n); // number
// mas o valor lido não é exatamente o que foi parseado
console.log(n.toLocaleString('pt-BR')); // 111.111.111.111.111.100.000.000.000.000.000.000.000
```

Então uma forma de resolver seria de fato criar a string em um formato específico que indique que o conteúdo deve ser interpretado como `BigInt` (como feito acima). Ou então tratar qualquer string que contenha números como `BigInt`.

---

#### Mas talvez não precise de tudo isso...

Eu sugiro dar um passo atrás e avaliar se precisa mesmo de um JSON. Acredito que está usando JSON porque esses dados devem ser enviados para outro lugar (outra aplicação/sistema). Se esse outro lugar "exige" que você mande um JSON e "não pode" mudar, aí não tem muito jeito. Mas se puder mudar, talvez seja interessante considerar outras alternativas.

Por que não mandar os valores diretamente? Se for uma requisição HTTP, poderia ser na própria *query string*, por exemplo:

```
http://url.com/api?valorBigInteger=123456789012345678901234567890
```

E aí você manda o valor usando `valorBigInteger.toString()`, e o lado que recebe trata a string da maneira que achar melhor (cada linguagem terá seus tipos numéricos mais adequados para cada caso).

Aliás, o lado que recebe o JSON também é em JavaScript? Se for, precisa que seja sempre `BigInt` (valores menores que `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` não poderiam ser `Number`)? Criar uma string com um formato customizado seria necessário somente se o lado que recebe os dados precisa de fato de um `BigInt` (ou de um tipo similar na linguagem utilizada) e quer diferenciá-lo de outros tipos numéricos.

Caso contrário, mandar os dados separadamente e tratá-los um a um me parece o mais adequado. Ainda usando o exemplo acima da *query string*, a aplicação que recebe os dados sabe que determinado parâmetro deve ser convertido para um `BigInt` (ou seja lá qual o tipo equivalente na linguagem do *backend*), pois este é o tipo esperado para aquele dado - assim nem precisaria customizar a serialização do JSON.

Mas novamente, se o lado que recebe "exige" que seja enviado um JSON e "precisa" que seja um `BigInt` (e você não tem controle sobre ele), aí não tem muito jeito mesmo. Mas se puder mudá-lo, considere outras alternativas.

Comment: +1 Obriago pela resposta. Usar o _prototype_ foi uma soluçao bem interessante, não tinha pensado nisso. Acho que nesse seu exemplo, usar regex se torna dispensável porque na outra resposta, a regex era por questao de seguranca para garantir que a string possuia apenas numeros. Inclusive a funcao de `parse` ficou até mais simples....

Comment: @CmteCardeal Vale lembrar que a função de `parse` confia cegamente no formato (ela assume que o JSON sempre virá com o prefixo correto e tal). Se for um cenário controlado e vc sabe que o prefixo é gerado corretamente, não tem problema. Caso contrário, ela teria que tratar os casos de erro, e aí varia conforme cada caso...

Comment: Sim, bem notado, teria que ter um padrão para o caso. Eu até clarifiquei essa parte do seu código usando um `PREFIX` , para algo como `const PREFIX = 'BigInt::'` ai em `val.substring` eu usaria `BigInt(val.substring(PREFIX.length))`.

Comment: _"se o lado que recebe "exige" que seja enviado um JSON e "precisa" que seja um BigInt, aí não tem muito jeito mesmo"_ é bem "se" mesmo. Se a pessoa tem controle dos dois lados, usar um formato verboso como JSON me parece um pouco... limitado... por assim dizer.