# Como serializar e desserializar uma RegEx para ser transportada via JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, regex, serialização, desserialização

Realizei uma pergunta sobre como serializar e desserializar objetos com valores do tipo [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) (*[Como serializar e desserializar objetos contendo valores do tipo `BigInt` em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/525381/como-serializar-e-deserializar-objetos-contendo-valores-do-tipo-bigint-em-javasc)*) e nesta pergunta, destaquei que ao se tentar serializar diretamente um objeto com valor `BigInt` via `JSON.stringify` é lançada uma exceção.

Recentemente em um projeto que estou trabalhando na API, tive uma ideia de para uma determinada rota, retornar uma RegEx para validar um campo específico de um input. Ao realizar os testes, percebi um comportamento diferente do caso do `BigInt`:

Ex:

```js
const searchUser = {
  userData: {
    name: 'Foo',
    lastName: 'Baz'
  },
  validation: {
    field: 'name',
    regex: /^[\w\-\s,!?áàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]+$/im
  },
};

console.log(searchUser);

const json = JSON.stringify(searchUser);

console.log('[JSON]: ', json);

console.log('[JSON PARSED]: ', JSON.parse(json));
```

Ao se executar o código acima, não é lançado nenhum erro e no JSON o campo `regex` aparece como `{}`. Obviamente ao se fazer o `parse`, este aparece como objeto vazio.

Cheguei a fazer uns testes com uma instância da classe `RegExp`, mas o resultado é o mesmo:

```js
const searchUser = {
  userData: {
    name: 'Foo',
    lastName: 'Baz'
  },
  validation: {
    field: 'name',
    regex: new RegExp(/^[\w\-\s,!?áàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]+$/im)
  },
};

console.log(searchUser);

const json = JSON.stringify(searchUser);

console.log('[JSON]: ', json);

console.log('[JSON PARSED]: ', JSON.parse(json));
```

- É possível transportar RegEx através de um JSON?

ou

- Devemos, por algum motivo, evitar transporte de RegEx via JSON?

Comment: Use string, por  fim resolva na aplicação quando for executar o a propriedade, separando as flags do regex algo como: `"pattern": "regex", "flags": "i"` e depois do parse resolvendo na aplicacao será algo como `new RegExp(foobar.pattern, foobar.flags)`, nesse caso flags pode até ser opcional, se não definida vira como undefined, então  provavelmente não precisará de uma if para resolver new Regex com flags e sem flags

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é uma boa solucao! Tinha uma outra forma de resolver que eu tava testando e vou tentar a sua ideia.

Comment: Apenas para deixar como nota aqui, sem relação direta com a pergunta: fazer `new RegExp(/^[\w\-\s,!?áàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]+$/im)` é redundante. Você pode apenas fazer: `regex: /^[\w\-\s,!?áàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]+$/im`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON sendo um formato baseado em texto para representar dados não tem muito que fazer quando é uma necessidade da linguagem, lembrando que JSON pode ser usado em diferentes linguagens não existiria motivos para criar um tipo de entrada especifica para RegEx, isso porque cada linguagem pode ter a sua própria implementação de RegEx e de como será usada na camada da linguagem, então não existe um formato para RegEx em JSON.

O caminho ideal é armazenar de forma que você possa resolver os valores na aplicação de forma simples, sem precisar criar um parser próprio, então para armazenar você pode usar um objeto próprio que irá conter as instruções para ser usada na sua aplicação posteriormente

Um detalhe importante que deve tomar cuidado são os escapes quando se usa `\`, então para armazenar

```js
const data = {
    pattern: '^[\\\\w\\\\-\\\\s,!?áàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]+$',
    flags: 'im',
};

const store = JSON.stringify(data);

console.log(store);
```

Note que tem duas entradas, pattern e flags, sendo pattern a sua regex e flags os modificadores da RegEx.

Supondo que você receba esse JSON de um servidor ou de algum armazenamento você irá decodificar e poderá usar os valores diretamente no objeto [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), assim:

```js
const store = '{"pattern":"^[\\\\w\\\\-\\\\s,!?áàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]+$","flags":"im"}';

const data = JSON.parse(store);

const pattern = new RegExp(data.pattern, data.flags);

console.log(pattern);
```

Supondo que fosse usar com outras linguagens vai ter que ajustar uma coisa ou outra, talvez tenha que ajustar o escape do *Backslash* também, em PHP para passar as flags é necessário checar se existe, já que RegEx no PHP funciona dentro das funções `preg_`, exemplo:

```
<?php

// Valor que estava armazenado em outro local
$store = '{"pattern":"^[\\\\w\\\\-\\\\s,!?áàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]+$","flags":"im"}';

// Decodifica o JSON para stdClass
$data = json_decode($store);

// Checa se existem flags
$flags = $store->flags ?? '';

// Aplica para o preg_match
var_dump(preg_match("#{$data->pattern}#{$flags}", 'á é ó -'));
```

Note que em PHP existem os delimitadores, no exemplo usei `#`, mas se sua RegEx depender do `#` isso poderá complicar, como disse antes, cada linguagem poderá depender de ter que adaptar algo, talvez seja melhor adaptar diretamente na aplicação.

---

No seu código poderá ficar algo como:

```
const searchUser = {
  userData: {
    name: 'Foo',
    lastName: 'Baz'
  },
  validation: {
    field: 'name',
    pattern: '^[\\\\w\\\\-\\\\s,!?áàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]+$',
    flags: 'im',
  },
};
```

Answer (score 3):

A [documentação de `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) deixa bem claro quais são os objetos suportados, e `RegExp` não cai em nenhuma das regras (não é citado explicitamente, e nem possui o método `toJSON`, portanto acaba sendo ignorado na serialização).

Para resolver, você pode usar uma ideia [similar ao que foi feito para `BigInt`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/525381/112052). Lembrando que em JSON, esses valores serão strings, então basta serializar tudo que for necessário para construir a regex na desserialização.

No caso, o [construtor de `RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp) recebe dois parâmetros: uma string contendo a expressão, e outra (opcional) contendo as *flags*. Então basta serializar estas informações separadamente, e para isso podemos usar as propriedades [`source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source) e [`flags`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/flags), que contém, respectivamente, a expressão e as *flags*:

```js
function serialize(key, value) {
    if (value instanceof RegExp) {
        return { __type__ : 'RegExp', __source__ : value.source, __flags__ : value.flags };
    }
    return value;
}

function deserialize(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value.__type__ === 'RegExp'
        && typeof value.__source__ === 'string'
        && typeof value.__flags__ === 'string') {
        return new RegExp(value.__source__, value.__flags__);
    }
    return value;
}

const searchUser = {
  userData: { name: 'Foo', lastName: 'Baz' },
  validation: { field: 'name', regex: /^[\w\-\s,!?áàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]+$/im }
};
console.log(searchUser);
const json = JSON.stringify(searchUser, serialize);
console.log('[JSON]: ', json);
console.log('[JSON PARSED]: ', JSON.parse(json, deserialize));
```

Lembrando que na regex serializada, como os valores são strings, as barras invertidas são escapadas e escritas como `\\`. E caso a regex não tenha *flags*, o valor da chave `__flags__` será uma string vazia. Mas você também pode adaptar o código acima para não enviar as *flags* caso a regex não as tenha, por exemplo:

```js
function serialize(key, value) {
    if (value instanceof RegExp) {
        var obj = { __type__ : 'RegExp', __source__ : value.source };
        if (value.flags !== '') {
            obj.__flags__ = value.flags;
        }
        return obj;
    }
    return value;
}

function deserialize(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && value.__type__ === 'RegExp'
        && typeof value.__source__ === 'string'
        && (!value.hasOwnProperty('__flags__') || typeof value.__flags__ === 'string')) {
        return new RegExp(value.__source__, value.__flags__ );
    }
    return value;
}
// testando com regex sem flags
const searchUser = {
  userData: { name: 'Foo', lastName: 'Baz' },
  validation: { field: 'name', regex: /^[\w\-\s,!?áàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]+$/ }
};
console.log(searchUser);
const json = JSON.stringify(searchUser, serialize);
console.log('[JSON]: ', json);
console.log('[JSON PARSED]: ', JSON.parse(json, deserialize));
```

---

Outra alternativa é adicionar o método `toJSON` no protótipo de `RegExp` (lembrando de [todos os poréns de se alterar o protótipo de um objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/449732/112052)). Na minha opinião é um pouco pior, já que este método deve retornar uma string que depois deverá ser *parseada* na desserialização (usando a abordagem anterior, o retorno é um objeto mais "organizado", com as informações devidamente separadas, sem a necessidade de *parsear* uma única string):

```js
Object.defineProperty(RegExp.prototype, "toJSON", {
  value: function (key, val) {
             return "__RegExp__:" + this.toString();
         }
});
function deserialize(key, value) {
    if (typeof value === 'string' && value.indexOf("__RegExp__:/") === 0) {
        var ultimaBarra = value.lastIndexOf('/');
        return new RegExp(value.substring(12, ultimaBarra), value.substring(ultimaBarra + 1));
    }
    return value;
}

const searchUser = {
  userData: { name: 'Foo', lastName: 'Baz' },
  validation: { field: 'name', regex: /^[\w\-\s,!?áàâãéèêíïóôõöúçñ]+$/im }
};
console.log(searchUser);

const json = JSON.stringify(searchUser);

console.log('[JSON]: ', json);
console.log('[JSON PARSED]: ', JSON.parse(json, deserialize));
```

No caso, eu uso `toString`, que retorna a regex no seu formato literal (a expressão entre barras, seguida das *flags*). Como é um formato [garantido pela especificação](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/text-processing.html#sec-regexp.prototype.tostring), posso fazer o *parsing* da forma acima (verifico se começa com barra, e vou até a última barra, e o que tiver depois são as *flags*).

---

> *Devemos, por X motivos, evitar transporte de RegEx via JSON?*

O principal problema, a meu ver, está na desserialização. Como você está recebendo uma string arbitrária, pode vir qualquer coisa, e existem alguns cuidados a serem tomados, como já discutido em [Criar expressões regulares com um padrão dinâmico é problemático? Se sim, há como evitar o problema?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/458289/112052).
Nesta pergunta há uma discussão mais detalhada sobre isso, e acredito que muitos pontos são pertinentes neste caso também, em especial o trecho que fala sobre ataques de *Regex Denial of Service* (mas não vou repetir tudo aqui, então siga o link).