# Formato do Json é válido, mas conceitualmente incorreto. Como argumentar?

Tags: json

Recentemente solicitamos um serviço para uma empresa parceira, para consultar algumas pessoas. O serviço foi concebido do zero, para atender uma demanda particular do sistema nosso. Este é um serviço Rest simples, usando JSON como retorno.

Porém, o resultado do serviço disponibilizado me chamou a atenção. Veja um exemplo:

```
{
    "73317882484": {
        "nome": "Joaquim"
    },
    "55968857463": {
        "nome": "Maria"
    }
}
```

Embora seja um Json válido, o desenvolvedor entendeu que o campo de CPF seria uma espécie de chave para agrupar as demais informações da pessoa. Então, ao invés dele criar um campo `"cpf"` com o valor do CPF, ele adotou o próprio CPF como nome do campo. Também, ao invés de criar um array para cada registro, foi devolvido um objeto só.

Tudo indica que o Json retornado foi manipulado, sem ajuda de framework para ser gerado, pois ficaria esquisito mapear este Json para uma classe Java (por exemplo) sem conhecer todos os possíveis retornos de CPF. Enfim, não faz muito sentido.

Eu esperava, como mencionei antes, algo assim:

```
[
    {
        "cpf: "73317882484"
        "nome": "Joaquim"
    },
    {
        "cpf: "55968857463"
        "nome": "Maria"
    }
]
```

A pergunta é: como explicar que o formato mencionado antes não é o adequado para um retorno?

Não achei nenhum tipo de referência sobre este assunto. Em uma breve leitura dinâmica pela [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259) também não achei nada associado a isto.

Comment: Em quais pontos exatamente o JSON deixa de ser adequado?

Comment: Na real dá pra você mapear no Java sim... O que você pode fazer é fornecer uma documentação do retorno esperado e dar exemplos

Comment: @Sorack, nunca tinha visto este tipo de formato antes. É possível ler com o [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)? Espero que não esteja falando de eu também precisar manipular a String do Json... rs.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, acredito que respondi sua pergunta na minha pergunta. Qual ponto não ficou claro? Um dos argumentos é que não vejo como seria possível ler isto em um framework de "parser" de json, tendo ao final uma lista de pessoas com o CPF e demais informações.

Comment: @Dherik sim, é possível. No caso você mapearia esse atributo para um `Map<String, Pessoa>` ou algo similar a isso

Comment: Sendo um JSON válido, qualquer ferramenta que se preze do Java para trabalhar com JSON será capaz de analisar os dados corretamente. O que vejo que é que talvez essa não seja a forma mais fácil para você, por isso questionei, para saber se estava claro para você quais eram as limitações. Estando claro isso, sua resposta estaria pronta.

Comment: @Sorack, fiz um teste aqui, de fato dá sim. É que o Anderson disse, é possível, mas para o meu caso não é um formato conveniente. Novamente, nunca tinha visto esta forma de usar Json antes e imediatamente assumi como "incorreta" (que é o ponto principal da discussão)

Comment: Talvez um argumento válido seja a semântica: solicitar uma **lista** de pessoas é diferente de solicitar um **mapa** de pessoas. Se tenho interesse no todo, faz sentido eu possuir uma lista, se tenho interesse em informações insoladas, faz mais sentido eu ter um mapa.

Comment: Aparentemente faltou escopo sobre a integração, publique exatamente o trecho que refere-se ao JSON que deveria ser retornado, de repente foi pedido um "JSON válido" e foi apenas nisso que ele se preocupou. Se foi esse o caso, adicione o termo lista à solicitação e mostre um exemplo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Um argumento válido: `"73317882484"` não faz parte de estrutura alguma. Os campos em um objeto JSON visam refletir, principalmente, estrutura. A estrutura compõe-se de nomes, códigos (como o CPF), campos demais, outros objetos, etc.

Você também pode argumentar, já que o serviço foi feito para ser consumido por vocês, que simplesmente serializar os dados de um modo que não seja proveitoso a quem desserializa é contra-producente. Também tem o problema da semântica: está implícito que a chave do campo é o CPF, não explícito.

Se fosse para enviar dados assim, você pode argumentar que um CSV seria mais útil.

Answer (score 6):

Sintaticamente, isso está ok. Mas o problema aqui é na semântica.

A notação com `{}` representa um objeto. A notação `[]` representa uma lista.

Você utiliza este serviço com a intenção de encontrar uma lista de pessoas. E não um objeto que contém as pessoas. Logo, se a ideia é obter como resultado uma lista, então você deveria ter um retorno com `[]`, e não com `{}`.

Além disso, cada pessoa é um objeto (representado com `{}`), e nele você espera encontrar as propriedades relevantes de cada pessoa, tais como nome, e-mail, telefone e CPF. Logo, o campo `cpf` deveria estar dentro do objeto representando a pessoa.

Answer (score 2):

O formato não está incorreto.  O que você pode fazer é definir uma especificação (JSON Style Guide) e fornecer para a empresa.

Alguns exemplos:
- https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsoncstyleguide.xml
- https://jsonapi.org/

> Tudo indica que o Json retornado foi manipulado, sem ajuda de framework para ser gerado, pois seria impossível mapear este Json para uma classe Java (por exemplo) sem conhecer todos os possíveis retornos de CPF. Enfim, não faz sentido.

Essa afirmação está incorreta. É possível gerar/mapear um JSON assim.