# Como obter o valor de um campo de um objeto JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Como é que eu posso pegar no correspondente a `earnings` no JSON (Valor `0€`) e dar output no JavaScript?

Ou seja, de forma que no website apareça o correspondente a `Earnings` (0€) no que eu identifiquei como `OUTPUT DE EARNINGS AQUI` no JavaScript.

**JSON**

```
{
  "DataInfo":[
    {
      "Earnings": "0€",
      "Orders": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

**JS**

```
function Earnings() {
  var ElementEarnings = document.getElementById("Earnings");
  ElementEarnings.innerHTML = OUTPUT DE EARNINGS AQUI (0€);
}
```

**WEBSITE**

```js
function Earnings() {
  var ElementEarnings = document.getElementById("Earnings");
  ElementEarnings.innerHTML = "OUTPUT DE EARNINGS AQUI (0€)";
}

function Orders() {
  var ElementOrders = document.getElementById("Orders")
  ElementOrders.innerHTML = "1";
}

function JSONLOAD() {
  "use stric";

  fetch("Static/Data/DATA.json")
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json();
    })
    .then(function(data){
      var Earnings = data.Earnings;
      var Orders = data.Orders;
      console.log(data);
    })
}

Earnings()
Orders()
JSONLOAD()
```

```css
body {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background: #252C35;
  color: white;
}

#UpperBar {
  height: 45px;
}

.MASlime {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 1px;
  left: 40px;
}

#Totals {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.Total {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 130px;
}

.TotalEarnings {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 200px;
}

.TotalO {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 130px;
}

.TotalOrders {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 200px;
}

#Earnings {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 350px;
}

#Orders {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 350px;
}

.NewOrder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.OrderName {
  position: absolute;
  top: 350px;
  left: 140px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #252C35;
  color: white;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.OrderDate {
  position: absolute;
  top: 400px;
  left: 140px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #252C35;
  color: white;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.SKU {
  position: absolute;
  top: 450px;
  left: 140px;
  width: 250px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #252C35;
  color: white;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.SUBMIT {
  position: absolute;
  top: 500px;
  left: 220px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #252C35;
  color: white;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}

.Menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 480px;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAED;
  border-top: 1px solid #EAEAED;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background: #252C35;
}

.All {
  display: block;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
}

.fadeIn {
  animation: fadein 1.3s ease-in;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  25% { opacity: 0.3; }
  50% { opacity: 0.5; }
  75% { opacity: 0.8; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>EComerce App Slime</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Static/css/index.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="menu">
      <label for="toggle" class="Menu">&#9776;</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" onclick="meuMenuToggle()"/>
      <div class="menu">
          <a href="#">Slime Recipe</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="UpperBar">
      <p class="MASlime">MASlime</p>
    </div>
      <div id="HomePage">
        <div id="Totals">
          <p class="Total">Total</p>
          <p class="TotalEarnings">Earnings</p>
          <p class="TotalO">Total</p>
          <p class="TotalOrders">Orders</p>
          <p id="Earnings">100€</p>
          <p id="Orders">1</p>
        </div>
        <div id="NewOrder">
          <p class="NewOrder">New Order</p>
          <form id="OrderForm">
            <input class="OrderName" type="text" name="OrderName" placeholder="Buyer Name" required>
            <input class="OrderDate" type="text" name="OrderDate" placeholder="Date of Order" required>
            <input class="SKU" type="text" name="ProductSKU" placeholder="Product SKU" required>
            <input class="SUBMIT" type="button" name="Submit" value="SUBMIT">
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var home = document.getElementById('HomePage');
    var menu = document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0];
    menu.style.display = 'none';

    document.getElementById('toggle').onclick = () => {

    if (menu.style.display == 'none') setTimeout(fadeMenu, 150);
    else if(menu.style.display == 'block') setTimeout(fadeHome, 150);
  }

    function fadeMenu() {
      home.style.display = 'none';
      menu.classList.add('fadeIn');
      menu.style.display =  'block';
    }

    function fadeHome() {
      home.style.display = 'block';
      home.classList.add('fadeIn');
      menu.style.display = 'none';
    }
    </script>
    <script src="Static/js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro temos que entender como é a [**estrutura de um JSON**](https://www.json.org/). Usando o seu caso como exemplo:

```
{
  "DataInfo":[
    {
      "Earnings": "0€",
      "Orders": "0"
    }
  ]
}
```

As chaves (`{` e `}`) delimitam um objeto, que nada mais é do que um conjunto de vários pares chave/valor. Cada par chave/valor é escrito no formato `chave : valor`, ou seja, uma string com o nome da chave¹, seguida de dois pontos, seguida do valor.

Então o objeto acima tem uma chave `"DataInfo"`, cujo valor é:

```
[
  {
    "Earnings": "0€",
    "Orders": "0"
  }
]
```

Os colchetes (`[` e `]`) delimitam um array, ou seja uma lista de um ou mais valores. Portanto, o valor da chave `DataInfo` é um array.

Dentro este array, temos:

```
{
  "Earnings": "0€",
  "Orders": "0"
}
```

Ou seja, é **outro** objeto, que possui duas chaves:

- `"Earnings"`, cujo valor é `"0€"`
- `"Orders"`, cujo valor é "0"

Então temos um objeto que possui a chave `"DataInfo"`, cujo valor é um array. Dentro deste array temos apenas um elemento, que é outro objeto, que possui as chaves `"Earnings"` e `"Orders"`.

Ou seja, para obter o valor de `Earnings`, basta percorrer esta estrutura. Se o seu objeto se chamar `data`, para pegar o valor da chave `DataInfo`, basta fazer `data.DataInfo`, e isso será um array.

Para pegar o primeiro elemento do array, faça `data.DataInfo[0]` (já que o primeiro elemento de um array é o elemento zero). E para pegar o valor da chave `Earnings` deste objeto, faça `data.DataInfo[0].Earnings`. E para pegar o valor de `Orders`, a ideia é a mesma: `data.DataInfo[0].Orders`.

```js
let data = {
  "DataInfo":[
    {
      "Earnings": "0€",
      "Orders": "0"
    }
  ]
};

console.log(data.DataInfo[0].Earnings); // 0€
console.log(data.DataInfo[0].Orders); // 0
```

Então bastaria fazer:

```
fetch("Static/Data/DATA.json")
  .then(function(resp) {
    return resp.json();
  })
  .then(function(data){
    document.getElementById("Earnings").innerHTML = data.DataInfo[0].Earnings;
  });
```

---

(1): No JavaScript também [dá para usar números como chave](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/362777/112052), pois eles [são automaticamente convertidos para strings](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/362806/112052).

Comment: Muito bem explicado de como funciona!

Comment: Se eu usar o primeiro exemplo (O que vs usa o Json dentro do js) mais tarde conseguiria mudar a informação dentro do website?

Comment: @DeadSec Não sei se entendi sua dúvida, mas enfim, se vc tem acesso ao DOM (via `document`) e tem acesso aos dados do JSON (seja dentro do `fetch`, seja em qualquer outro ponto do código), vc pode manipular os elementos da página (usando o `document`) usando os dados do JSON. Se for o caso, vc pode [abrir outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) com a dúvida mais específica, assim vc aumenta as chances de ser respondido (pois perguntas novas ficam visíveis para todos, enquanto os comentários só ficam visiíveis aqui) e o site fica mais organizado (uma pergunta por dúvida) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa passar a resposta que obteve no `fetch` para a função que insere o `Earnings` na página.

```
function appendEarnings(earnings) {
  var ElementEarnings = document.getElementById("Earnings");
  ElementEarnings.innerHTML = earnings
}

function JSONLOAD() {
  "use stric";

  fetch("Static/Data/DATA.json")
    .then(function(resp) {
      return resp.json();
    })
    .then(function(data){
      var Earnings = data.DataInfo[0].Earnings;
      appendEarnings(Earnings)
    })
}
```

Comment: Eu coloquei desta forma : https://pastebin.com/g081zmAv Mas ele esta a dizer na cosola isto `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .   index.js:18`

Comment: @hkotsubo Eu coloquei desta forma : pastebin.com/g081zmAv Mas ele esta a dizer na cosola isto Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . index.js:18

Comment: @DeadSec Não testei, mas em uma olhada rápida, faltou o parâmetro na primeira função: `function appendOrders(orders)`, e mais embaixo é `use strict` (faltou o "t"). Mas talvez tenha outro erro em outras partes do código, pois testando só com o que vc passou, não tive nenhum erro de sintaxe...

Comment: @hkotsubo Todos os problemas foram resolvidos Obrigado!

Comment: @DeadSec Se uma das respostas resolveu o seu problema, vc pode escolher a que melhor resolveu e aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema (mas se achar que nenhuma delas resolveu de fato, então não precisa aceitar nenhuma). Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.