# Eu posso criar parâmetros de funções como string?

Tags: javascript, string, objetos, campos

Eu estou tentando me aprofundar em funções e no exemplo do site do [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) eles tem o seguinte exemplo:

```js
var math = {
  'factit': function factorial(n) {
    console.log(n)
    if (n <= 1) {
      return 1;
    }
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
  }
};

math.factit(3) //3;2;1;
```

Nessa parte do código `'factit': function factorial(n) {}` foi aqui que eu não entendi, pois nos códigos que eu vejo geralmente é assim `factit: function(){}` que é o parâmetro do objeto e o valor do objeto e no exemplo nessa parte `'factit'` é um parâmetro, mas é uma *string*?

Comment: Toda chave de objeto, no fundo, acaba sendo convertida em string, veja mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/362806/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40682/112052)

Comment: Muito, obrigado!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isto não é um parâmetro, menos ainda pertence a uma função. Isto é um objeto, se fosse um parâmetro estaria entre parenteses, por exemplo o `n` ali na função `factorial()` é um parâmetro.

Isto é um membro de um objeto, e sim, ele pode ser usado como um símbolo no código ou como *string*, dá no mesmo. Então o que está definindo aí é um membro de um objeto cujo tipo é uma função (`function`) e o seu valor é justamente uma função, talvez daí vem a confusão, a função está aí como o valor e nada tem a ver com o que está falando.

[Um objeto em JS é criado como um *array* associativo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40682/101), um mapa, portanto na verdade ele é uma estrutura que tem elementos com uma chave e um valor. Como é um objeto todas as chaves são *strings* mesmo. Existe um açúcar sintático que faz com você não precise escrever as aspas ou o indexador do objeto.

Então o mesmo código pode ser escrito assim:

```js
var math = {
    factit: function factorial(n) {
        console.log(n)
        if (n <= 1) return 1;
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
    }
};

math['factit'](3) //3;2;1;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/KetString.js).

Note que agora eu inverti o uso do açúcar sintático. Agora na definição do campo eu não usei aspas no nome, mas quando foi chamar o método dentro do objeto eu usei as apas e indexador para acessar o campo. Como o campo é uma função eu pude chamá-la, mas isto é outro mecanismo, por coincidência está aí, mas poderia ser a mesma coisa com um valor qualquer que não seja uma função.

O ideal é usar sempre o açúcar sintático a não ser que tenha um motivo muito bom para não fazê-lo o que quase sempre é um erro (existem algumas poucas situações avançadas legítimas, mas há muito abuso). O exemplo da documentação poderia ter feito a declaração do objeto como eu fiz aqui, mas a chamada lá está na melhor forma mesmo.

Comment: Maniero, mas um objeto não é composto por parâmetros, valores dos parâmetros e métodos? https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: @draw O que a documentação chama de parâmetros são as "coisas" que são passadas para se construir um objeto. Mas repare que essas "coisas" são *nameValuePairs*, ou seja, pares de nome-valor (sendo que "nome" tb é chamado de "chave"). O nome (a chave) sempre é uma string (caso não seja, é convertida para string), e o valor pode ser qualquer coisa (números, string, um método, outro objeto, etc). Mas os valores não são necessariamente métodos

Comment: @hkotsubo é só mal uso da ferramenta que foi criada para descrever funções e usaram para descrever o objeto, então como não tinha uma seção pronta para isto e não tinha como criar ou tiveram preguiça usaram uma pronta fazendo a documentação ficar errada. É o que eu sempre falo, para aprender programar precisa aprender ler documentação, não só ir ler, mas interpretá-la e para fazer isto é preciso saber os fundamentos antes de ler a documentação e começar programar de verdade, se não a pessoa não consegue ver que tem um erro da documentação, mesmo que seja só ambiguidade de definição,como o caso