# Utilizar Valores de uma Coluna Dicionário para Criar uma Nova Coluna em um Dataframe

Tags: python, dicionário, dataframe

Estou tentando extrair os nomes dos países de uma coluna do tipo string que eu tenho para criar uma nova coluna em meu DataFrame só com os nomes dos países. O formato é o abaixo:

```
["[{'iso_3166_1': 'US', 'name': 'United States of America'}]",
 "[{'iso_3166_1': 'US', 'name': 'United States of America'}]",
 "[{'iso_3166_1': 'US', 'name': 'United States of America'}]",
 "[{'iso_3166_1': 'US', 'name': 'United States of America'}]",
 "[{'iso_3166_1': 'US', 'name': 'United States of America'}]",
 "[{'iso_3166_1': 'US', 'name': 'United States of America'}]",
 "[{'iso_3166_1': 'DE', 'name': 'Germany'}, {'iso_3166_1': 'US', 'name': 'United States of America'}]",
 "[{'iso_3166_1': 'US', 'name': 'United States of America'}]"]
```

Importante ressaltar que alguns elementos da lista contém dois dicionários, a exemplo da linha 7th que possui Estados Unidos e Alemanha.

Eu pensei em transformar essa coluna em dicionário e então extrair os valores da *key* name, mas meu loop falha quando depara-se com problemas como da linha 7th. Por exemplo:

```
Countries_Movie = []
for k in range(0,len(movies_datasets['production_countries'])):
    if (type(movies_datasets.production_countries[k]) == str): 
        mv_inter = movies_datasets.production_countries[k].replace('[',"").replace(']',"")
        mv_inter = ast.literal_eval(mv_inter)
        mv_inter = mv_inter.get('name')
        Countries_Movie.append(mv_inter)
```

Podem, por favor, me sugerir um método mais eficiente ou ajuda a compreender o que está faltando em meu código?

Atenciosamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui extrair os nomes criando uma função. O que acontece é que a coluna possui um formato JSON, ou seja, cada linha é um objeto que pode ser convertido para uma lista.

Para mais informações acessar:

> [O que é JSON? Para que serve e como funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4042/o-que-%C3%A9-json-para-que-serve-e-como-funciona)

Portando, eu criei a seguinte função:

```
def extract_names(mv_str):
    if isinstance(mv_str, float):
        pass
    else:
        values = []
        mv_str = ast.literal_eval(mv_str)
        if isinstance(mv_str, list):
            for mv_str_i in mv_str:
                values.append(mv_str_i['name'])
            return values
        else:
            return None
```

Eu seleciono a linha que é um objeto `JSON` e transformo em um dicionário, então eu percorro a lista e seleciono os valores da *key* **name**. Resultado fica como abaixo:

```
0   [United States of America]
1   [United States of America]
2   [United States of America]
3   [United States of America]
4   [United States of America]
5   [United States of America]
6   [Germany, United States of America]
```

Atenciosamente.