# Salvar valores de array no Banco

Tags: php

Tenho um carrinho de compras:

```
<?php

          if(!isset($_SESSION['itens'])) {
            $_SESSION['itens'] = array();
          }

          // ADD ITEMS TO CART //
          if(isset($_GET['add']) && $_GET['add'] == "carrinho") {
            $idProduto = $_GET['id'];
            if(!isset($_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto])) {
              $_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto] = 1;
            } else {
              $_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto] += 1;
            }
          }
          
          // REMOVE ITEMS FROM CART //
          if(isset($_GET['removeone']) && $_GET['removeone'] == "carrinho") {
            $idProduto = $_GET['id'];
            if(!isset($_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto])) {
              $_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto] = 1;
            } else {
              $_SESSION['itens'][$idProduto] -= 1;
            }
          }

          // SHOW PRODUCTS //
          if (count($_SESSION['itens']) == 0) {
            echo '<h5>Seu carrinho está vazio. <a href="index.php">Clique aqui para adicionar itens!</a></h5>';
          }

          else {
            $conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=***;dbname=***',"***","***");

            foreach($_SESSION['itens'] as $idProduto => $quantidade) {
              $select = $conexao->prepare("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id=?");
              $select->bindParam(1,$idProduto);
              $select->execute();
              $produtos = $select->fetchAll();
              $total = $quantidade * $produtos[0]["valor"];
              $totalgeral += $total;

        ?>
```

E este mostra os produtos numa tabela:

```
<?php

          echo
            '<td>'.$produtos[0]["nome"].'</td>
            <td>R$ '.number_format($produtos[0]["valor"],2,",",".").'</td>
            <td>'.$quantidade.'</td>
            <td>R$ '.number_format($total,2,",",".").'</td>
            <td>
                <a href="carrinho.php?add=carrinho&id='.$idProduto.'"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="carrinho.php?removeone=carrinho&id='.$idProduto.'"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="remover.php?remover=carrinho&id='.$idProduto.'"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>
            </td>
            ';

          }
        }

      ?>
```

Envio via POST com alguns outros campos que preciso para adicionar no banco. Salvo ele dentro de um `input="hidden"`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="produtos" value="<?php echo $produtos; ?>" required>
```

Quero pegar ele no outro arquivo, pra mandar para o banco, faço desta forma:

```
$produtos = $_POST['produtos'];
  $produtos = array();
  foreach($_POST as $nome => $quantidade) {
    
    echo $produtos;
    
  }
```

Ao tentar "pegar" ele no outro arquivo, só recebo: `"ArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArrayArray"`

Não consigo perceber no que estou falhando. Podem me ajudar?

**EDIT: Coloquei os colchetes no input:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="produtos[]" value="<?php echo $produtos; ?>" required>
```

E tentei buscar os valores de forma diferente:

```
$produtos = $_POST['produtos'];
  $produtos = '"' . implode('","', $produtos) . '"';
  
  echo $produtos;
```

Mesmo assim, sem sucesso.

**EDIT 2:**

Outra forma, também sem sucesso. Só recebo a palavra `Array`:

```
$contador = count($_POST["produtos"]);
  for ($x = 0; $x < $contador; $x++){
  $produto = $_POST["produtos"][$x];
  
    echo $produto;
    
  }
```

Não consigo enxergar a solução!

**EDIT 3: Desculpem, estou deseperado pela solução...**

O que estou percebendo é que os valores não estão sendo passados corretamente de um arquivo para o outro, porque gero um array no `carrinho2.php` e consigo ver os valores com o `echo`.

Será que o problema está no input?

```
<form action="carrinho2.php" method="post" id="form_payment">

            <p class="title_bold">Valor total dos produtos: R$ <?=number_format($totalgeral,2,",",".")?></p>
            <p class="title_bold">Frete escolhido: <input type="text" name="freteescolhido" id="freteescolhido" readonly required /> </p>
            <p class="title_bold">Valor total do pedido: R$ <input type="text" name="valorfinalcomofrete" id="valorfinalcomofrete" readonly required /></p>

            <!-- PRODUCT DETAILS -->
            <input type="hidden" name="altura" value="<?php echo $altura; ?>" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="largura" value="<?php echo $largura; ?>" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="comprimento" value="<?php echo $comprimento; ?>" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="peso" value="<?php echo $peso; ?>" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="produtos[]" value="<?php echo $produtos; ?>" required>
            
            <!-- CUSTOMER DATA -->
            <input type="hidden" name="nome" value="<?php echo $razaosocial; ?>" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="cnpj" value="<?php echo $cnpj; ?>" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="endereco" value="<?php echo $endereco; ?>" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="bairro" value="<?php echo $bairro; ?>" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="cidade" value="<?php echo $cidade; ?>" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="estado" value="<?php echo $estado; ?>" required>
            <input type="hidden" name="cep" value="<?php echo $cep; ?>" required>

            <!-- ORDER DATA -->
            <input type="hidden" name="datavencimento" value="<?php echo $hoje; ?>" required>

            <!-- ORDER BUTTON -->
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dhfarma">Finalizar Pedido</button>

          </form>
```

Comment: Consegue descrever em texto o que esse último trecho de código deveria fazer? Por que define a variável `$produtos` duas vezes? Por que o laço itera a variável superglobal `$_POST`?

Comment: É pra pegar os dados da variável e tentar mostrar... mostrando, eu salvo no banco... Mas você já achou um erro. Alguma sugestão, por gentileza?

Comment: Tentei usar o `for` também, mas não tive resultados satisfatórios.

Answer (score 0):

Ao fazeres echo de um *array* em php ele irá te apresentar um formato 'friendly', e assim a tua interligação de backend e frontend não irá ser a melhor... existe por ai a fora algumas linguagens de estruturação como amável **[JSON](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4042/o-que-%C3%A9-json-para-que-serve-e-como-funciona)** :)

**Invés de isto:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="produtos[]" value="<?php echo $produtos; ?>" required>
```

**Tenta transformar os dandos em JSON exemplo:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="produtos[]" value="<?= json_encode($produtos); ?>" required>
```

Depois no teu backend irás descodificar (**transformar o JSON em PHP array ou objeto**), exemplo:

```
  $produtos = json_decode($_POST['produtos']);
  foreach($produtos as $produto) {
    
    echo $produto;
    
  }
```

**É de nota que o teu for estava com erros, o ciclo deve consistir nos produtos obtidos pelo post.**

Comment: Grato pelo suporte, meu amigo. Tenho uma briga eterna com os arrays, algo tão simples que apanho às vezes. É mais por conta do desespero e atraso. Agradeço de coração pelo suporte! Vou testar e retorno com a resposta. Grande abraço!

Comment: obrigado eu, espero ter ajudado! :) (não te esqueças mais tarde marcar a resposta que consideres correta e que te ajudou)

Comment: Sem dúvidas, depois de resolvido, marcarei. Sei como é importante para a comunidade! Abração!