# Existe um método mais eficiente de se percorrer um JSON e retornar o seu índice do que o FOR?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Procuro saber se existe um método otimizado, ou pelo menos mais idiomático, de percorrer este JSON e retornar o seu índice, no caso o jogador procurado

```js
const data = {
  "clubes": {
      "20" : {
         "id" : 20,
          "nome": "Grêmio",
          "estadio": "Arena Grêmio",
          "capacidade": 60.540,
          "escudo" : "url" }
    },
  "Jogadores": [{
      "jogador": {
          "nome": "Borja",
          "nacionalidade": "Colômbia",
          "posicao": "Atacante",
          "n_camisa": "9",
          "foto": "url",
          "clube_id": 20
  }},
  {
      "jogador": {

          "nome": "Brenno",
          "nacionalidade": "Brasil",
          "posicao": "Goleiro",
          "n_camisa": "1",
          "foto": "url",
          "clube_id": 20
        },
}]}
  
let buscar = "Brenno";
let indice;

for (let i = 0; i < data['Jogadores'].length; i++){

if (data['Jogadores'][i]['jogador']['nome'] == buscar) {
      indice = i; 
     console.log(indice); 
}}
```

Comment: Se está procurando por um jeito mais eficiente, fique com seu código mesmo, pois usar `findIndex`, como sugerido abaixo, é mais lento: https://jsbench.me/dbks2gok5r/1 - vale lembrar que `findIndex` retorna o índice do primeiro elemento que satisfaz a condição, enquanto o seu loop busca todos (caso haja mais de um). Porém, no link que indiquei, mudei o loop pra retornar só o primeiro (e assim ter uma comparação mais "justa"). Agora se quer código mais curto (que não necessariamente é "melhor"), aí `findIndex` é uma opção.

Comment: E sobre JSON não ser o mesmo que um objeto do JavaScript, leia aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/517767/112052

Comment: @hkotsubo informações de grande valor, sou imensamente grato por tudo.

Answer (score 4):

A variável `data` não é JSON, é um objeto JavaScript. E na realidade, o seu problema consiste em localizar um objeto específico em um array de objetos. Para isso existe a função `findIndex()`. Você poderia tentar algo do tipo:

```
let buscar = "Brenno"; 
let indice = data.Jogadores.findIndex(e => e.jogador.nome === buscar);
console.log(indice);
```

Comment: Isto era exatamente o que eu procurava. 
E peço desculpa minha falta de conhecimento, achei que se tratava de um JSON. 

Muito obrigado!