# Como passar nome do atributo vindo da variável ao JSON - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Olá, como posso passar o nome do atributo vindo da variável ao JSON

```
var varNome = 'nome';

var person = {
    varNome: 'Fulano de Tal'
};
```

Comment: Só pra ser pedante, o que vc tem é um objeto do JavaScript, e não um JSON. Apesar de à primeira vista serem meio parecidos (e de ser possível converter de um para o outro), na verdade são coisas diferentes ([ver aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/517767/112052) para mais detalhes) :-)

Comment: @hkotsubo Sim eu converto para Json depois....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta fazer `person.varNome = varNome;`

Comment: Ótimo, funcionou!       var person = {}; person[name] = "ValorCampo";